# In C++, can you have a function that modifies a tuple of variable length?

Tags: c++, tuples

In C++0x I would like to write a function like this:

```
template <typename... Types>
void fun(typename std::tuple<Types...> my_tuple) {
    //Put things into the tuple
}
```

I first tried to use a for loop on `int i` and then do:

```
get<i>(my_tuple);
```

And then store some value in the result. However, `get` only works on `constexpr`.

If I could get the variables out of the `tuple` and pass them to a variadic templated function I could recurse through the arguments very easily, but I have no idea how to get the variables out of the tuple without `get`. Any ideas on how to do that? Or does anyone have another way of modifying this `tuple`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the "i" in

```
get<i>(tup)
```

needs to be a compile-time constant, template instantiation is used to "iterate" (actually recurse) through the values.  Boost tuples have the "length" and "element" meta-functions that can be helpful here -- I assume C++0x has these too.

Comment: Thanks! My code now looks like this:
    template<int nPos, typename... Types>
    void fun(typename std::tuple<Types...> my_tuple) {
        get<nPos>(my_tuple);
        fun<nPos+1>(my_tuple);
    }

Answer (score 3):

[Boost.Fusion](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/fusion/doc/html/index.html) is worth a look. It can 'iterate' over `std::pair`, `boost::tuple`, some  other containers and its own tuple types, although I don't think it supports `std::tuple` yet.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at section 6.1.3.4 of TR1, http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1836.pdf

get is defined for both const and non-const qualified tuples and returns the appropriate reference type.  If you change your function declaration to the following:

```
template 
void fun(typename std::tuple& my_tuple) {
    //Put things into the tuple
}
```

Then the argument to your function is a non-const tuple and get will allow you to make the necessary assignments once you've written the iteration using the information provided in previous responses.

Answer (score 0):

AFAICT, C++ tuples basically need to be handled with recursion; there don't seem to be any real ways of packing/unpacking tuples *except* using the typesystem's only variadic template handling.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at my answer here for an example of template recursion to unwind tuple arguments to a function call.

[How do I expand a tuple into variadic template function's arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687490/c0x-how-do-i-expand-a-tuple-into-variadic-template-function-arguments)