# GCC ICE -- alternative function syntax, variadic templates and tuples

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11

(Related to [C++0x, How do I expand a tuple into variadic template function arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687490/c0x-how-do-i-expand-a-tuple-into-variadic-template-function-arguments).)

The following code (see below) is taken from this [discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c++.moderated/browse_thread/thread/750fa3815cdaac45/d8dc09e34bbb9661?lnk=gst&q=tuple+variadic#d8dc09e34bbb9661).  The objective is to apply a function to a tuple.  I simplified the template parameters and modified the code to allow for a return value of generic type.

While the original code compiles fine, when I try to compile the modified code with GCC 4.4.3,

> g++ -std=c++0x main.cc -o main

GCC reports an internal compiler error (ICE) with the following message:

> main.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
>   main.cc:53: internal compiler error: in tsubst_copy, at cp/pt.c:10077
>   Please submit a full bug report,
>   with preprocessed source if appropriate.
>   See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.4/README.Bugs> for instructions.

**Question:** Is the code correct? or is the ICE triggered by illegal code?

```
// file: main.cc
#include <tuple>

// Recursive case
template<unsigned int N>
struct Apply_aux
{
  template<typename F, typename T, typename... X>
  static auto apply(F f, const T& t, X... x)
    -> decltype(Apply_aux<N-1>::apply(f, t, std::get<N-1>(t), x...))
  {
    return Apply_aux<N-1>::apply(f, t, std::get<N-1>(t), x...);
  }
};

// Terminal case
template<>
struct Apply_aux<0>
{
  template<typename F, typename T, typename... X>
  static auto apply(F f, const T&, X... x) -> decltype(f(x...))
  {
    return f(x...);
  }
};

// Actual apply function
template<typename F, typename T>
auto apply(F f, const T& t)
  -> decltype(Apply_aux<std::tuple_size<T>::value>::apply(f, t))
{
  return Apply_aux<std::tuple_size<T>::value>::apply(f, t);
}

// Testing
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int f(int p1, double p2, std::string p3)
{
  std::cout << "int=" << p1 << ", double=" << p2 << ", string=" << p3 << std::endl;
  return 1;
}

int g(int p1, std::string p2)
{
  std::cout << "int=" << p1 << ", string=" << p2 << std::endl;
  return 2;
}

int main()
{
  std::tuple<int, double, char const*> tup(1, 2.0, "xxx");
  std::cout << apply(f, tup) << std::endl;
  std::cout << apply(g, std::make_tuple(4, "yyy")) << std::endl;
}
```

*Remark:*  If I hardcode the return type in the recursive case (see code), then everything is fine.  That is, substituting this snippet for the recursive case does not trigger the ICE:

```
// Recursive case (hardcoded return type)
template<unsigned int N>
struct Apply_aux
{
  template<typename F, typename T, typename... X>
  static int apply(F f, const T& t, X... x)
  {
    return Apply_aux<N-1>::apply(f, t, std::get<N-1>(t), x...);
  }
};
```

Alas, this is an incomplete solution to the original problem.

Comment: Illegal or not, the ICE should not happen. File a bug.

Comment: The bug has been filed.  Please see GCC Bugzilla Bug 44167 (http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=44167).  Cheers

Answer (score 2):

I tried you code on g++4.6. It does not compile due to missing implementation. However, one way to achieve generality would be to wrap the free standing function in a std::function wrapper and use `result_type` typedef like below.

```
template<typename F, typename T>
typename F::result_type apply(F f, const T& t)
{
  ...
}
int f(int p1, double p2, std::string p3) 
{
  std::cout << "int=" << p1 << ", double=" << p2 << ", string=" << p3 << std::endl;
  return 1;
}
int main()
{
  std::tuple<int, double, char const*> tup(1, 2.0, "xxx");
  std::function<int (int, double, char const *)> func = &f; 
  std::cout << apply(func, tup) << std::endl;

}
```

Comment: Elegant solution.  Unfortunately, I wasn't able to get it to work in GCC 4.4.3.  I'm not sure why.  I'll post here if I find anything new.  Cheers