# C++ metaprogramming

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

I have the following problem:

Suppose I have some basic counter `class Counter`. And suppose we also have some sets of *classes, that can be counted.* Let's name some of them `class CountedA` and `class CountedB`.

Now, every class, which can *be counted (such as `CountedA` and `CountedB`)* has the following statically declared parts: *one `enum` and one `int` part, that acts like a part of **counted data***.

For example, it's declaration could look the following way:

```
enum CountedType { A, B };

template <CountedType Type, int N>
class Counted { };

// Now we can declare 'CountedA' and 'CountedB'
typedef Counted<A, 25> CountedA;
typedef Counted<B, 7> CountedB;
```

*Now, the declaration of the counter:*

```
// C++0x variadic or simply bunch of 'typename XX' definitions for C++03
template <typename T0, typename T1, typename ...>
class Counter
{
   // I don't know how to implement this
   // for now!
   int GetTotalN() { ... }

   // Retrieve the corresponding type
   // so that GetTypeAt<0> returns
   // enum from 'T0'
   template <int Pos>
   CountedType GetTypeAt() { ... }
};
```

I want to be able to write something like:

```
class RealCounter : public Counter<CountedA, CountedB> { };
```

And use it the following way:

```
RealCounter counter;
int n = counter.GetTotalN();
CountedType type = counter.GetTypeAt<0>();
```

Now, I'm pretty sure that this can be done. **But what's the best way of implementing it? *(don't ask me why would I need such crazy kind of things :)***

Does `boost::mpl` offer something for this case?

Thank you.

---

*Small update:*

In this particular example, `GetTotalN()` should return `25 + 7`.

If we add, for example, `typedef Counted<C, 2> CountedC`, then the result for

```
RealCounter : public Counter<CountedA, CountedB, CountedC>
```

should become `25 + 7 + 2`.

Comment: Do you have the book _C++ Templates: The Complete Guide_? If you are going to be doing anything remotely interesting with templates, you should find a copy.

Comment: What should the value of `n` be?  25 + 7?

Comment: @aschepler Well, in this sample, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's C++03 code which works (for up to 10 template arguments).  The main trick is giving class Counter a multiple inheritance, and passing objects of type Counter to function templates which must select a base class.  The actual summation is done recursively.

**Counter.hpp**

```
enum CountedType { A, B };

template <CountedType Type, int N>
struct Counted {};

struct DummyCounted {};

template <int Pos, typename T>
struct IndexedType {};

template <unsigned int Terms>
struct PartialSum
{
  template <typename CounterT>
  static int getSum(const CounterT& ctr)
  { return PartialSum<Terms-1>::getSum(ctr) + ctr.template GetNAt<Terms>(); }
};

template <> struct PartialSum<0U>
{
  template <typename CounterT>
  static int getSum(const CounterT& ctr)
  { return ctr.template GetNAt<0>(); }
};

template <typename T0, typename T1=DummyCounted,
  typename T2=DummyCounted, typename T3=DummyCounted,
  typename T4=DummyCounted, typename T5=DummyCounted,
  typename T6=DummyCounted, typename T7=DummyCounted,
  typename T8=DummyCounted, typename T9=DummyCounted>
class Counter :
  public IndexedType<0, T0>, public IndexedType<1, T1>,
  public IndexedType<2, T2>, public IndexedType<3, T3>,
  public IndexedType<4, T4>, public IndexedType<5, T5>,
  public IndexedType<6, T6>, public IndexedType<7, T7>,
  public IndexedType<8, T8>, public IndexedType<9, T9>
{
public:
  static int GetTotalN() {
    return PartialSum<9>().getSum( Counter() );
  }

  template <int Pos>
  static CountedType GetTypeAt() { return _getTypeAt<Pos>( Counter() ); }

  template <int Pos>
  static int GetNAt() { return _getNAt<Pos>( Counter() ); }

private:
  template <int Pos, CountedType Type, int N>
  static CountedType _getTypeAt(const IndexedType<Pos, Counted<Type,N> >&)
  { return Type; }

  template <int Pos, CountedType Type, int N>
  static int _getNAt(const IndexedType<Pos, Counted<Type,N> >&)
  { return N; }

  template <int Pos>
  static int _getNAt(const IndexedType<Pos, DummyCounted>&)
  { return 0; }

};
```

**Counter.cpp**

```
#include "Counter.hpp"
#include <iostream>

typedef Counted<A, 25> CountedA;
typedef Counted<B, 7> CountedB;

class RealCounter : public Counter<CountedA, CountedB> {};

int main()
{
  RealCounter counter;
  int n = counter.GetTotalN();
  CountedType type = counter.GetTypeAt<0>();

  std::cout << "n is " << n
            << "\ntype check is " << (type == A) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
n is 32
type check is 1
```

That C++0x variadic template stuff looks interesting, but I haven't taken a good look at it yet.  But I do think in C++0x, all this example's functions (except `main` of course) could be `constexpr`.

Comment: I would not use public inheritance here. It's clearly an abuse as far as I can see it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you need to embed those parameters in the templates arguments and not simply in a constructor since they are all the same types for each "derived" CountedA/B types.

Anyways you can embed the resulting types into a std::tuple as shown in the link below (see Message class for an example). Then create a variadic template function similar to the applyTuple version in the link below that will add all your integer arguments and return the final result once all arguments have been unrolled. As for the returning of the enum value for the item in "Pos" simply call the get( tuple ).getEnum() or .value to get it.

[How do I expand a tuple into variadic template function's arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687490/c0x-how-do-i-expand-a-tuple-into-variadic-template-function-arguments/1547118#1547118)