# List of functions to be called. Have to have same signature. Better implementation?

Tags: c++, delegates, function-pointers

My program reads in "commands" from a text file such as "w test.txt 5" for write to test.txt the number 5 or "r test.txt" for reading from test.txt. Instead of having a horrible switch loop to maintain I have a called aFunction which has function member

```
string name;
void (*thefunction)(char *argsIn[], char *out);
```

So I have a string name and a function pointer. Outside the class I have a

```
vector<aFunction> funcVec
```

which holds all the functions. When I read a command in from a text file the code looks through funcVec to find the correct function to call

So when funcVec.name = command read in

```
(*funcVec[i].theFunction(other values from the text file, output);
```

For example I may have the funciton `read(char *argsIn[], char *out)`
where argsIn would be an array containing test.txt, 5 and char out might be a 1 or 0 depending on whether the operation was successful.

However I don't really like this very much because all functions now have to have the signature (char *argsIn[], char *out) and it's up to the function to know what each parameter in the list means.

Can anyone think of a better implementation? Surely software that supports scripting has to cope with this sort of thing?

Answer (score 3):

*Note: you'd better use `std::string` and `std::vector`*

The `Command` pattern is normally the way to do this, this allows "packing" the input/output arguments in the object and presenting a "blank" execution method `void operator()()` ensuring a common interface.

**EDIT:** a demonstration of Command (generic).

Define some commands:

```
struct Command: boost::noncopyable
{
  virtual void do() = 0;
  virtual void undo() = 0;
  virtual ~Command() {}
};

class SaveFile: public Command
{
public:
  explicit SaveFile(FileHandle f, Changes c): _file(file), _changes(c) {}

  virtual void do() { _file.apply(_changes); }
  virtual void undo() { _file.revert(_changes); }

private:
  FileHandle _file;
  Changes _changes;
};

class OpenFile: public Command
{
public:
  explicit OpenFile(std::string filename): _filename(filename) {}

  FileHandle get() const { return _file; }

  virtual void do() { _file.load(_filename); }
  virtual void undo() { /*nothing to be done*/ }

private:
  std::string _filename;
  FileHandle _file;
};
```

Example use of two stacks of actions: those to be performed, and those that have been performed.

```
typedef std::stack<std::unique_ptr<Command>> CommandStack;

void transaction(CommandStack& todo)
{
  CommandStack undo;
  try
  {
    while(!todo.empty())
    {
      todo.top()->do();
      undo.push(std::move(todo.top()));
      todo.pop();
    }
  }
  catch(std::exception const&)
  {
    while(!undo.empty())
    {
      undo.top()->do();
      undo.pop();
    }
  }
} // transaction
```

Comment: Matthieu, the disadvantage of the command pattern applied this way is that it leaves breaking down of the command line into the real arguments to each command's implementation. That's tedious and error-prone, so I can see why you skipped over this. `:)`

Comment: @sbi: on the other hand, isn't every command susceptible to have its own set of commands ?

Comment: Yes, but it has to convert all of it's arguments from a list of strings. This is tedious and error-prone. I have just experienced it while doing exactly this in C#, where template's aren't half as powerful as in C++. Maintaining three dozen commands this way is a major pain in the donkey, even though I liberally sprinkled the whole thing with a lot of helper functions. OTOH, I know there is a way to extract that string cracking, because I've read about it and saw the code. It's not easy, though.

Answer (score 1):

What you have to do reading these commands is threefold:

1. Find out *which* function to call.
2. Convert the list of argument strings into the arguments of the *right type*.
3. *Call the function* passing those arguments to do the whatever needs to be done.

To abstract #2 is pretty hard, as C++ has very little support for dealing with different types that are known only at runtime, but it's not impossible.

I have once seen an article where someone used template-meta programming to find out about the parameters of registered function, and then generate the code that breaks down string list into the matching arguments. Functions were kept in a map of key strings to function pointers (using type erasure to store functions with different signatures).

---

Here's a sketch about how to use type erasure to store different function pointer sin a map:

```
struct func_base {
    virtual void operator()(std::istream&)  const = 0;
};

template< typename F >
class function : public func_base {
public:
    function(F f) : func_(f) {}
    void operator()(std::string& arguments) const;
private:
    func_base func_;
};

typedef std::map< std::string, std::shared_ptr<func_base> >  func_map; 

template< typename F >
void addFunc(func_map& map, const std::string& keyword, F f)
{
    assert(map.find(keyword) == map.end());
    map[keyword] = std::shared_ptr<func_base>(new function<T>(f));
}
```

That would leave `function<F>::operator()()` to chop the arguments into individual strings, convert them into the appropriate types, and then call the function with them.

---

Chopping the string into a list of arguments shouldn't be a problem, so I'll skip over that. The hard part is calling a function with the right parameters given that list. Note that the function's type is known within `function<F>::operator()()` *at compile-time*, so you have the whole of template-meta programming techniques at your disposal.

ISTR that article did this by creating tuples according to the function's parameter list and had the means to call any function given such a tuple. Here's you could create such tuples with recursive calls:

```
template< typename Tuple >
Tuple convert_args(const std::string& line)
{
  Tuple result;
  // I don't know tuples well enough yet, so here's just an 
  // algorithm rather than code:


  // 1. read first argument from line and put it into tuple's first element
  // 2. call yourself for a tuple that consists of the remaining elements of Tuple
  // 3. fill the remaining tuple elements from the result of #2

  return result
}
```

Then use traits to call those functions:

```
template<typename F>
struct func_traits;

template<typename R, typename A1>// function taking one arg
struct func_traits<R(*)()> {
  typedef std::tuple<A1> arg_list;

  static R call(R(*f)(), const arg_list& args)
  {
    return f(std::get<0>(arg_list)); // how do you access an element in a tuple
  }
};

template<typename R, typename A1, typename A2>// function taking two args
struct func_traits<R(*)()> {
  typedef std::tuple<A1,A2> arg_list;

  static R call(R(*f)(), const arg_list& args)
  {
    return f(std::get<0>(arg_list), std::get<1>(arg_list));
  }
};

// repeat for as many args as you'll need
```

Comment: Do you remember where you saw that article? I would be interested in reading that one.

Comment: @diverscuba23: No, unfortunately not. (I couldn't find it now that I searched.)

Comment: you might want to see this [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/687490/c0x-how-do-i-expand-a-tuple-into-variadic-template-function-arguments/1547118#1547118) for a generalized way you could deal with any number of arguments... don't have to the time right now to completely work it in with what you posted though...

Answer (score 0):

A very simple implementation would be using `std::map` instead of `std:vector` which you've used:

```
typedef void (*FunctionType)(char *argsIn[], char *out); 

std::map<std::string, FunctionType> functionMap;

//populate the functionMap
//key = commandName, value = function to be called;
functionMap["write"] = WriteFunc;
functionMap["read"]= ReadFunc;

//later use this map as
functionMap[commandName](arguments, output);
```