# Unpacking Argument List with Variadic Template

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-functions

I'm trying to create a C++ convenience wrapper around an old C-API that uses an opaque data type.  There's one particular C-function which takes a format string, along with a variable number of arguments using the C `<stdarg.h>` facilities.  As part of my wrapper, I want to be able to pass an arbitrary number of arguments (including C++ objects) to this function.  However, since obviously the `<stdarg.h>` facilities can't work with non-POD data, I created a templated conversion function which converts C++ objects (like `std::string`) into POD equivalents.

I thought this whole thing would be an easy exercise using C++0x variadic templates, but I'm having difficulty figuring out how to write this function in a way that properly unrolls the argument pack while applying my conversion function to each argument.

What I have so far is:

```
   template <class T, class... Args>
   void apply(OPAQUE* object, const char* fmt_string, T&& val, Args&&... args)
   {
      apply(object, fmt_string, Convert(val), args...);
   }

   template <class... Args>
   void apply(OPAQUE* object, const char* fmt_string, Args&&... args)
   {
      C_API_Function_Call(object, fmt_string, args...);
   }
```

Of course, this doesn't work because the recursive function call never actually unpacks the `Args...`, so it just recurses until the stack overflows.  I can't figure out how to make it unpack the arguments while *also* passing the current argument to the `Convert` function, and then recursively passing along the result.

Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I think you need the same syntax as when you do perfect forwarding :

```
template <class... Args>
void apply(OPAQUE* object, const char* fmt_string, Args&&... args)
{
   C_API_Function_Call(object, fmt_string, Convert(std::forward<Arg>(args))...);
}
```

The ellipsis ... can be placed at the right of an expression containing the argument pack, and not only directly at the right of the argument pack itself.

So,  :
func(args...) expand to func(arg1, arg2, arg3, [...] , argN)
func(args)... expand to func(arg1), func(arg2), [...] , func(argN)

Comment: Not sure why the OP hasn't yet changed his opinion and accepted this answer. The currently accepted one is obviously wrong, and yours is correct. +1 Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

At the moment C++0x draft does not provide any solution for that. Because problem is similar to expanding tuples, you can read [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687490/c0x-how-do-i-expand-a-tuple-into-variadic-template-function-arguments) and write similar expanding function.