# Pretty-print std::tuple

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples, variadic-templates

This is a follow-up to my previous question on [pretty-printing STL containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850473/pretty-print-c-stl-containers), for which we managed to develop a very elegant and fully general solution.

---

In this next step, I would like to include pretty-printing for `std::tuple<Args...>`, using variadic templates (so this is strictly C++11). For `std::pair<S,T>`, I simply say

```
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & o, const std::pair<S,T> & p)
{
  return o << "(" << p.first << ", " << p.second << ")";
}
```

What is the analogous construction for printing a tuple?

I've tried various bits of template argument stack unpacking, passing indices around and using SFINAE to discover when I'm at the last element, but with no success. I shan't burden you with my broken code; the problem description is hopefully straight-forward enough. Essentially, I'd like the following behaviour:

```
auto a = std::make_tuple(5, "Hello", -0.1);
std::cout << a << std::endl; // prints: (5, "Hello", -0.1)
```

Bonus points for including the same level of generality (char/wchar_t, pair delimiters) as the the previous question!

Comment: Has someone put any of the code here into a library? Or even an .hpp-with-everything-in which one could grab and use?

Comment: @einpoklum: Maybe [cxx-prettyprint](https://louisdx.github.io/cxx-prettyprint/)? That's what I needed that code for.

Comment: Great question, and +1 for "I shan't burden you with my broken code", although I am surprised it seems to have actually succeede in fending off the mindless "what have you tried" hordes.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Yay, [indices](http://loungecpp.wikidot.com/tips-and-tricks:indices)~

```
namespace aux{
template<std::size_t...> struct seq{};

template<std::size_t N, std::size_t... Is>
struct gen_seq : gen_seq<N-1, N-1, Is...>{};

template<std::size_t... Is>
struct gen_seq<0, Is...> : seq<Is...>{};

template<class Ch, class Tr, class Tuple, std::size_t... Is>
void print_tuple(std::basic_ostream<Ch,Tr>& os, Tuple const& t, seq<Is...>){
  using swallow = int[];
  (void)swallow{0, (void(os << (Is == 0? "" : ", ") << std::get<Is>(t)), 0)...};
}
} // aux::

template<class Ch, class Tr, class... Args>
auto operator<<(std::basic_ostream<Ch, Tr>& os, std::tuple<Args...> const& t)
    -> std::basic_ostream<Ch, Tr>&
{
  os << "(";
  aux::print_tuple(os, t, aux::gen_seq<sizeof...(Args)>());
  return os << ")";
}
```

[Live example on Ideone.](http://ideone.com/Rihfre)

---

For the delimiter stuff, just add these partial specializations:

```
// Delimiters for tuple
template<class... Args>
struct delimiters<std::tuple<Args...>, char> {
  static const delimiters_values<char> values;
};

template<class... Args>
const delimiters_values<char> delimiters<std::tuple<Args...>, char>::values = { "(", ", ", ")" };

template<class... Args>
struct delimiters<std::tuple<Args...>, wchar_t> {
  static const delimiters_values<wchar_t> values;
};

template<class... Args>
const delimiters_values<wchar_t> delimiters<std::tuple<Args...>, wchar_t>::values = { L"(", L", ", L")" };
```

and change the `operator<<` and `print_tuple` accordingly:

```
template<class Ch, class Tr, class... Args>
auto operator<<(std::basic_ostream<Ch, Tr>& os, std::tuple<Args...> const& t)
    -> std::basic_ostream<Ch, Tr>&
{
  typedef std::tuple<Args...> tuple_t;
  if(delimiters<tuple_t, Ch>::values.prefix != 0)
    os << delimiters<tuple_t,char>::values.prefix;

  print_tuple(os, t, aux::gen_seq<sizeof...(Args)>());

  if(delimiters<tuple_t, Ch>::values.postfix != 0)
    os << delimiters<tuple_t,char>::values.postfix;

  return os;
}
```

And

```
template<class Ch, class Tr, class Tuple, std::size_t... Is>
void print_tuple(std::basic_ostream<Ch, Tr>& os, Tuple const& t, seq<Is...>){
  using swallow = int[];
  char const* delim = delimiters<Tuple, Ch>::values.delimiter;
  if(!delim) delim = "";
  (void)swallow{0, (void(os << (Is == 0? "" : delim) << std::get<Is>(t)), 0)...};
}
```

Comment: @Kerrek: I'm currently testing & fixing myself, I get weird output on Ideone though.

Comment: I think you're also confusing streams and strings. You're writing something akin to "std::cout << std::cout". In other words, `TuplePrinter` doesn't have an `operator<<`.

Comment: @Kerrek: Yeah, I did some pretty strange stuff.. New version is edited, and works like requested. :P

Comment: Grand, now it works! I'll now try to include this into the pretty printer project from the previous question. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @Kerrek: To add the delimiters from the previous question, you just need another partial spec on tuples. Included that now. The rest (`basic_ostream` etc) should be easy from here on.

Comment: Maybe doesn't work so well with empty tuples, but that's easy enough to fix with another specialization or a size check in the top-level operator<<...?

Comment: I wasn't going to deal with empty tuples, I'm happy enough that it works for oneples ;-) Hey, could one of you non-GNU people check if the template aliases in the pretty printer project work? Those would make defining custom delimiters a lot easier.

Comment: @Kerrek: You can define template aliases in C++03 too, as seen [here](http://ideone.com/oKwBU). :)

Comment: Haha, jehova :-) Well, if you look at the prettyprinter.h code, I want a convenient way for users to define those delimiter classes for TChar = {char, wchar_t}, so I basically want to provide an "sdelims" and "wsdelims" shortcut, without making stuff more verbose. C++0x template aliases sound like the way to go, but I'm open to suggestions. Mind you, my sample case already contains a demo of custom delimiters, so the goal here is to be strictly more elegant.

Comment: Can't we replace `struct TuplePrinter` with just templated functions when using C++0x/C++11?

Comment: @Nordlöw: No, we still can't easily, because functions *still* can't be partially specialized, but see my update on ways to circumvent that, even in C++03.

Comment: If you don't have variadic templates, you can use class Tuple instead of class... Args and std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value instead of sizeof...(Args).

Comment: @Thomas: You can't just use `class Tuple` for the `operator<<` overload - it would get picked for any and all things. It would need a constraint, which kinda implies the need for some kind of variadic arguments.

Comment: Dang, my compilation hadn't completed when I posted.  Guess I need to port boost/tuple_io.hpp to std::tuple.

Comment: @Xeo: The code has two problems: a) `operator<<` should return `std::basic_ostream<Ch,Traits>&` instead of `std::ostream&` and b) it does not work with empty tuples, i.e., `std::tuple<>`.

Comment: @DanielFrey: The return type was a fragment from refactoring, thanks for catching that. And yeah, empty tuple is currently broken, but can easily be fixed. In fact, I should probably rewrite this thing to just use the indices trick.

Comment: @Xeo: Using indices won't be easy here, but try it. Main problem will be order of evaluation.

Comment: @DanielFrey: That's a solved problem, list-initialization guarantees left-to-right order: `swallow{(os << get<Is>(t))...};`.

Comment: @Xeo: Thanks to your hint to use initializer-lists to guarantee the order of execution, I have an elegant version with indices ready. Shall I modify your answer or write a separate one?

Comment: @Xeo I borrowed your swallow for [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence), if you don't mind.

Comment: Some nitpicking... You don't want to define operators in the wrong namespace and you cannot define this one in the right namespace (`::std`). It would be better as a function that is called (possibly qualified) to avoid lookup failing to locate the operator.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Really, you should have a namespace `print_pretty` with an expression template `pretty<T>` with an overloaded `<<` that recursively handles pretty printing iterables and tuple-likes, falling back on `ostream << t`, and then a Koenig `std` enabled `ostream << to_string(t)`, with max line length and indenting and long list tableification, and the like.  You end up with a library, not a SO answer.

Answer (score 31):

In C++17 we can accomplish this with a little less code by taking advantage of [Fold expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold), particularly a unary left fold:

```
template<class TupType, size_t... I>
void print(const TupType& _tup, std::index_sequence<I...>)
{
    std::cout << "(";
    (..., (std::cout << (I == 0? "" : ", ") << std::get<I>(_tup)));
    std::cout << ")\n";
}

template<class... T>
void print (const std::tuple<T...>& _tup)
{
    print(_tup, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(T)>());
}
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5d86aa176f657702) outputs:

> (5, Hello, -0.1)

given

```
auto a = std::make_tuple(5, "Hello", -0.1);
print(a);
```

---

### Explanation

Our unary left fold is of the form

```
... op pack
```

where `op` in our scenario is the comma operator, and `pack` is the expression containing our tuple in an unexpanded context like:

```
(..., (std::cout << std::get<I>(myTuple))
```

So if I have a tuple like so:

```
auto myTuple = std::make_tuple(5, "Hello", -0.1);
```

And a [`std::integer_sequence`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) whose values are specified by a non-type template (see above code)

```
size_t... I
```

Then the expression

```
(..., (std::cout << std::get<I>(myTuple))
```

Gets expanded into

```
((std::cout << std::get<0>(myTuple)), (std::cout << std::get<1>(myTuple))), (std::cout << std::get<2>(myTuple));
```

Which will print

> 5Hello-0.1

Which is gross, so we need to do some more trickery to add a comma separator to be printed first unless it's the first element.

To accomplish that, we modify the `pack` portion of the fold expression to print `" ,"` if the current index `I` is not the first, hence the `(I == 0? "" : ", ")` portion<sup>*</sup>:

```
(..., (std::cout << (I == 0? "" : ", ") << std::get<I>(_tup)));
```

And now we'll get

> 5, Hello, -0.1

Which looks nicer (Note: I wanted similar output as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31116392/27678))

<sup>*Note: You could do the comma separation in a variety of ways than what I ended up with. I initially added commas conditionally *after* instead of *before* by testing against `std::tuple_size<TupType>::value - 1`, but that was too long, so I tested instead against `sizeof...(I) - 1`, but in the end I copied [Xeo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6245777/27678) and we ended up with what I've got.</sup>

Comment: You could also use `if constexpr` for the base case.

Comment: @KerrekSB: For deciding whether to print a comma? Not a bad idea, wish it came in ternary.

Comment: A conditional expression is already a potential constant expression, so what you have is already good :-)

Comment: sorry, do you mind elaborating what kind of expression `((std::cout << std::get<0>(myTuple)), (std::cout << std::get<1>(myTuple))), (std::cout << std::get<2>(myTuple));` is?  Haven't seen a list of comma-separated `ostream`...

Comment: @HCSF: Sure, thanks for asking. this is three invocations of `cout << something` separated by the [comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other). The comma operator enforces that the individual expressions are evaluated in order, and the result of the expression (the returned stream) is discarded. We do it this way so that a fold expression can work in such a way that a pack expansion `...` results in one function call per argument in the pack (fold expressions only work over operators). Hope that helps.

Answer (score 21):

I got this working fine in C++11 (gcc 4.7). There are I am sure some pitfalls I have not considered but I think the code is easy to read and and not complicated. The only thing that may be strange is the "guard" struct tuple_printer that ensure that we terminate when the last element is reached. The other strange thing may be sizeof...(Types) that return the number of types in Types type pack. It is used to determine the index of the last element (size...(Types) - 1).

```
template<typename Type, unsigned N, unsigned Last>
struct tuple_printer {

    static void print(std::ostream& out, const Type& value) {
        out << std::get<N>(value) << ", ";
        tuple_printer<Type, N + 1, Last>::print(out, value);
    }
};

template<typename Type, unsigned N>
struct tuple_printer<Type, N, N> {

    static void print(std::ostream& out, const Type& value) {
        out << std::get<N>(value);
    }

};

template<typename... Types>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const std::tuple<Types...>& value) {
    out << "(";
    tuple_printer<std::tuple<Types...>, 0, sizeof...(Types) - 1>::print(out, value);
    out << ")";
    return out;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that looks sensible - perhaps with another specialization for the empty tuple, for completeness.

Comment: @KerrekSB, There isn't a simple way to print tuples in c++?, in python function implicitly returns a tuple and you can simply print them, in c++ in order to return the multiple variables from a function I need to pack them using `std::make_tuple()`. but at the time of printing it in `main()`, it throws a bunch of errors!, Any suggestions on simpler way to print the tuples?

Comment: @Anu you have answered yourself, pick another programming language, or wait for a newer c++. Overall, printing a tuple is not that important.

Answer (score 18):

I'm surprised the implementation on [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple_cat) has not already been posted here, so I'll do it for posterity. It's hidden in the doc for `std::tuple_cat` so it's not easy to find. It uses a guard struct like some of the other solutions here, but I think theirs is ultimately simpler and easier-to-follow.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <string>

// helper function to print a tuple of any size
template<class Tuple, std::size_t N>
struct TuplePrinter {
    static void print(const Tuple& t) 
    {
        TuplePrinter<Tuple, N-1>::print(t);
        std::cout << ", " << std::get<N-1>(t);
    }
};

template<class Tuple>
struct TuplePrinter<Tuple, 1> {
    static void print(const Tuple& t) 
    {
        std::cout << std::get<0>(t);
    }
};

template<class... Args>
void print(const std::tuple<Args...>& t) 
{
    std::cout << "(";
    TuplePrinter<decltype(t), sizeof...(Args)>::print(t);
    std::cout << ")\n";
}
// end helper function
```

And a test:

```
int main()
{
    std::tuple<int, std::string, float> t1(10, "Test", 3.14);
    int n = 7;
    auto t2 = std::tuple_cat(t1, std::make_pair("Foo", "bar"), t1, std::tie(n));
    n = 10;
    print(t2);
}
```

Output:

> (10, Test, 3.14, Foo, bar, 10, Test, 3.14, 10)

[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/A1LNMu)

Answer (score 9):

Leveraging on `std::apply` (C++17) we can drop the `std::index_sequence` and define a single function:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

template<class Ch, class Tr, class... Args>
auto& operator<<(std::basic_ostream<Ch, Tr>& os, std::tuple<Args...> const& t) {
  std::apply([&os](auto&&... args) {((os << args << " "), ...);}, t);
  return os;
}
```

Or, slightly embellished with the help of a stringstream:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

template<class Ch, class Tr, class... Args>
auto& operator<<(std::basic_ostream<Ch, Tr>& os, std::tuple<Args...> const& t) {
  std::basic_stringstream<Ch, Tr> ss;
  ss << "[ ";
  std::apply([&ss](auto&&... args) {((ss << args << ", "), ...);}, t);
  ss.seekp(-2, ss.cur);
  ss << " ]";
  return os << ss.str();
}
```

Comment: Anyone using `const&` deserves an upvote (plus I used this solution).

Comment: This one is cool, but gives me build errors for a more complicated tuple. I think it's not linking the std::function in this but it was a very long compile error on mac os clang. `template<typename TResult, typename... TInputParams>
std::tuple<std::string, TResult, std::tuple<TInputParams...>, std::optional<std::function<bool(const TResult& expected, const TResult& actual)>>, std::optional<std::function<void()>>, std::optional<std::function<void()>>, bool>` It's still my preferred solution for now.

Answer (score 4):

Based on AndyG code, for C++17

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

template<class TupType, size_t... I>
std::ostream& tuple_print(std::ostream& os,
                          const TupType& _tup, std::index_sequence<I...>)
{
    os << "(";
    (..., (os << (I == 0 ? "" : ", ") << std::get<I>(_tup)));
    os << ")";
    return os;
}

template<class... T>
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const std::tuple<T...>& _tup)
{
    return tuple_print(os, _tup, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(T)>());
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "deep tuple: " << std::make_tuple("Hello",
                  0.1, std::make_tuple(1,2,3,"four",5.5), 'Z')
              << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

with output:

```
deep tuple: (Hello, 0.1, (1, 2, 3, four, 5.5), Z)
```

Answer (score 3):

Based upon example on [The C++ Programming Language By Bjarne Stroustrup, page 817](https://books.google.com/books?id=0klsAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA817):

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
template<size_t N>
struct print_tuple{
    template<typename... T>static typename std::enable_if<(N<sizeof...(T))>::type
    print(std::ostream& os, const std::tuple<T...>& t) {
        char quote = (std::is_convertible<decltype(std::get<N>(t)), std::string>::value) ? '"' : 0;
        os << ", " << quote << std::get<N>(t) << quote;
        print_tuple<N+1>::print(os,t);
        }
    template<typename... T>static typename std::enable_if<!(N<sizeof...(T))>::type
    print(std::ostream&, const std::tuple<T...>&) {
        }
    };
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const std::tuple<>&) {
    return os << "()";
    }
template<typename T0, typename ...T> std::ostream&
operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::tuple<T0, T...>& t){
    char quote = (std::is_convertible<T0, std::string>::value) ? '"' : 0;
    os << '(' << quote << std::get<0>(t) << quote;
    print_tuple<1>::print(os,t);
    return os << ')';
    }

int main(){
    std::tuple<> a;
    auto b = std::make_tuple("One meatball");
    std::tuple<int,double,std::string> c(1,1.2,"Tail!");
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << b << std::endl;
    std::cout << c << std::endl;
    }
```

Output:

```
()
("One meatball")
(1, 1.2, "Tail!")
```

Answer (score 3):

I like DarioP's answer, but stringstream uses heap. This can be avoided:

```
template <class... Args>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, std::tuple<Args...> const& t) {
  os << "(";
  bool first = true;
  std::apply([&os, &first](auto&&... args) {
    auto print = [&] (auto&& val) {
      if (!first)
        os << ",";
      (os << " " << val);
      first = false;
    };
    (print(args), ...);
  }, t);
  os << " )";
  return os;
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer, however parenthesis in `(os << " " << val)` aren't needed - it's not a fold expression.

Answer (score 1):

Another one, similar to @Tony Olsson's, including a specialization for the empty tuple, as suggested by @Kerrek SB.

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

template<class Ch, class Tr, size_t I, typename... TS>
struct tuple_printer
{
    static void print(std::basic_ostream<Ch,Tr> & out, const std::tuple<TS...> & t)
    {
        tuple_printer<Ch, Tr, I-1, TS...>::print(out, t);
        if (I < sizeof...(TS))
            out << ",";
        out << std::get<I>(t);
    }
};
template<class Ch, class Tr, typename... TS>
struct tuple_printer<Ch, Tr, 0, TS...>
{
    static void print(std::basic_ostream<Ch,Tr> & out, const std::tuple<TS...> & t)
    {
        out << std::get<0>(t);
    }
};
template<class Ch, class Tr, typename... TS>
struct tuple_printer<Ch, Tr, -1, TS...>
{
    static void print(std::basic_ostream<Ch,Tr> & out, const std::tuple<TS...> & t)
    {}
};
template<class Ch, class Tr, typename... TS>
std::ostream & operator<<(std::basic_ostream<Ch,Tr> & out, const std::tuple<TS...> & t)
{
    out << "(";
    tuple_printer<Ch, Tr, sizeof...(TS) - 1, TS...>::print(out, t);
    return out << ")";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code I recently made for printing a tuple.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

using namespace std;

template<typename... Ts>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& output, const tuple<Ts...> t) {
    output << '(';
    apply([&](auto&&... args) {
        ((cout << args << ", "), ...);
    }, t);
    output << "\b\b";
    output << ')';
    return output;
}
```

Using your example case:

```
auto a = std::make_tuple(5, "Hello", -0.1); 
cout << a << '\n'; // (5, Hello, -0.1)
```

Comment: It actually prints (5, Hello, -0.1, )

Answer (score 1):

I see answers using `std::index_sequence` with C++17, however, that's not the road I'd go personally. I'd rather go for recursion and `constexpr if`:

```cpp
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

template<std::size_t I, class... Ts>
void doPrintTuple(const std::tuple<Ts...>& tuples) {
    if constexpr (I == sizeof...(Ts)) {
        std::cout << ')';
    }
    else {
        std::cout << std::get<I>(tuples);
        if constexpr (I + 1 != sizeof...(Ts)) {
            std::cout << ", ";
        }
        doPrintTuple<I + 1>(tuples);
    }
}

template<class... Ts>
void printTuple(const std::tuple<Ts...>& tuples) {
    std::cout << '(';
    doPrintTuple<0>(tuples);
}

int main() {
    auto tup = std::make_tuple(1, "hello", 4.5);
    printTuple(tup);
}
```

Output:

```
(1, hello, 4.5)
```

Note that this does not work for nested tuples.

Answer (score 1):

**Starting with C++23** you can use [`std::format`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format) or [`std::print`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/print) (or [`std::println`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/println)) to do this.

```cpp
#include <print>

int main() {
    std::print("{}", std::make_tuple(1, 5.5, "text"));
}
```

```
(1, 5.5, "text")
```

If you need the result as `std::string` use [`std::format`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format). Note that formatting tuples requires C++23 support, specifically the implementation of [P2286R8](https://wg21.link/P2286R8) (check [C++23 library features](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support#C.2B.2B23_library_features)).

```cpp
#include <format>

int main() {
    std::string text = std::format("{}", std::make_tuple(1, 5.5, "text"));
}
```

---

**If you are stuck to an older standard**, you can use the [fmt](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) library to [print tuples](https://fmt.dev/latest/api.html#ranges-api).

```cpp
#include <fmt/ranges.h>

int main() {
    // direct print
    fmt::print("{}", std::make_tuple(1, 5.5, "text"));

    // create std::string object
    std::string str = fmt::format("{}", std::make_tuple(1, 5.5, "text"));
}
```

Comment: Finally, something reasonable, without bending over backwards!

Answer (score 0):

One thing I dislike about the previous answers that use fold expressions is that they use index sequences or flags to keep track of the first element, which removes much of the benefit of nice clean fold expressions.

Here is an example that does not need indexing, but achieves a similar result. (Not as sophisticated as some of the others, but more could be added.)

The technique is to use what the fold already gives you: a special case for one element. I.e., one element fold just expands to `elem[0]`, then 2 elements is `elem[0] + elem[1]`, where `+` is some operation. What we want is for one element to write just that element to the stream, and for more elements, do the same, but join each one with an additional write of ", ". So mapping this on to the c++ fold, we want each element to be the action of writing some object to the stream. We want our `+` operation to be to intersperse two writes with a ", " write. So first transform our tuple sequence into a sequence of write actions, `CommaJoiner` I have called it, then for that action add an `operator+` to join two actions in the way we want, adding a ", " in between:

```cpp
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct CommaJoiner
{
    T thunk;
    explicit CommaJoiner(const T& t) : thunk(t) {}

    template <typename S>
    auto operator+(CommaJoiner<S> const& b) const
    {
        auto joinedThunk = [a=this->thunk, b=b.thunk] (std::ostream& os) {
            a(os);
            os << ", ";
            b(os);
        };
        return CommaJoiner<decltype(joinedThunk)>{joinedThunk};
    }

    void operator()(std::ostream& os) const
    {
        thunk(os);
    }

};

template <typename ...Ts>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, std::tuple<Ts...> tup)
{
    std::apply([&](auto ...ts) {
        return (... + CommaJoiner{[=](auto&os) {os << ts;}});}, tup)(os);

    return os;
}

int main() {
    auto tup = std::make_tuple(1, 2.0, "Hello");
    std::cout << tup << std::endl;
}
```

A cursory glance at godbolt suggests that this compiles quite well too, all the thunks calls being flattened.

This will need a second overload to deal with an empty tuple however.