# Using boost::mpl::vector to create variadic templates?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-mpl, boost-tuples

I'm stuck with C++03 for now, and I want to create a global function that accepts any number of *type-safe* arguments (up to a reasonable limit if necessary, like 9).

I have access to the full boost library in my code base, so I'm hoping `boost::mpl::vector` can be useful here. I also don't want this to be too inconvenient to write. Syntax at the call site should be simple like so:

```
LogDebugMessage("Number of cats and dogs:", m_myPets->NumCats(), m_myPets->NumDogs());
```

What would be the best way to implement this, in a type safe way?

EDIT

I also realize I could use template specialization for this, but I don't want to end up defining the same struct 9 times, one for each additional template parameter. That's just too messy for this. I'd like to avoid that if at all possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way would be 9 overloads. :P

The easiest way for you, however, would rather be `boost::tuple` instead of using `boost::mpl`, since `mpl` is mostly compile-time only. The call site (user) would then write something like

```
LogDebugMessage("Number of cats and dogs:",
    boost::tie(m_myPets->NumCats(), m_myPets->NumDogs()));
```

`tie` creates a tuple of references. Or if the call involves temporaries:

```
LogDebugMessage("Number of cats, dogs and birds:",
    boost::make_tuple(m_myPets->NumCats(), m_myPets->NumDogs(), 0));
```

If the logged types are a bit heavier (`boost::make_tuple` makes copies), you can resort to good old `boost::ref`.

Your `LogDebugMessage` would then look something like this:

```
template<class Tuple>
void LogDebugMessage(std::string const& msg, Tuple const& args);
```

And after that you'd unpack the tuple using recursion similar to [my tuple printer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6245777/500104). Note that only `operator<<` actually uses variadic templates, and only does so to just pick up `std::tuple`. You would most likely only use the `print_tuple` part.

Comment: Type boost::tie() for every log message? I'd rather go with 9 overloads. :(