# Translating (1-tuple to 10-tuple) argument to n-tuple argument in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples, variadic-templates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pretty-print std::tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245735/pretty-print-stdtuple)

In a database library (soci), there is a chunk of code below that works on `std::tuple<>`'s from one to ten parameters.

*static class methods `from_base()` and `to_base()` are implemented for arguments of 1-tuple to 10-tuple.*

The guts essentially stream every n-tuple element to and from the passed-in stream.  Everything is hard-coded.

**How can this code be translated to use C++11's variadic templates instead (no limit on parameters)?**
*Actually using variadic templates or not is secondary.  What we really want to do is replace the hard-coding with the general case of n-tuple argument.*

Part of the problem is, there is, technically, only one argument, but that argument is an n-tuple, so I can't quite use what is described [here in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_template).  What is the best approach?

```
#include "values.h"
#include "type-conversion-traits.h"
#include <tuple>

namespace soci
{

template <typename T0>
struct type_conversion<std::tuple<T0> >
{
    typedef values base_type;

    static void from_base(base_type const & in, indicator ind,
        std::tuple<T0> & out)
    {
        in
            >> std::get<0>(out);
    }

    static void to_base(std::tuple<T0> & in,
        base_type & out, indicator & ind)
    {
        out
            << std::get<0>(in);
    }
};

template <typename T0, typename T1>
struct type_conversion<std::tuple<T0, T1> >
{
    typedef values base_type;

    static void from_base(base_type const & in, indicator ind,
        std::tuple<T0, T1> & out)
    {
        in
            >> std::get<0>(out)
            >> std::get<1>(out);
    }

    static void to_base(std::tuple<T0, T1> & in,
        base_type & out, indicator & ind)
    {
        out
            << std::get<0>(in)
            << std::get<1>(in);
    }
};

// ... all the way up to 10 template parameters

}
```

**RUNNABLE ANSWER (based on Grizzly's post below)**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

using namespace std;

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

template<unsigned N, unsigned End>
struct to_base_impl 
{
    template<typename Tuple>
    static void execute(Tuple& in, ostream& out) 
    {
      out << std::get<N>(in) << endl;
      to_base_impl<N+1, End>::execute(in, out);
    }
};

template<unsigned End>
struct to_base_impl<End, End>
{ 
    template<typename Tuple>
    static void execute(Tuple& in, ostream& out) 
    {
      out << "<GAME OVER>" << endl;
    }
};

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

template <typename Tuple>
struct type_conversion
{
    static void to_base(Tuple& in, ostream& out )
    {
        to_base_impl<0, std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value>::execute(in, out);
    }
};

template <typename... Args>
struct type_conversion<std::tuple<Args...>>
{
    static void to_base(std::tuple<Args...>& in, ostream& out )
    {
        to_base_impl<0, sizeof...(Args)>::execute(in, out);
    }
};

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

main()
{
    typedef tuple<double,int,string> my_tuple_type;
    my_tuple_type t { 2.5, 5, "foo" };

    type_conversion<my_tuple_type>::to_base( t, cerr );
}
```

Comment: See also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7858971/726300) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/687490/500104).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you basically need to call the operator `<<` or `>>` on in respectively out for every element of your tuple. In this case you can construct something similar to a for loop using partial specialization and recursion (sort of, since it actually calls a different function each time):

```
template<unsigned N, unsigned End>
struct to_base_impl {
    template<typename Tuple>
    void execute(Tuple& in, base_type& out) {
      out<<std::get<N>(in);
      to_base_impl<N+1, End>::execute(in, out);
    }
};

template<unsigned End>
struct to_base_impl<End, End> { //End of loop
    template<typename Tuple>
    void execute(Tuple& in, base_type& out) {}
};

template <typename Tuple>
struct type_conversion
{
    typedef values base_type;

    static void to_base(Tuple& in, base_type & out, indicator & ind){
        to_base_impl<0, std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value>::execute(in, out);
    }
};
```

This will iterate from zero to the size of the tuple and call `out<<std::get<N>(in);` each iteration. `from_base` would be implemented the same way only with `in>>std::get<N>(out);`. If you want to make sure your converter is only called with tuples you can use a variadic template:

```
template <typename... Args>
struct type_conversion<std::tuple<Args...>>
{
    typedef values base_type;

    static void to_base(std::tuple<Args...>& in, base_type & out, indicator & ind){
        to_base_impl<0, sizeof...(Args)>::execute(in, out);
    }
};
```

Of course you could write this more generically, but that will make the source much more complex and probably not give you much in return.

Comment: [It works](http://liveworkspace.org/code/4342f4edd8e09840bd1ae569894a78e3), +1.

Comment: Fantastic - the two-step process is brilliant!

Comment: @jrok +1 for nice, tight example

Answer (score 3):

I like the [indices trick](http://loungecpp.wikidot.com/tips-and-tricks%3aindices):

```
template<unsigned...> struct seq{};
template<unsigned N, unsigned... Is>
struct gen_seq : gen_seq<N-1, N-1, Is...>{};
template<unsigned... Is>
struct gen_seq<0, Is...> : seq<Is...>{};

template<class T> using Alias = T;

template<class... Ts, unsigned... Is>
void to_base(std::tuple<Ts...> const& t, base_type& out, seq<Is...>){
  Alias<char[]>{ (void(out << std::get<Is>(t)), '0')... };
}

template<class... Ts, unsigned... Is>
void to_base(std::tuple<Ts...> const& t, base_type& out){
  to_base(t, out, gen_seq<sizeof...(Ts)>{});
}
```

And the same for `from_base`. ([Live example based on jrok's.](http://liveworkspace.org/code/f8acfc4d1c324d724110b5ff7e00317c))

The code "exploits" the variadic unpacking mechanism to call `out << get<Is>(t)` exactly `sizeof...(Is)` (which is the same as `sizeof...(Ts)`) times. `gen_seq<N>` generates a compile-time integer list from `0` to `N-1` (`seq<0, 1, 2, ..., N-1>`). This list is saved to `unsigned... Is`, which are then unpacked in `get<Is>(t)` to `get<0>(t)`, `get<1>(t)`, all the way up to `get<N-1>(t)`.
`Alias<char[]>{ ... }` (a temporary array) provides a context where pack expansion can be used. I specifically chose array initialization here, because left-to-right evaluation of the passed arguments is guaranteed. The `(void(expression), '0')` will evaluate `expression`, discard the value, and pass `'0'` as the initializer (`void(...)` is used to force the built-in comma-operator to be selected, and not any possible overloaded one).

Comment: +1 for a different take (and a nice link with detailed explanations)