# How to iterate over a std::tuple in C++ 11

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples

I have made the following tuple:

I want to know how should I iterate over it? There is `tupl_size()`, but reading the documentation, I didn't get how to utilize it. Also I have search SO, but questions seem to be around `Boost::tuple` .

```
auto some = make_tuple("I am good", 255, 2.1);
```

Comment: Depends what you plan on doing after you "iterate" over it.

Comment: What would iterate on data of different types mean for you?

Comment: I want to `cout` each element - the most basic iteration. Accessing each element for `cout`-ing...

Comment: Something like [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245735/pretty-print-stdtuple) then?

Comment: @Tony D It seems  then tuple utilization and implementation quite differs from traditional list data types such as array and/or vector..thanks...

Comment: @MostafaTalebi: true... `tuple`s can hold heterogeneous types, which can only be indexed at compile time as the compiler needs to vary the element-handling code appropriately for the type.  Very different.  `vector`, `array` etc. are homogenous containers, so runtime iteration and processing doesn't need any polymorphic dispatch.

Comment: Is the order of iteration important to you?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here is an attempt to break down iterating over a tuple into component parts.

First, a function that represents doing a sequence of operations in order.  Note that many compilers find this hard to understand, despite it being legal C++11 as far as I can tell:

```
template<class... Fs>
void do_in_order( Fs&&... fs ) {
  int unused[] = { 0, ( (void)std::forward<Fs>(fs)(), 0 )... }
  (void)unused; // blocks warnings
}
```

Next, a function that takes a `std::tuple`, and extracts the indexes required to access each element.  By doing so, we can perfect forward later on.

As a side benefit, my code supports `std::pair` and `std::array` iteration:

```
template<class T>
constexpr std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<T>::value>
get_indexes( T const& )
{ return {}; }
```

The meat and potatoes:

```
template<size_t... Is, class Tuple, class F>
void for_each( std::index_sequence<Is...>, Tuple&& tup, F&& f ) {
  using std::get;
  do_in_order( [&]{ f( get<Is>(std::forward<Tuple>(tup)) ); }... );
}
```

and the public-facing interface:

```
template<class Tuple, class F>
void for_each( Tuple&& tup, F&& f ) {
  auto indexes = get_indexes(tup);
  for_each(indexes, std::forward<Tuple>(tup), std::forward<F>(f) );
}
```

while it states `Tuple` it works on `std::array`s and `std::pair`s.  It also forward the r/l value category of said object down to the function object it invokes.  Also note that if you have a free function `get<N>` on your custom type, and you override `get_indexes`, the above `for_each` will work on your custom type.

As noted, `do_in_order` while neat isn't supported by many compilers, as they don't like the lambda with unexpanded parameter packs being expanded into parameter packs.

We can inline `do_in_order` in that case

```
template<size_t... Is, class Tuple, class F>
void for_each( std::index_sequence<Is...>, Tuple&& tup, F&& f ) {
  using std::get;
  int unused[] = { 0, ( (void)f(get<Is>(std::forward<Tuple>(tup)), 0 )... }
  (void)unused; // blocks warnings
}
```

this doesn't cost much verbosity, but I personally find it less clear.  The shadow magic of how `do_in_order` works is obscured by doing it inline in my opinion.

`index_sequence` (and supporting templates) is a C++14 feature that can be written in C++11.  Finding such an implementation on stack overflow is easy.  A current top google hit is [a decent O(lg(n)) depth implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17426611/1774667), which if I read the comments correctly may be the basis for at least one iteration of the actual gcc `make_integer_sequence` (the comments also point out some further compile-time improvements surrounding eliminating `sizeof...` calls).

Alternatively we can write:

```
template<class F, class...Args>
void for_each_arg(F&&f,Args&&...args){
  using discard=int[];
  (void)discard{0,((void)(
    f(std::forward<Args>(args))
  ),0)...};
}
```

And then:

```
template<size_t... Is, class Tuple, class F>
void for_each( std::index_sequence<Is...>, Tuple&& tup, F&& f ) {
  using std::get;
  for_each_arg(
    std::forward<F>(f),
    get<Is>(std::forward<Tuple>(tup))...
  );
}
```

Which avoids the manual expand yet compiles on more compilers.  We pass the `Is` via the `auto&&i` parameter.

In C++1z we can also use `std::apply` with a `for_each_arg` function object to do away with the index fiddling.

Comment: ADL for `get` is a nice touch. `tuple_size` works on arrays and pairs too so I don't see the need for separate `get_indexes` overloads - also, `-> decltype( std::make_index_sequence< sizeof...(Ts) >() )` - why use `decltype`?

Comment: @T.C. Well, I stared with `auto` then made it SFINAE by moving the `return` expression to the `->` and `return {}`.  Didn't think to get rid of the `decltype`.  Changed it to a direct `make_index_sequence` off `tuple_size` and killed overloads.  And fixed a typo (missed a `...`).

Comment: @T.C., Yakk: can one you explain why "ADL for `get`" is a "nice touch"? What is the advantage over directly using `std::get` in the function call?

Comment: @davidhigh So suppose you define your own `tuple`-like structure (I dunno, a fixed size matrix class?).  If I do ADL-enabled `std::get` and you define your own free `get` in the namespace with your class, my ADL-enabled call to `get` may access it.  You'd also have to specialize `std::tuple_size`, but such specializations are legal.  Really, it is just a matter of trying to write overly generic code as a matter of habit.

Comment: It appears to use the C++14 feature make_index_sequence. Which can be implemented in C++11 according to http://pdimov.com/cpp2/simple_cxx11_metaprogramming.html but makes the approach less useful for C++11 as the OP poster asked for.

Comment: @T.C. As an aside, with structured bindings, my ADL get may actualy be useful!  Is only going to take 3 years!  ;)

Comment: it's a nice solution, but even if you manage to get it to compile in C++11, you can't use it in C++11 since you can't create lambdas or functions with auto parameters :(

Comment: @dput true, but auto parameter arguments was among the first C++14 features every compiler implemented.  So there is that.

Answer (score 29):

```
template<class F, class...Ts, std::size_t...Is>
void for_each_in_tuple(const std::tuple<Ts...> & tuple, F func, std::index_sequence<Is...>){
    using expander = int[];
    (void)expander { 0, ((void)func(std::get<Is>(tuple)), 0)... };
}

template<class F, class...Ts>
void for_each_in_tuple(const std::tuple<Ts...> & tuple, F func){
    for_each_in_tuple(tuple, func, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts)>());
}
```

Usage:

```
auto some = std::make_tuple("I am good", 255, 2.1);
for_each_in_tuple(some, [](const auto &x) { std::cout << x << std::endl; });
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0b99052cbada2ffb).

`std::index_sequence` and family are C++14 features, but they can be easily implemented in C++11 (there are many available on SO). Polymorphic lambdas are also C++14, but can be replaced with a custom-written functor.

Comment: +1 but you should mention that this is c++14 only .. (the title is c++11)

Comment: what concept is this: [class followed by "..." and then Tx], i dont know how should i pronounce it, the only thing i can understand is, it is giving variable argument for tuple's values as it is logically correct that tuple is gona have diff types, but even though i would love if some one could direct me to the right place from where i can learn this?

Comment: These are variadic templates: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn439779.aspx and http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack

Answer (score 12):

Here is a similar and more verbose solution than the formerly accepted one given by T.C., which is maybe a little bit easier to understand (-- it's probably the same as thousand others out there in the net):

```
template<typename TupleType, typename FunctionType>
void for_each(TupleType&&, FunctionType
            , std::integral_constant<size_t, std::tuple_size<typename std::remove_reference<TupleType>::type >::value>) {}

template<std::size_t I, typename TupleType, typename FunctionType
       , typename = typename std::enable_if<I!=std::tuple_size<typename std::remove_reference<TupleType>::type>::value>::type >
void for_each(TupleType&& t, FunctionType f, std::integral_constant<size_t, I>)
{
    f(std::get<I>(std::forward<TupleType>(t)));
    for_each(std::forward<TupleType>(t), f, std::integral_constant<size_t, I + 1>());
}

template<typename TupleType, typename FunctionType>
void for_each(TupleType&& t, FunctionType f)
{
    for_each(std::forward<TupleType>(t), f, std::integral_constant<size_t, 0>());
}
```

Usage (with `std::tuple`):

```
auto some = std::make_tuple("I am good", 255, 2.1);
for_each(some, [](const auto &x) { std::cout << x << std::endl; });
```

Usage (with `std::array`):

```
std::array<std::string,2> some2 = {"Also good", "Hello world"};
for_each(some2, [](const auto &x) { std::cout << x << std::endl; });
```

[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1bc0bdd62aa0239f)

---

**General idea:** as in the solution of T.C., start with an index `I=0` and go up to the size of the tuple. However, here it is done not per variadic expansion but one-at-a-time.

**Explanation:**

- The first overload of `for_each` is called if `I` is equal to the size of the tuple. The function then simply does nothing and such  end the recursion.
- The second overload calls the function with the argument `std::get<I>(t)` and increases the index by one. The class `std::integral_constant` is needed in order to resolve the value of `I` at compile time. The `std::enable_if` SFINAE stuff is used to help the compiler separate this overload from the previous one, and call this overload only if the `I` is smaller than the tuple size (on Coliru this is needed, whereas in Visual Studio it works without).
- The third starts the recursion with `I=0`. It is the overload which is usually called from outside.

---

---

**EDIT:** I've also included the idea mentioned by Yakk to additionally support `std::array` and `std::pair` by using a general template parameter `TupleType` instead of one that is specialized for `std::tuple<Ts ...>`.

As `TupleType` type needs to be deduced and is such a "universal reference", this further has the advantage that one gets perfect forwarding for free. The downside is that one has to use another indirection via `typename std::remove_reference<TupleType>::type`, as `TupleType` might also be a deduced as a reference type.

Comment: This is not a C++11 solution, it's a C++1y solution.

Comment: @EdwardZ.Yang: The basic code is C++11, only the example with the generic lambda requires C++14. But thanks for the note.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @davidhigh, I was looking for a solution for an entire day and finally I get with your lines of code. You save my day. Really thanks