# how to access variadic lambda function arguements

Tags: c++, lambda, variadic-templates, c++17

There are many articles here about variadic generic lambda functions, however I would like a simple explanation on how to access an argument inside the lambda function

pt. I am using an old setup to fetch the arguments, however I want a more generic solution

example - old use :

```
auto lambda = [](...)                              
{                                                  
    va_list args;                                  
    va_start(args,0);                              
    auto b = va_arg(args, const char*);            
    cout << "hello " << b << endl;           
    va_end(args);                                  
};                                                 

lambda();                                      
lambda("world");
```

shows this:

```
hello
hello world
```

I would like to know if it is possible to use variadic template on lambda functions to refactor this into are more generic solution

also how to access individual arguments inside the lambda, not just all in one go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I ended up with:

```
auto lambda = [](const auto&...args)                                  
{                                                                      
    typedef boost::variant<int, float, std::string> Variant;           
    std::vector<Variant> vec = {args...};                              
    std::cout << "hello ";                                             
    for(auto a: vec) {                                                 
        std::cout << a;                                                
    }                                                                  
    std::cout << std::endl;                                            
};                                                                     

lambda("world", " and ", "universe");
```

shows following:

```
hello world and universe
```

it seems using a Variant type for vector, does the magic

Answer (score 1):

You may do something like:

```
auto lambda = [](const auto&...args)
{
    std::cout << "hello ";
    const int dummy[] = {0, ((std::cout << args), 0)...};
    static_cast<void>(dummy);
    std::cout << std::endl;
};
```

or with folding expression in C++17:

```
auto lambda = [](const auto&...args)
{
    (std::cout << "hello " << ... << args) << std::endl;
};
```

Comment: I have seen this part `const int dummy[] = {0, ((std::cout << args), 0)...};`
however I really do not understand what is happening there - could you elaborate on this?

Comment: @serup: You may look at [how-to-iterate-over-a-stdtuple-in-c-11](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26902633/how-to-iterate-over-a-stdtuple-in-c-11)

Comment: waou - you really saved my day - top rank to you

Comment: I could not get the C++17 version to work - how would you write your makefile for this ? must be something wrong with mine

Comment: it seems that in combination with this solution and following 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/7232968/3990012
a more complete solution can be made

Comment: @serup, Compile with `-std=c++1z` or `-std=c++17` if the compiler supports it and make sure you're using a compiler that implements fold expressions. There's also no need for that `any` (which is actually a variant). It won't get you anything extra for simply iterating over arguments. In fact, it limits the function's usefulness because it no longer works for any type of argument that you can print, only the few types you specify.

Comment: @chris, I tried adding both -std=c++1y and -std=c++17 and it still gave compiler error, also I think maybe I need to read a little more about folding before I start using it