# Anatomy of pretty print tuple

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples, variadic-templates, pretty-print

A while ago, a solution to print out std::tuple was posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6245777). For the most part I get what's happening. I'm having trouble understanding whats happening in the print_tuple function though.

```
template<class Ch, class Tr, class Tuple, std::size_t... Is>
void print_tuple(std::basic_ostream<Ch,Tr>& os, Tuple const& t, seq<Is...>){
  using swallow = int[];
  (void)swallow{0, (void(os << (Is == 0? "" : ", ") << std::get<Is>(t)), 0)...};
}
```

I don't get what's happening in the body of this function. As far as I can tell, it has something to do with unpacking `Is`. I get that the condition, `Is == 0` is checking to see if we're at the head element.

So what's going on?

Comment: The code constructs (and then throws away) an `int[]` array from an initializer list, where each element is 0 but prints one element of the tuple as a side effect (via comma operator). The use of initializer list is just to get into a context where pack expansion would work.

Comment: Ah! So the `swallow{...}` construct is an initialization list for int[]. I did not catch that at first glance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's go through an example with an arbitrary tuple, say:

```
using Tuple = tuple<char, int, string>;
```

Thus, the integer sequence that our function will be called with is:

```
seq<0, 1, 2>
```

And our pack expansion in the body is:

```
(void)swallow{0, (void(os << (Is == 0? "" : ", ") << std::get<Is>(t)), 0)...};
```

which, if we manually expand it the way the compiler would, becomes:

```
(void)swallow{0,
              (void(os << (0 == 0? "" : ", ") << std::get<0>(t)), 0),
              (void(os << (1 == 0? "" : ", ") << std::get<1>(t)), 0),
              (void(os << (2 == 0? "" : ", ") << std::get<2>(t)), 0)
              };
```

And then evaluating the branches:

```
(void)swallow{0,
              (void(os << "" << std::get<0>(t)), 0),
              (void(os << ", " << std::get<1>(t)), 0),
              (void(os << ", " << std::get<2>(t)), 0)
              };
```

Which is to say, we're constructing an integer array of 4 `0`s, with the side effect of printing out the contents of the tuple, comma-separated, making sure we don't start with an extra comma. The four expressions *must* be evaluated in order, so that guarantees that the tuple contents get printed in order.

The initial `(void)` cast is just there to avoid the unused-variable warning that compilers should emit if you have all warnings turned on. The initial `0` in the array initialization handles the case where the tuple is empty.

Comment: I'm starting to get it. What does the `void(...)` do?

Comment: @SalvadorGuzman Casts the result of `os << whatever` to `void`, so that the expression `(void(stuff), 0)` definitely returns `0`. This is done on the off chance that somebody decided to write an overload for `operator,()` that does something other than return the `int`.

Comment: This is making much more sense. One last question. So is the  '...' operator an unpacker? Can I count on it to return comma separated values?

Comment: @SalvadorGuzman It's not an operator, but it does expand the parameter pack. Read through [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack), it's a good intro.

Answer (score 0):

`(os << (Is == 0? "" : ", ") << std::get<Is>(t))` print the `Is`th element (with prefix `", "` for `Is > 0`)

Then, casting the result to `void` to avoid possible overload of comma operator.

`(/*previous stuff*/, 0)...` does a series of 0

`{0, /*previous stuff*/ }` manages the cases where `sizeof...(Is) == 0`

`swallow /*previous stuff*/` build an int array of `0`.

`void /*previous stuff*/` : cast to void to avoid warning.