# template looping through tuple

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, stdtuple

I'm playing with variadic templates and I'm currently trying to implement `operator<<` for tuple.

I've tried the following code but it doesn't compile (GCC 4.9 with -std=c++11).

```
template<int I, typename ... Tlist>
void print(ostream& s, tuple<Tlist...>& t)
{
    s << get<I>(t) << ", ";
    if(I < sizeof...(Tlist)){
        print<I+1>(s,t);
    }
}
template<typename ... Tlist>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& s, tuple<Tlist...> t)
{
    print<0>(s,t);
    return s;
}
```

The error message is very cryptic and long, but it basically says that there is no matching function call for get. Can someone explain to me why?
Thanks.

EDIT:
Here is the template instantiation I'm using

```
auto t = make_tuple(5,6,true,"aaa");
cout << t << endl;
```

Comment: MCVE as usual please! How are you actually instantiating the template function?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pretty-print std::tuple](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245735/pretty-print-stdtuple)

Comment: Most of the code unpacking tuples by position I've seen, goes from `sizeof...(Tlist)` downwards to `0`, not the other way round.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code in an `if (blah) {` block `}` is compiled and must be valid even if the condition `blah` is false.

```
template<bool b>
using bool_t = std::integral_constant<bool, b>;

template<int I, typename ... Tlist>
void print(std::ostream& s, std::tuple<Tlist...> const& t, std::false_type) {
  // no more printing
}

template<int I, typename ... Tlist>
void print(std::ostream& s, std::tuple<Tlist...> const& t, std::true_type) {
  s << std::get<I>(t) << ", ";
  print<I+1>(s, t, bool_t<((I+1) < sizeof...(Tlist))>{});
}
template<typename ... Tlist>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, std::tuple<Tlist...> const& t)
{
  print<0>(s,t, bool_t<(0 < sizeof...(Tlist))>{});
  return s;
}
```

should work.  Here we use tag dispatching to control which overload we recursively call: the 3rd argument is `true_type` if `I` is a valid index for the tuple, and `false_type` if not.  We do this instead of an `if` statement.  We always recurse, but when we reach the end of the tuple, we recurse into the terminating overload.

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a6dac8e9ad2cb242)

As an aside, it is ambiguous if overloading `<<` for two types defined in `std` is compliant with the standard: it depends if `std::tuple<int>` is a "user defined type" or not, a clause that the standard does not define.

On top of that, it is considered best practice to overload operators for a type within the namespace of that type, so it can be found via ADL.  But, overloading `<<` inside `std` is illegal under the standard (you cannot inject new overloads into `std`).  The result can be somewhat surprising behavior in some cases, where the wrong overload is found, or an overload is not found.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use specialization or SFINAE as the branch even if it is not taken generates the instantiation:

```
template<int I, typename ... Tlist>
void print(ostream& s, tuple<Tlist...>& t)
{
    s << get<I>(t) << ", ";
    if(I < sizeof...(Tlist)){
        print<I+1>(s,t); // Generated even if I >= sizeof...(Tlist)
    }
}
```

And so you would have infinite instantiation of `print` if `get<sizeof...(Tlist)>` doesn't produce an error sooner.

You may wrote it without recursion with:

```
template<std::size_t ... Is, typename Tuple>
void print_helper(std::ostream& s, const Tuple& t, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    int dummy[] = { 0, ((s << std::get<Is>(t) << ", "), 0)...};
    (void) dummy; // remove warning for unused var
}


template<typename Tuple>
void print(std::ostream& s, const Tuple& t)
{
    print_helper(s, t, std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value>());
}
```

[Live example](https://ideone.com/KPFVrb)