# Is it possible to auto add some code, when I add class member variables

Tags: c++11, boost

I'm boost newbie.

I would like to know is it possible

When I add some class member variable(at header file)
then automatically generate some code

```
// classA.h file
class classA
{
    public:
        int a; // in fact a,b,c is some structure.
        int b;
        // I will add "int c;"

        void save(); // I want to auto generate some code at save()
        void load();
}
```

When I add "int c;"

```
// classA.cpp
void classA::save()
{
    someStream << a << b; // I use boost::serialize

    // I want auto replace above code by next
    // someStream << a << b << c;
}

void classA::load()
{
    someStream >> a >> b;

    // replace above 
    // someStream >> a >> b >> c;
    // Exactly same order
}
enter code here
```

It is possible? using boost mpl? macro?

I have variable to add a lot.

Comment: no. maybe... with some crazy macro. It is worth it? No. Just write by hand. If you have a lot of members, consider refactoring (e.g. hold a vector)

Comment: there are some proposal to add compile-time reflection to c++, but I wouldn't count on it for the near (?) future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest you can get is `std::tuple<int,int> data` which you can then grow to `std::tuple<int,int,int>`, See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245735/pretty-print-stdtuple) how to print them.

Comment: Actually, Boost Fusion has stuff much closer http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/adapted/define_struct.html