# pretty-print C++ containers with indent by level

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, pretty-print

This is a follow-up to [Kerrek SB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/596781/kerrek-sb) etc's previous question on pretty-printing STL containers [Pretty-print C++ STL containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850473/pretty-print-c-stl-containers) , for which Kerrek etc managed to develop a very elegant and fully general solution, and its sequel, [Pretty-print std::tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245735/pretty-print-stdtuple) , where `std::tuple<Args...>` is handled.

I wonder, if it's possible, to inlucde in the solution about indent?

For example, if I have a vector of vector of vector of string, I'd like to see something like:

```
{ // vector of vector of vector of string
   { // vector of vector of string
      { hello, world };// vector of string
      { The, quick, brown, fox, jumps, over, the, lazy, dog };
      ...
      { Now, is, the, time, for, all, good, men, to, come, to, the, aid, of, the, party}
   };
   { // vector of vector of string
      { hello, world };// vector of string
      { The, quick, brown, fox, jumps, over, the, lazy, dog };
      ...
      { Now, is, the, time, for, all, good, men, to, come, to, the, aid, of, the, party}
   };
   ...
   { // vector of vector of string
      { hello, world };// vector of string
      { The, quick, brown, fox, jumps, over, the, lazy, dog };
      ...
      { Now, is, the, time, for, all, good, men, to, come, to, the, aid, of, the, party}
   };
}
```

How would that be done nicely?

Answer (score 2):

<sub>*Note: This is not a **'real'** answer to the question as I interpret it because I suspect that OP wants a general solution which uses proper indentation for arbitrarily nested containers.*</sub>

As a workaround you could of course use the given solutions and properly adjust prefix, delimiter and postfix.

[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850473/pretty-print-c-stl-containers/32808235#32808235):

```
using namespace std::string_literals;

using vs = std::vector<std::string>;
using vvs = std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>;
using vvvs = std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>>;
std::cout << pretty::decoration<vs>("       { ", ", ", " }");
std::cout << pretty::decoration<vvs>("  {\n", ",\n", "\n    }");
std::cout << pretty::decoration<vvvs>("{\n", ",\n", "\n}\n");

std::vector<std::string> vs1 = { "hello"s, "world"s };
std::vector<std::string> vs2 = { "The"s, "quick"s, "brown"s, "fox"s };
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> vvs1 = { vs1, vs1, vs2 };
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> vvs2 = { vs2, vs1, vs2 };
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>> vvvs1 = { vvs1, vvs2 };

std::cout << vvvs1;
```

Prints:

```
{
    {
        { hello, world },
        { hello, world },
        { The, quick, brown, fox }
    },
    {
        { The, quick, brown, fox },
        { hello, world },
        { The, quick, brown, fox }
    }
}
```