# How to print std::tuple iteratively

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

Most samples of c++ books leverage recursively mechanism to print std::tuple.
Is it possible to print std::tuples iteratively by leverage sizeof...(Typename)?

For example, the function signature is like below:

`template<typename... Ts>
 constexpr void PrintTuple(std::tuple<Ts...>& tuple)`

Then I could use sizeof...(Ts) to know how many elements in the tuple and then
I could use std::get< i >(tuple) to retrieve the individual element?

Comment: Which standard version are you using?

Comment: You will find the answer to your question [as the `print_tuple_impl` example on cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence).

Comment: g++ 6.3, C++14 standard.

Comment: Related [Pretty-print std::tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6245735/27678)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one of the possible solutions:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template <typename T, std::size_t ...I, typename F>
void tuple_foreach_impl(T &&tuple, std::index_sequence<I...>, F &&func)
{
    // In C++17 we would use a fold expression here, but in C++14 we have to resort to this.
    using dummy_array = int[];
    dummy_array{(void(func(std::get<I>(tuple))), 0)..., 0};
}

template <typename T, typename F> void tuple_foreach(T &&tuple, F &&func)
{
    constexpr int size = std::tuple_size<std::remove_reference_t<T>>::value;
    tuple_foreach_impl(std::forward<T>(tuple), std::make_index_sequence<size>{},
                       std::forward<F>(func));
}

int main()
{
    auto x = std::make_tuple("Meow", 1, 2.3);

    tuple_foreach(x, [](auto &&value)
    {
        std::cout << value << ' ';
    });
    // Prints:
    // Meow
    // 1
    // 2.3
}
```

---

With `tuple_foreach` making a proper printer should be simple.

```
template <typename T> void print_tuple(const T &tuple)
{
    std::cout << '{';
    tuple_foreach(tuple, [first = true](auto &value) mutable
    {
        if (!first)
            std::cout << "; ";
        else
            first = 0;
        std::cout << value;
    });
    std::cout << '}';
}

// ...

print_tuple(std::make_tuple("Meow", 1, 2.3)); // Prints `{Meow; 1; 2.3}`
```

Comment: How is this different from any of the solutions on [Pretty-print std::tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6245735/27678)?

Comment: @AndyG The comment wasn't there when I started writing answer, and I didn't bother checking again before clicking 'Post Answer'. If you decide to dupe-hammer the question, I don't mind removing the answer (if I even can delete an accepted answer).

Comment: Why do you pass function by reference (*F &&func*) and not by value as in std-library?

Comment: @Fedor Functors can have internal state (e.g. lambdas have their captures), which I wouldn't want to copy. It doesn't really matter in this case though.

Answer (score 0):

c++20 makes everything very easy:

```
void print_tuple(auto&& t) noexcept
{
  [&]<auto ...I>(std::index_sequence<I...>) noexcept
  {
    (
      [&]() noexcept
      {
        if constexpr(I)
        {
          std::cout << ", ";
        }

        std::cout << std::get<I>(t);
      }(),
      ...
    );

    std::cout << '\n';
  }
  (
    std::make_index_sequence<
      std::tuple_size_v<std::remove_cvref_t<decltype(t)>>
    >()
  );
}
```

Comment: This goes simpler already in C++17 as `std::apply([](auto const& ... x) {(std::cout<<...<<x);},tuple)`

Comment: Yeah, tell this to the folks over [here](https://www.cppstories.com/2022/tuple-iteration-apply/), lol. Anyway, I kind of like the `if constexpr` and the lambda within the fold expression, seems more flexible to me.

Comment: It is more flexible, and C++20 indeed makes many things very easy.