# can a type tuple be unpacked later?

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I have a tuple of types encoded as

```
template<class... T>struct packed;
```

I want to unpack it later like

```
template<class T>struct unpack;
template<class... T>
struct unpack<packed<T...>>{
      //how to define the unpacked type here?
};
```

So that, I can use it as

```
template<class Packed>
struct foo : unpack<Packed>::type...{};
```

Note, I do not want to unpack the elements of the tuple immediately like

```
template<class... T>
struct unpack<packed<T...>> : T...{};
template<class Packed>
struct foo: unpack<Packed>{};
```

I am interested to have elements of the tuple 'packed' to be direct base classes of 'foo' instead of indirect base classes via 'unack'. Also the elements of the type tuple are distinct non-primitive and non-final types.

To make the example more detailed,

```
template<class T, T... Values> 
struct variadic_values{};
template<class T,T From,class Encode,T To>
struct value_gen;
template<class T, T From, T... Values, T To>
struct value_gen<T,From,variadic_values<T,Values...>,To>
{
   using type = typename value_gen<T,From+1,variadic_values<T,Values...,From>,To>::type;
};
template<class T,T From,T... Values>
struct value_gen<T,From,variadic_values<T,Values...>,From>
{
    using type = variadic_values<T,Values...>;
};
template<class T, T From,T To>
using values = typename value_gen<T,From,variadic_values<T>,To>::type;
template<unsigned Idx,class T>
struct node{};
template<class Idx,class... Ts>
struct unpack;
template<unsigned... Idx,class...Ts>
struct unpack<variadic_values<unsigned,Idx...>,Ts...> : node<Idx,Ts>...{};
template<class... Ts>
class foo : unpack<values<unsigned,0,sizeof...(ts)>,Ts...>{};
```

What I am interested to have is that `foo` should be directly derived from `node`s

Comment: It's not quite the same question, but I think some of the solutions to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7858817/unpacking-a-tuple-to-call-a-matching-function-pointer would also work for this.

Comment: I had gone though the solution before, but failed to convert it to a solution whet types are unpacked one by one rather than at a time. See comment on @HighCommander4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second try ...

Would it be acceptable to specialize `foo` to accept a special tag type, which passes in the type and corresponding index?

```
template<typename T, unsigned N>
struct tagged_node
{ };

template<typename...>
struct foo;

// specialize for case where pack is list of special tag types.
template<typename... T, unsigned... N>
struct foo<tagged_node<T, N>...> : node<T,N>...
{ };

template<typename T, unsigned N>
struct wrapped_node
{ typedef node<T, N> type; };

template<typename T, typename U>
struct make_node_foo_impl;

template<typename... T, unsigned... I>
struct make_node_foo_impl<packed<T...>, index_tuple<I...>>
{
  typedef foo<tagged_node<T, I>...> type;
};   

template<typename... T>
struct make_node_foo
: make_node_foo_impl<packed<T...>, to_index_tuple<T...>>
{ };  // inherits 'type'
```

(Untested, sorry, I have to go out!)

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
template <class>
struct foo;

template <class... T>
struct foo<packed<T...>> : T...
{
};
```

Then you can use it as:

```
typedef packed<A, B, C> packed_type;
typedef foo<packed_type> foo_t;  // foo_t derives from A, B, and C
```

Comment: That is not an option as I want unpack to transform the types so that it becomes template<class Packed> struct foo : node<T0,0>, node<T1,1>...{};  where Ts are the arguments for packed, and node is a structure parametrized over the type and Iis position.

Comment: @abir: Can you separate the transformation from the definition of packed? As in `typedef packed<A, B, C> packed_type; typedef my_transform<packed_type>::type transformed_packed_type; typedef foo<transformed_packed_type> foo_t;` where `transformed_packed_type` would be `packed<node<A, 0>, node<B, 1>, node<C, 2>>`?

Comment: I can change all other class signatures except foo. I expanded the question to give one more complete and motivated example.

Answer (score 1):

N.B. this part of your question is not possible:

```
template<class Packed>
struct foo : unpack<Packed>::type...{};
```

`Packed` is not a parameter  pack here, so cannot be used in a pack expansion.
If you changed it to:

```
template<class Packed>
struct foo<packed<Packed...> : unpack<Packed>::type...{};
```

then you could expand the parameter pack, but now `unpack` would only be passed a single type, and would have no way to know which index it was, i.e. what `N` should be for `node<Pn, N>`

To make it work you need to combine the type parameter pack with a non-type parameter pack of integers, which your `values` gets close to, but you have the indirection of deriving from `unpack` not a list of `node` types.

I think this is what you're asking for (edited after misunderstanding the `node` part), using my [`index_tuple`](https://gitorious.org/redistd/redistd/blobs/master/include/redi/index_tuple.h) utility, which could easily be replaced by litb's [`seq`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7858971/981959) template or any similar type.  The non-type parameter pack of integers is deduced as a default template argument and can then be used in the base-class list of `foo`:

```
#include <redi/index_tuple.h>

template<typename T, unsigned N> struct node { };

template<typename... T> struct packed { };

template<typename T>
struct index_tuple_from_packed;

template<typename... T>
struct index_tuple_from_packed<packed<T...>>
{
  typedef redi::to_index_tuple<T...> type;
};

template<typename T, typename I = typename index_tuple_from_packed<T>::type>
struct foo;

template<typename... T, unsigned... Indices>
struct foo<packed<T...>, redi::index_tuple<Indices...>>
: node<T, Indices>...
{ };

struct A { };
struct B { };
struct C { };

int main()
{
  typedef packed<A, B, C> p;
  foo<p> d;
  node<A, 0>* a = &d;
  node<B, 1>* b = &d;
  node<C, 2>* c = &d;
}
```

Comment: I guess "index_tuple" or "seq" are nearly same as "values" and value_gen in my example. See later part of the example. You are using make_derived<...>::type as the implementation, while I am looking for make_derived to look like that (in my example it is foo).though I can use template alias for that but I want to have a class template instead of alias.

Comment: I got rid of `make_derived`, please reload

Comment: This is very close to the solution, however as foo is to take variadic types, it is not possible to add default type at end. I agree some confusion about foo is in the question. Look at the last part, where template<class...>foo; is defined.

Comment: Then I don't an easy solution, you need some way to get the integer list available in the base-clause of `foo`, so it has to be a template parameter. I _think_ you either have to change the template parameters of `foo` or accept an indirection instead of deriving directly from `node`. Hmm, just had another idea that won't fit in a comment ...