# Variadic templates: iterate over type/template argument

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, g++, libffi

I've been working with [libffi](http://sourceware.org/libffi/) lately, and since it uses a C API, any abstraction is done by using void pointers (good ol' C). I'm creating a class (with variadic templates) which utilizes this API. The class declaration is the following: (where `Ret` = return value and `Args` = function arguments)

```
template <typename Ret, typename... Args>
class Function
```

Within this class I have two different functions declared as well (simplified):

```
Ret Call(Args... args); // Calls the wrapped function
void CallbackBind(Ret * ret, void * args[]); // The libffi callback function (it's actually static...)
```

I want to be able to use `Call` from `CallbackBind`; and that is my problem. I have no idea how I am supposed to convert the `void*` array to the templated argument list. This is what I want more or less:

```
CallbackBind(Ret * ret, void * args[])
{
 // I want to somehow expand the array of void pointers and convert each
 // one of them to the corresponding template type/argument. The length
 // of the 'void*' vector equals sizeof...(Args) (variadic template argument count)

 // Cast each of one of the pointers to their original type
 *ret = Call(*((typeof(Args[0])*) args[0]), *((typeof(Args[1])*) args[1]), ... /* and so on */);
}
```

If this is not achievable, are there any workarounds or different solutions available?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just call directly into the library's API from the callback? You already have a `void*`, and it already expects that.

Comment: Mmm why would you want to call a variadic template function with a fixed amount of arguments? Based on the fact that "the length of args equals sizeof...(Args)", then you know the number of arguments required, why use variadic templates?.

Comment: @MarkB Since `CallbackBind` is called _from_ the library's API I'm trying to call my own function which does not use void pointers.
@mfontanini I want a class which mimics `std::function`, and therefore I require variadic templates (such as `operator()(Args...)`)

Comment: I'm tempted to write something like `CallAux<Tuple, Indices...>::call(void * args[]) { Call(*static_cast<(*std::tuple_element<Tuple, Indices>*>(args[Indices]))...); }`.

Comment: You should have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7858817/unpacking-a-tuple-to-call-a-matching-function-pointer. You could adapt it to fit your needs :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't want to iterate over the types, you want to create a parameter pack and expand it in a variadic template. You have an array, so the pack you want is a pack of integers 0,1,2... to serve as array indices.

```
#include <redi/index_tuple.h>

template<typename Ret, typename... Args>
struct Function
{
  Ret (*wrapped_function)(Args...);

  template<unsigned... I>
  Ret dispatch(void* args[], redi::index_tuple<I...>)
  {
    return wrapped_function(*static_cast<Args*>(args[I])...);
  }

  void CallbackBind(Ret * ret, void * args[])
  {
    *ret = dispatch(args, to_index_tuple<Args...>());
  }
};
```

Something like that, using [index_tuple.h](http://gitorious.org/redistd/redistd/blobs/master/include/redi/index_tuple.h)

The trick is that CallbackBind creates an `index_tuple` of integers representing the arg positions, and dispatches to another function which deduces the integers and expands the pack into a list of cast expressions to use as arguments to the wrapped function.

Comment: What an elegant solution! Worked flawlessly for me.