# In C++, What should I do when I want to initialize class members via constructor when I initialize a class object array?

Tags: c++, initialization

I thought I could do the following:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class cl
{
  public:
    double* Arr;
    cl(int);
};

cl::cl(int i)
{
    Arr=new double[i];
    Arr[0]=11;
};

int main()
{
    cl* BB;
    BB=new cl(3)[3];      /* I want to initialize a class member Arr for each element of the class cl array BB when I initialize this array by means of constructor. What should I do? */
    cout << cl[1].Arr[0] << endl;                                                                                                   

    return 0;
}
```

but obviously something is wrong with the line where I noted. The compiler wouldn't compile.

Comment: Why not use a `std::vector`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++11 you can use brace initializer:

```
cl* BB = new cl[3] {1, 2, 3};
```

or more verbose, so it's clear that the numbers are passed as arguments to constructors of different objects:

```
cl* BB = new cl[3] {{1}, {2}, {3}};
```

Though as you are allocating memory dynamically anyway, it's better to use `std::vector`, also it's more convenient if you want to initialize large number of objects with the same parameters:

```
std::vector<cl> BB(300, 3);
```

However, `std::vector` initialization won't compile if `cl` doesn't have a copy constructor. In that case you can use `emplace_back()`:

```
vector<cl> BB;
BB.reserve(300);
for(int i = 0; i < 300; ++i)
    BB.emplace_back(3);
```

This in turn can be [wrapped into a template `back_emplacer_iterator` to use with `std::fill_n`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12129760/3959454)

Answer (score 3):

There are several approaches:

- C++11 [initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization)

  ```
  cl* BB = new cl[3] {42, 42, 42};
  ```
- STL-vector (recommended)

  ```
  std::vector<cl> BB( 3, cl( 42 ) );
  ```

As pre-C++11 there are also other more involved solutions relying on [placement new](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4756306/1938163) operator although I'd not recommend this.

Answer (score 1):

The format of a new-expression is a type, followed by an initializer. If you want to allocate an array of 3 `cl` objects then the type is `cl[3]`. You can't say `cl(3)[n]` because `cl(3)` is not a type.

In C++03 the only valid initializer for a dynamically-allocated array is `()` which value-initializes each element, but you can't do that as your type doesn't have a default constructor.

In C++11 you can use an initializer-list to pass arguments to each array element:

```
cl* ptr = new cl[3]{ 3, 3, 3};
```

Answer (score 0):

Each element in the array will be initialized by the default constructor (no argument constructor). After that you may call any function that does the desired task. Corrected program example:

```
class cl
{
  public:
    double* Arr;
    cl(int i = 0);
    ~cl();
    void allocArr(int i=0);
};

cl::cl(int i)
{
    allocArr(i);
}

void cl::allocArr(int i)
{
    if (i <= 0) {
        Arr = (double *) NULL;
    }
    else {
        Arr=new double[i];
        Arr[0]=11;
    }
};

cl::~cl() {
    if (Arr)
      delete [] Arr;
}

int main()
{
    cl* BB;
    BB=new cl[3]; // default constructor 
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        BB[i].allocArr(3);
    }

    cout << BB[1].Arr[0] << endl;                                                                                                   

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yuck. `allocArr` leaks memory if called twice. You do not need to check a pointer is non-null before deleting it.

Comment: Also, it is valid to allocate 0 items, you just can't index the pointer you get for it. And as for the problem of the number being negative, a preferable solution is to replace all of the `int`s that deal with numbers that must be positive with `unsigned int`s.

Comment: I just gave the idea of what can be done, robustness has to be checked by the original requester, if the idea helped that's fine, what's the point of downvoting in honest help

Comment: OK, but there is no way doing this by argument constructor?