# Does copy operator= exist for std::pair

Tags: c++

I'm facing with an issue. Returning std::pair<T1, T2>  from lambda function.
I'm trying to generate map with opened ifstream's, but compiler complains with this output:

> /usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_algo.h:4337:12: error: use of deleted function ‘std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string, std::basic_ifstream >& std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string, std::basic_ifstream >::operator=(const std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string, std::basic_ifstream >&)’

I went through cppref for std::pair and I didn't notice that copy operator= is not viable for this one.

I'm fairly certain that lambdas that return pair is possible, then I definitely have some misunderstanding in snippet below.

```
std::map<int, std::string> mFileMap;
std::map<std::string, std::ifstream> files;
std::transform(mFileMap.begin(), mFileMap.end(), files.begin(),
                [](const auto& arg) -> std::pair<std::string, std::ifstream> {
                    std::string path(arg.second);
                    std::ifstream stream(path);
                    return std::make_pair(path, stream);
                });
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12129760/using-emplace-with-algorithms-such-as-stdfill might be interested for you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`std::pair` is copyable only as long as whatever's in a `std::pair` is copyable. If you think about, for a few seconds, you will agree that this makes 100% sense.

```
std::pair<std::string, std::ifstream>
```

`std::ifstream` is not copyable. You cannot copy `std::ifstream`s. Putting it inside a `std::pair` doesn't make it copyable.

But that's not the least of the problems in the shown code:

```
std::map<std::string, std::ifstream> files;
std::transform(mFileMap.begin(), mFileMap.end(), files.begin(),
      // ...
```

The `files` map is empty. `files.begin()` will return the beginning iterator to an empty map, which will be the same value as `files.end()`. Attempting to copy into an ending iterator (ignoring the fact that the underlying type is not copyable) will not end well.

Additionally, `std::map`'s key is constant, in the map, so that won't work either.

This is not how stuff gets added to a map, one needs to use a [`std::insert_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/insert_iterator).

So, to summarize, the following problems must be solved:

1. This `std::pair` is not copyable.
2. A `std::insert_iterator` must be used to insert new key/value pairs into a `std::map`.

Presuming you insist on your `std::map` containing these values, you'll have to do some work to populate it, using [`std::map::emplace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace), this will be the most practical way to drop new things into this map.

Answer (score 2):

thanks to Sam I found the way to solve this problem.
So, one possible fix could be

```
std::map<std::string, std::ifstream> files;
std::transform(mFileMap.begin(), mFileMap.end(), std::inserter(files, files.end()),
                [](auto const& arg) -> std::pair<std::string, std::ifstream> {
                    std::string path(arg.second);
                     return std::make_pair(path, std::ifstream(path));
                  });
```

Comment: This really makes full use of mandatory copy elision in order to avoid an actual need to copy an uncopyable object. But, this does seem to work.