# How to avoid decay of std::reference_wrapper to plain references in std::make_tuple?

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples, reference-wrapper

I' am trying to correctly produce a tuple of `std::reference_wrapper`s to objects. By using the technique [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13070218/how-to-get-from-a-tuple-to-a-tuple-of-references-to-elements-in-the-tuple) I manage to map the `std::ref` function over all the original tuple, however, according to [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/make_tuple) (and it actually happens), `std::reference_wrapper`s *decay* to plain refs (&) in the process. Is there a way to avoid this? I have a whole set of function that accept tuples of `std::reference_wrapper`s and I'd rather not change them to use references.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is sufficient to do

```
tuple<reference_wrapper<T>...> = /* my tuple of references */;
```

Answer (score 0):

In case it is possible to change the wrapper type, using [boost::reference_wrapper](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/core/doc/html/boost/reference_wrapper.html) / [boost::ref](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/core/doc/html/boost/ref_idm45818739683584.html) could be a solution to the problem.