# Transforming std::tuple<T...> to T

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, stdtuple

So I'm given a `std::tuple<T...>`, and I want to create a function pointer accepting `T...`, currently this is what I've got;

```
template<typename... Arguments>
using FunctionPointer = void (*)(Arguments...);

using FunctionPtr = FunctionPointer<typename std::tuple_element<0, V>::type,
                                    typename std::tuple_element<1, V>::type,
                                    typename std::tuple_element<2, V>::type>;
```

However I can't seem to find a way to do this, without manually entering each and every index from `0, ..., tuple_size<V>::value`. The FunctionPtr is defined in a context, where `V=std::tuple<T...>` (also there is already a variadic template (hence I can't just pass `T...` directly))

I guess I need to generate some list of indexes, and do some black magic..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7858817/unpacking-a-tuple-to-call-a-matching-function-pointer

Comment: @Morwenn: Wouldn't that require me to add another variadic template?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

```
#include <tuple>

// This is what you already have...
template<typename... Arguments>
using FunctionPointer = void (*)(Arguments...);

// Some new machinery the end user does not need to no about
namespace detail
{
    template<typename>
    struct from_tuple { };

    template<typename... Ts>
    struct from_tuple<std::tuple<Ts...>>
    {
        using FunctionPtr = FunctionPointer<Ts...>;
    };
}

//=================================================================
// This is how your original alias template ends up being rewritten
//=================================================================
template<typename T>
using FunctionPtr = typename detail::from_tuple<T>::FunctionPtr;
```

And here is how you would use it:

```
// Some function to test if the alias template works correctly
void foo(int, double, bool) { }

int main()
{
    // Given a tuple type...
    using my_tuple = std::tuple<int, double, bool>;

    // Retrieve the associated function pointer type...
    using my_fxn_ptr = FunctionPtr<my_tuple>; // <== This should be what you want

    // And verify the function pointer type is correct!
    my_fxn_ptr ptr = &foo;
}
```

Comment: Amazing! - I've been hacking at it for quite a while now, and you just fixed it in a blink of an eye! - It seems I still need much practice with tuples and variadic templates ;)

Comment: @Skeen: That's normal, it takes a while to get the hang of it

Comment: @AndyProwl: do you know if it is allowed to keep the original definition of `FunctionPtr` and add a *specialization* for tuples ?

Comment: @MatthieuM.: You mean partially specializing the alias template? No, that is forbidden...

Comment: @MatthieuM.: The standard reference is 14.5/3: "*Because an alias-declaration cannot declare a template-id, it is not possible to partially or explicitly specialize
an alias template.*"

Answer (score 5):

A simple trait might do the trick:

```
#include <tuple>

template <typename> struct tuple_to_function;

template <typename ...Args>
struct tuple_to_function<std::tuple<Args...>>
{
    typedef void (*type)(Args...);
};
```

Usage:

```
typedef std::tuple<Foo, Bar, int> myTuple;

tuple_to_function<myTuple>::type fp; // is a void (*)(Foo, Bar, int)
```