# How to create a type list (for variadic templates) that contains n-times the same type?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

I would like my class

```
template <class T, unsigned int n>
class X;
```

to create a `std::tuple` that contains `n` times the type `T`. Is there a particularly neat way for this? Is there also a nice way to do this for arbitrary variadic template classes?

This is what I did first:

```
#include <tuple>

template <class, unsigned int, class>
struct simple_repeat_helper;

template <class T, unsigned int n, class... Args>
struct simple_repeat_helper<T, n, std::tuple<Args...>>
{
    typedef typename simple_repeat_helper<T, n-1, std::tuple<Args..., T>>::type type;
};

template <class T, class... Args>
struct simple_repeat_helper<T, 0, std::tuple<Args...>>
{
    typedef std::tuple<Args...> type;
};

template <class T, unsigned int n>
struct simple_repeat
{
    using type = typename simple_repeat_helper<T, n, std::tuple<>>::type;
};
```

But actually, I do not need this for `std::tuple`, but for another class that acts similarly. So I thought that I would create a version that is a little bit more generic:

```
template <class, unsigned int, template <class...> class, class>
struct repeat_helper;

template <class T, template <class...> class M, class... Args>
struct repeat_helper<T, 0, M, M<Args...>>
{
    typedef M<Args...> type;
};

template <class T, unsigned int n, template <class...> class M, class... Args>
struct repeat_helper<T, n, M, M<Args...>>
{
    typedef typename repeat_helper<T, n-1, M, M<Args..., T>>::type type;
};

template <class T, unsigned int n, template <class...> class M = std::tuple>
struct repeat
{
    using type = typename repeat_helper<T, n, M, M<>>::type;
};
```

I thought that I could use it like this:

```
repeat<double, 5, std::tuple>::type x = std::make_tuple( 1., 2., 3., 4., 5. );
```

But unfortunately it fails to [compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=065b81b4e3ef5220e0d3a3500045c5a5-50d9cfc8a1d350e7409e81e87c2653ba) due to:

```
ambiguous class template instantiation for ‘struct repeat_helper<double, 0u, std::tuple, std::tuple<double, double, double, double, double> >’
```

Any help on this error would be appreciated!

Comment: what would be the benefit over `std::array<double, 5>`?

Comment: @stefan: I've got a class `A` that can contain different types (similar to `std::tuple`) and a function `B` that creates special instances of `A` which happen to have the same type. I do not want to create yet another flavor of `A`, because in my case if I would create another type, users would probably think that it has different semantics. Apart from that, I would like to merge instances of `A` (which happens to be cheap in my case). I do not want to consider `array` like types for this.

Comment: As Andy Prowl already stated, clang++ compiles this w/o error. If you replace the last template parameter with a parameter pack (containing the template parameters of the tuple instead of the tuple itself), g++ also compiles it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would do it this way:

```
template<typename, typename>
struct append_to_type_seq { };

template<typename T, typename... Ts, template<typename...> class TT>
struct append_to_type_seq<T, TT<Ts...>>
{
    using type = TT<Ts..., T>;
};

template<typename T, unsigned int N, template<typename...> class TT>
struct repeat
{
    using type = typename
        append_to_type_seq<
            T,
            typename repeat<T, N-1, TT>::type
            >::type;
};

template<typename T, template<typename...> class TT>
struct repeat<T, 0, TT>
{
    using type = TT<>;
};
```

As a small test:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>

template<typename... Ts>
struct X { };

int main()
{
    repeat<double, 5, std::tuple>::type t = std::make_tuple(1., 2., 3., 4., 5.);
    static_assert(
        std::is_same<
            decltype(t),
            std::tuple<double, double, double, double, double>
        >::value, "!");

    repeat<double, 3, X>::type y;
    static_assert(
        std::is_same<decltype(y), X<double, double, double>>::value, "!");
}
```

Finally, a [**live example**](http://ideone.com/iKJakv).

Comment: Great answer & nice code! But out of curiosity, do you also know what is wrong with my code?

Comment: @MarkusMayr: I have to confess I just had a brief look at it, I failed to understand the intended mechanism, and then started over with a solution that matched my intuition. So at the moment the answer is "I don't know" :(

Comment: @MarkusMayr: I had a deeper look at it, and understood your mechanism. Honestly, it seems OK to me. This might be a bug in GCC, since Clang compiles it fine. But I'm not 100% sure

Answer (score 10):

An [indices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7858971/726300)-based solution:

```
template<typename Dependent, int Index>
using DependOn = Dependent;

// Assuming e.g. Indices<3> is indices<0, 1, 2>
template<typename T, int N, typename I = Indices<N>>
struct repeat;

template<typename T, int N, int... Indices>
struct repeat<T, N, indices<Indices...>> {
    // Can be an actual type-list instead of (ab)using std::tuple
    using type = std::tuple<DependOn<T, Indices>...>;
};
```

[C++14 flavour](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3658.html):

```
template<typename Dependent, std::size_t Index>
using DependOn = Dependent;

template<typename T, std::size_t N, typename Indices = std::make_index_sequence<N>>
struct repeat;

template<typename T, std::size_t N, std::size_t... Indices>
struct repeat<T, N, std::index_sequence<Indices...>> {
    using type = std::tuple<DependOn<T, Indices>...>;
};
```

Comment: +1, but answers using indices like this need to start using C++14's `std::integer_sequence` :)

Comment: @JonathanWakely I may not have the time to fix my other preexisting answers but I agree with you.

Comment: Indices-based code was totally new to me. Thank you for pointing me in that direction. This is a very convenient way to think about many problems related to tuples and parameter packs.

Comment: Can someone add an simple example to this code? I failed to understand how it works.