# convert CUDA device interleaved array to tuple for vector operations

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust

How do I convert a device array that contains interleaved floats to a CUDA thrust tuple for thrust vector operations.

Purpose : I generate a crude list of vertices using Marching Cubes on CUDA. The output is a list of vertices, with redundancy and no connectivity. I wish to get a list of unique vertices and then an index buffer to these unique vertices, so I can perform some operations such as mesh simplification, etc...

```
float *devPtr; //this is device pointer that holds an array of floats
//6 floats represent a vertex, array size is vertsCount*6*sizeof(float).
//format is [v0x, v0y, v0z, n0x, n0y, n0z, v1x, v1y, v1z, n1x, ...]

typedef thrust::tuple<float, float, float, float, float, float> MCVertex;

thrust::device_vector<MCVertex> inputVertices(vertsCount);

//copy from *devPtr to inputVertices.

//use something like unique to get rid of redundancies.
thrust::unique(inputVertices.begin(), inputVertices.end());
```

how do I achieve the copy, or is there some other better way of doing this?

Comment: You have correctly identified `thrust::unique` as the stream compaction primitive which would do what you want. What is your question, exactly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no need to copy, you can use a combination of `thrust::zip_iterator` and a [`strided_range` iterator](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/blob/master/examples/strided_range.cu).

The following example works for a list of floats where 3 consecutive values belong to each other. It can of course be extended to support more than that, it is just a matter of typing.

The first step is to load some demo data on to the GPU, this uses a `thrust::device_vector`, but this results in a `float*` pointer just like you have.

Based on the `strided_range` iterator and the `thrust::zip_iterator` the data is first sorted and then compacted.
This code uses C++11 features, so compile it using:

```
nvcc -std=c++11 unique.cu -o unique
```

The output when running `./unique` is:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

**unique.cu**

```
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <thrust/unique.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/zip_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/sort.h>
#include <thrust/execution_policy.h>

template<typename... Iterators>
__host__ __device__
thrust::zip_iterator<thrust::tuple<Iterators...>> zip(Iterators... its)
{
    return thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(its...));
}

template <typename Iterator>
struct strided_range
{
    typedef typename thrust::iterator_difference<Iterator>::type difference_type;

    struct stride_functor : public thrust::unary_function<difference_type,difference_type>
    {
        difference_type stride;

        stride_functor(difference_type stride)
            : stride(stride) {}

        __host__ __device__
        difference_type operator()(const difference_type& i) const
        { 
            return stride * i;
        }
    };

    typedef typename thrust::counting_iterator<difference_type>                   CountingIterator;
    typedef typename thrust::transform_iterator<stride_functor, CountingIterator> TransformIterator;
    typedef typename thrust::permutation_iterator<Iterator,TransformIterator>     PermutationIterator;

    // type of the strided_range iterator
    typedef PermutationIterator iterator;

    // construct strided_range for the range [first,last)
    strided_range(Iterator first, Iterator last, difference_type stride)
        : first(first), last(last), stride(stride) {}

    iterator begin(void) const
    {
        return PermutationIterator(first, TransformIterator(CountingIterator(0), stride_functor(stride)));
    }

    iterator end(void) const
    {
        return begin() + ((last - first) + (stride - 1)) / stride;
    }

    protected:
    Iterator first;
    Iterator last;
    difference_type stride;
};

int main()
{
    const int stride = 3;
    const int num = 3;

    const int size = stride * num;

    float values[size] = {1,2,3,
                          4,5,6,
                          1,2,3};


    // in this example I use thrust vectors to simplify copying from host to device
    thrust::host_vector<float> h_vec (values, values+size);
    thrust::device_vector<float> d_vec = h_vec;

    // in your case, dev_ptr is your input pointer
    float* dev_ptr = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_vec.data());

    auto first =  strided_range<float*>(dev_ptr,   dev_ptr + size+1-stride,   stride);
    auto second = strided_range<float*>(dev_ptr+1, dev_ptr + size+1-stride+1, stride);
    auto third =  strided_range<float*>(dev_ptr+2, dev_ptr + size+1-stride+2, stride);

    auto zip_begin = zip(first.begin(),second.begin(), third.begin());
    auto zip_end = zip(first.end(), second.end(), third.end());

    thrust::sort(thrust::device, zip_begin, zip_end);
    auto new_end = thrust::unique(thrust::device, zip_begin,zip_end);
    std::size_t new_size = stride * (new_end - zip_begin);

    // use the underlying thrust::device_vector again to simplify printing
    thrust::copy(d_vec.begin(), d_vec.begin()+new_size, std::ostream_iterator<float>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

By the way: Be aware of floating point inaccuracies when trying to get unique values.

---

I also created a generic version of the example above which builds the `zip_iterator` automatically and works for any number of consecutive elements. Since the official thrust version unfortunately does not yet support variadic tuples, we use a `std::tuple` to build the desired tuple type and then convert it into a `thrust::tuple`. If [Andrew Corrigan's branch of thrust](https://github.com/andrewcorrigan/thrust-multi-permutation-iterator/tree/variadic) (which adds support for variadic tuples) was merged into thrust master, we could avoid using std::tuple at all.

Compile this example using:

```
nvcc generic_unique.cu -std=c++11 -o generic_unique
```

The output when running `./generic_unique` is:

```
input data: 1 2 3 4 5 6 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
after sort: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 1 2 3 4 5 6 1 2 3 4 5 6 
after unique: 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

**generic_unique.cu**

```
#include <tuple>
#include <thrust/tuple.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <thrust/unique.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/zip_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/sort.h>
#include <thrust/execution_policy.h>

// adapted from https://github.com/thrust/thrust/blob/master/examples/strided_range.cu
template <typename Iterator, typename thrust::iterator_difference<Iterator>::type stride>
class strided_range
{
public:
    typedef typename thrust::iterator_difference<Iterator>::type difference_type;

    //template <difference_type stride>
    struct stride_functor : public thrust::unary_function<difference_type,difference_type>
    {
        __host__ __device__
        difference_type operator()(const difference_type& i) const
        { 
            return stride * i;
        }
    };

    typedef typename thrust::counting_iterator<difference_type>                           CountingIterator;
    typedef typename thrust::transform_iterator<stride_functor, CountingIterator> TransformIterator;
    typedef typename thrust::permutation_iterator<Iterator,TransformIterator>             PermutationIterator;

    // type of the strided_range iterator
    typedef PermutationIterator iterator;

    // construct strided_range for the range [first,last)
    strided_range(Iterator first, Iterator last)
        : first(first), last(last) {}

    iterator begin(void) const
    {
        return PermutationIterator(first, TransformIterator(CountingIterator(0), stride_functor()));
    }

    iterator end(void) const
    {
        return begin() + ((last - first) + (stride - 1)) / stride;
    }

protected:
    Iterator first;
    Iterator last;
};

// copied from http://stackoverflow.com/a/16853775/678093
template<typename, typename>
struct append_to_type_seq { };

template<typename T, typename... Ts, template<typename...> class TT>
struct append_to_type_seq<T, TT<Ts...>>
{
    using type = TT<Ts..., T>;
};

template<typename T, unsigned int N, template<typename...> class TT>
struct repeat
{
    using type = typename
        append_to_type_seq<
            T,
            typename repeat<T, N-1, TT>::type
            >::type;
};

template<typename T, template<typename...> class TT>
struct repeat<T, 0, TT>
{
    using type = TT<>;
};

template<typename Tuple> struct std_to_thrust_tuple;
template<typename...T> struct std_to_thrust_tuple<std::tuple<T...>> {
  using type = thrust::tuple<T...>;
};

template<typename IteratorType, std::size_t stride>
class zipped_strided_range
{
public:

    typedef typename strided_range<IteratorType, stride>::iterator SingleIterator;
    typedef typename repeat<SingleIterator, stride, std::tuple>::type StdIteratorTuple;
    typedef typename std_to_thrust_tuple<StdIteratorTuple>::type IteratorTuple;
    typedef decltype(thrust::make_zip_iterator(IteratorTuple())) ZipIterator;

    zipped_strided_range(IteratorType first, IteratorType last) : first(first), last(last)
    {
        assign<0>();
    }

    ZipIterator begin() const
    {
        return thrust::make_zip_iterator(begin_tuple);
    }

    ZipIterator end() const
    {
        return thrust::make_zip_iterator(end_tuple);
    }

protected:

    template <std::size_t index>
    void assign(typename std::enable_if< (index < stride) >::type* = 0)
    {
        strided_range<IteratorType,stride> strided_range_iterator(first+index, last-(stride-1)+index);

        thrust::get<index>(begin_tuple) = strided_range_iterator.begin();
        thrust::get<index>(end_tuple) = strided_range_iterator.end();
        assign<index+1>();
    }

    template <std::size_t index>
    void assign(typename std::enable_if< (index == stride) >::type* = 0)
    {
        // end recursion
    }

    IteratorType first;
    IteratorType last;

    IteratorTuple begin_tuple;
    IteratorTuple end_tuple;
};


int main()
{

    const int stride = 6;
    const int num = 6;

    const int size = stride * num;

    float values[size] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,
                          0,0,0,0,0,0,
                          1,2,3,4,5,6,
                          0,0,0,0,0,0,
                          1,2,3,4,5,6,
                          0,0,0,0,0,0
    };


    // in this example I use thrust vectors to simplify copying from host to device
    // it also simplifies printing
    thrust::host_vector<float> h_vec (values, values+size);
    thrust::device_vector<float> d_vec = h_vec;

    std::cout << "input data: ";
    thrust::copy(d_vec.begin(), d_vec.end(), std::ostream_iterator<float>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << std::endl;

    // in your case, dev_ptr is your input pointer
    float* dev_ptr = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_vec.data());

    zipped_strided_range<float*, stride> zipped(dev_ptr, dev_ptr+size);


    thrust::sort(thrust::device, zipped.begin(), zipped.end());

    std::cout << "after sort: ";
    thrust::copy(d_vec.begin(), d_vec.end(), std::ostream_iterator<float>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << std::endl;

    auto new_end = thrust::unique(thrust::device, zipped.begin(), zipped.end());
    std::size_t new_size = stride * (new_end - zipped.begin());

    std::cout << "after unique: ";
    d_vec.resize(new_size);
    thrust::copy(d_vec.begin(), d_vec.end(), std::ostream_iterator<float>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks m.s. I tried your solution however I am not able to get my solution to build with the -std=c++11 flag. I use VS2013 and CUDA 7. 

It gives the following error : 
`CUDACOMPILE : nvcc warning : The -c++11 flag is not supported with the configured host compiler.`

am I specifying something wrong in the properties?
I put it in additional options.
`--std=c++11`

Comment: With VS2013 and CUDA 7, you don't need to add the `-std=c++11` flag.  It compiles that way by default.  The example given in this answer assumes linux, for which that flag is necessary to select C++11 features.

Comment: Perhaps nvcc does not like the variadic templates for functions.
Here is the error message I get with m.s.'s code at this line. `template<typename... Iterators>
__host__ __device__
thrust::zip_iterator<thrust::tuple<Iterators...>> zip(Iterators... its)`

The error is as follows : 
`unique.cu(76): error : a "__device__" function cannot have ellipsis`

am I missing some other flag somewhere?

Comment: I have no experience with CUDA7+C+11+VS2013. The error message suggests that `nvcc` treats the `...` as an ellipsis instead of a template parameter pack expansion. Mabye C++11 is not enabled for nvcc (but it should be as per comment by @RobertCrovella)? You could remove the `__device__` specifier for this function since it is not used in device code.

Comment: @HarishMandalika are you trying to compile `unique.cu` or `generic_unique.cu`?

Comment: I was trying to compile unique.cu. Anyways I think I found the problem. My platform toolset is set to v110 and this does not support variadic templates, hence nvcc thinks its an elipsis. I need to update this to v120 that supports it but unfortunately I rely on other libraries and projects which are all v110 and hence not link-able if I change this project version to v120.

Comment: For now I will simply define a tuple myself for the number of floats. This works for me. Unfortunately the `thrust::lower_bound()` does not work if zip iterater tuple is of type `strided_range<float*>` like in your example. But it does work if I use`strided_range<thrust::device_ptr<float>>` instead. Thanks a lot for the help m.s.

Comment: @HarishMandalika why doesn't `thrust::lower_bound()` work? Compiler error or runtime error?

Comment: Its a runtime error when I try to do `thrust::copy()` or `thrust::lower_bound()` on the `zip<>` of tuple of `strided_range<float*>` using raw device ptr, however, when I use `thrust::device_ptr<float>` instead of `<float*>` they work as expected. Not sure why it does not work with a raw pointer initialized strided_range.

PS : How does the compiler know weather the address in the raw_ptr is really on the device or on the host? 

The sort works for the sample code perfectly and the output is as expected however, a copy or lower_bound fails in a run-time error, not sure if this is VS specific.

Comment: @HarishMandalika you need to tell thrust that the data is on the GPU by specifying `thrust::device`  as the execution policy (first argument, see `thrust::sort(thrust::device,...` in the example above.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, thanks to [m.s.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/678093/m-s) for his answer as it pointed me in the right direction.

Please bear in mind though if you are using Microsoft Visual Studio, only VS2013 supports variadic tuples.

For c++11 feature support list for host compiler (cl.exe as in VS2013) use the link below.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx

PS : make sure you are building for v120 platform toolset to avail the variadic template feature.

Thanks to @[Robert Crovella](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1695960/robert-crovella), [-std=c++11] is set by default with VS2013 so the flag need not be set.

Back to the problem at hand, here is how I solved it using code from [m.s.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/678093/m-s) but using thrust::device_ptr instead of raw pointers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "thrust\host_vector.h"
#include "thrust\device_vector.h"
#include "thrust\sort.h"
#include "thrust\unique.h"
#include "thrust\binary_search.h"
#include "thrust\iterator\zip_iterator.h"
#include "thrust\execution_policy.h"

template <typename Iterator>
struct strided_range
{
    typedef typename thrust::iterator_difference<Iterator>::type     difference_type;

    struct stride_functor : public thrust::unary_function < difference_type, difference_type >
    {
        difference_type stride;

        stride_functor(difference_type stride)
            : stride(stride) {}

        __host__ __device__
            difference_type operator()(const difference_type& i) const
        {
            return stride * i;
        }
    };

    typedef typename thrust::counting_iterator<difference_type>                   CountingIterator;
    typedef typename thrust::transform_iterator<stride_functor, CountingIterator> TransformIterator;
    typedef typename thrust::permutation_iterator<Iterator, TransformIterator>     PermutationIterator;

    // type of the strided_range iterator
    typedef PermutationIterator iterator;

    // construct strided_range for the range [first,last)
    strided_range(Iterator first, Iterator last, difference_type stride)
        : first(first), last(last), stride(stride) {}

    iterator begin(void) const
    {
        return PermutationIterator(first, TransformIterator(CountingIterator(0), stride_functor(stride)));
    }

    iterator end(void) const
    {
        return begin() + ((last - first) + (stride - 1)) / stride;
    }

protected:
    Iterator first;
    Iterator last;
    difference_type stride;
};

//forcing it to be a 3-tuple one instead of using variadic templates
template<typename Iterator>
__host__ __device__
thrust::zip_iterator<thrust::tuple<Iterator, Iterator, Iterator>> zip(const         Iterator& sr1, const Iterator& sr2, const Iterator& sr3)
{
    return thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(sr1, sr2, sr3));
}

int main()
{

    const int stride = 3;
    const int num = 6;

    const int size = stride * num;

    //values on host
    float values[size] = { 1, 2, 3,
        4, 5, 6,
        1, 2, 3,
        4, 5, 6,
        1, 2, 3,
        7, 8, 9 };
    //ptr for device
    float *d_data;
    //allocate memory on the device
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_data, size*sizeof(float));
    //copy from host to device
    cudaMemcpy(d_data, values, size*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    //a typedef for device_ptr<float>
    typedef thrust::device_ptr<float> floatdevptr;

    //cast our raw pointer to device pointer
    floatdevptr dev_dataptr = thrust::device_pointer_cast(d_data);

    //create a device_vector from the dev_dataptr
    thrust::device_vector<float> d_vec(dev_dataptr, dev_dataptr + size);
    //make a copy
    thrust::device_vector<float> d_veccopy = d_vec;

    //create a device_vector to hold indices (6 indices for 6 vertices)
    thrust::device_vector<unsigned int> indices( num );

    //print input values
    std::cout << "Input Values : ";
    thrust::copy(d_vec.begin(), d_vec.begin() + size, std::ostream_iterator<float>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << std::endl;

    //a typedef for our strided_range<device_ptr<float>>
    typedef strided_range<floatdevptr>::iterator floatdevptr_stridedrangeiterator;

    //create the strided_range for x, y and z;
    strided_range<floatdevptr> dvx = strided_range<floatdevptr>(dev_dataptr + 0, dev_dataptr + size - stride + 1, stride);
    strided_range<floatdevptr> dvy = strided_range<floatdevptr>(dev_dataptr + 1, dev_dataptr + size - stride + 2, stride);
    strided_range<floatdevptr> dvz = strided_range<floatdevptr>(dev_dataptr + 2, dev_dataptr + size - stride + 3, stride);

    //create zip_iterator for the vertex
    auto zip_dv_first = zip<floatdevptr_stridedrangeiterator>(dvx.begin(), dvy.begin(), dvz.begin());
    auto zip_dv_last = zip<floatdevptr_stridedrangeiterator>(dvx.end(), dvy.end(), dvz.end());

    //sort
    thrust::sort(zip_dv_first, zip_dv_last);
    //remove duplicates
    auto new_dv_last = thrust::unique(zip_dv_first, zip_dv_last);
    //compute new size
    std::size_t new_dv_size = stride * (new_dv_last - zip_dv_first);

    //create the same for the copy.
    strided_range<floatdevptr> dvcpyx = strided_range<floatdevptr>(d_veccopy.data() + 0, d_veccopy.data() + size - stride + 1, stride);
    strided_range<floatdevptr> dvcpyy = strided_range<floatdevptr>(d_veccopy.data() + 1, d_veccopy.data() + size - stride + 2, stride);
    strided_range<floatdevptr> dvcpyz = strided_range<floatdevptr>(d_veccopy.data() + 2, d_veccopy.data() + size - stride + 3, stride);

    auto zip_dvcpy_first = zip<floatdevptr_stridedrangeiterator>(dvcpyx.begin(), dvcpyy.begin(), dvcpyz.begin());
    auto zip_dvcpy_last = zip<floatdevptr_stridedrangeiterator>(dvcpyx.end(), dvcpyy.end(), dvcpyz.end());

    //find index of each input vertex in the list of unique vertices
    thrust::lower_bound(zip_dv_first, new_dv_last,
        zip_dvcpy_first, zip_dvcpy_last,
        indices.begin());

    // print unique vertex data
    std::cout << "Output Values : ";
    thrust::copy(d_vec.begin(), d_vec.begin() + new_dv_size, std::ostream_iterator<float>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << std::endl;
    // print the indices
    std::cout << "Index Values : ";
    thrust::copy(indices.begin(), indices.end(), std::ostream_iterator<float>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Output is :

```
Input Values : 1 2 3 4 5 6 1 2 3 4 5 6 1 2 3 7 8 9 
Output Values : 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
Index Values : 0 1 0 1 0 2
```

Comment: [Usually one does not accept his own answer if it based on another one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/296944/678093). I don't really care and did not downvote your answer, I just wanted to let you know.

Comment: Indeed, I downvoted this. for precisely the reasons cited at the link above

Comment: I accept the answer that best fits my needs in the question. In this case I am getting a run-time error with m.s.'s answer and its limited to v120 platform toolset so I cant even get past compilation with v110. So I accepted my answer and provided code so it might help someone else. I did thank m.s. in the first line of my answer. I apologize if I did something wrong. I think I made my gratitude towards m.s. very clear. I will gladly accept m.s.'s answer if it benefits him.

Comment: @talonmies I am new to the forum and this is my first question, and simply downvoting does not help encourage new users.