# Generating parameter list at compile time

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, parameter-list

```
template<typename ... Args>
class Container 
{

    public:

    Container(Args&& ... args)
    : values_(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
    {}

    private:

    std::tuple<Args ...> values_;

};
```

Considering the code above, this is valid:

```
typedef Container<double,double,double> Container3d;
```

Would something like this be possible ?

```
typedef Container<3,double> Container3d;
```

Note that this should still remain possible:

```
Container<double,int> c(0.1,2);
```

Comment: The tricky part is answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16853552/how-to-create-a-type-list-for-variadic-templates-that-contains-n-times-the-sam

Comment: Is `Container<3,double>` supposed to be equivalent to `Container<double, double, double>`?

Comment: @super Yes. It would be a "shorthand" for it. Like Container<32,double> is more elegant than typing "double" 32 times. I guess a macro would do, but I am curious if there is a more elegant solution.