# Generalized lambda capture on param-pack?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14, variadic-functions

In C++14, generalized lambda capture let us do:

```
template<class T>
auto pack(T t)
{
    return [t=std::move(t)](auto&& f){f(t);};
};
```

But it doesn't play with param-pack:

```
template<class... T>
auto pack(T... t)
{
    return [t=std::move(t)...](auto&& f){f(t...);};
};
```

Is there any special syntax or further standard proposal to address this?

Comment: What problem are you having with capturing `&` and using `f(std::move(t)...)`?

Comment: @chris The references would become dangling as soon as `pack` returns, no?

Comment: @Brian, Oh yeah, good point. I didn't notice it was being returned.

Comment: It's intended to be used in replacement of tuple for callback, so I can't use reference which will become dangling.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

My draft of C++14 says ([expr.prim.lambda]/24):

> A *simple-capture* followed by an ellipsis is a pack expansion (14.5.3). An *init-capture* followed by an ellipsis is ill-formed.

So it looks like there is no way to do a variadic generalized capture. A possible workaround is to just capture the arguments in a tuple and then use one of the solutions suggested here: ["unpacking" a tuple to call a matching function pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7858817/unpacking-a-tuple-to-call-a-matching-function-pointer)

```
auto pack(T... t)
{
    return [args=make_tuple(std::move(t)...)](auto&& f){
               // find a way to call f with args
           };
};
```

**EDIT:**

It's now voted into C++20, made by this [proposal](http://wg21.link/p0780). Although the syntax is a bit different:

```
template<class... T>
auto pack(T... t)
{
    return [...t=std::move(t)](auto&& f){f(t...);};
};
```

Note that the `...` is before the init-capture.

Comment: "An init-capture followed by an ellipsis is ill-formed", so the draft author is aware of this possible usage and doesn't want to support it? hmm...

Comment: @Jamboree I suppose so. Maybe there are some technical issues that would make it hard to support, or maybe whoever submitted the proposal for init-captures wanted to keep it simple.

Comment: @Jamboree Here's a discussion: https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!topic/std-discussion/ePRzn4K7VcM

Comment: " // find a way to call f with args", in C++17 you can use `std::apply` for that, so this problem can be solved by: 1) capturing into a tuple as you propose, 2) writing a variadic lambda with the code you want to execute, 3) `std::apply` the tuple on the lambda.

Answer (score 4):

This expands on my comment to Brian answer above. In C++14 with the library fundamentals TS you can:

```
template<class... T>
auto pack(T... t)
{
    return [ts = std::make_tuple(std::move(t)...)](auto&& f){
        std::experimental::apply(f, ts);
    };
};
```

Supposing you want to generically capture a parameter pack by move and use it within a lambda you can write the code in a lambda within a lambda, and then apply the arguments on it:

```
[ts = std::make_tuple(std::move(t)...)](/* args */){
    auto lambda = [&](auto&&... args) {
      // - args is the original parameter pack that one wanted to 
      //   capture by move
      // - the other arguments can be used by reference
    };
    return std::experimental::apply(lambda, ts);
};
```

Answer (score 3):

As a follow-up, I came to this workaround:

```
template<class T>
struct mover
{
    mover(T const& val) : val(val) {}

    mover(T&& val) : val(std::move(val)) {}

    mover(mover const& other) = default;

    mover(mover&& other) = default; 

    mover(mover& other) : val(std::move(other.val)) {}

    operator T const&() const
    {
        return val; 
    }

    T val;
};

template<class T>
using wrap_t = typename std::conditional
    <
        std::is_move_constructible<T>::value
    && !std::is_trivially_copy_constructible<T>::value
      , mover<T>
      , T
    >::type;

template<class... Ts>
auto pack_impl(wrap_t<Ts>... ts)
{
    return [=](auto&& f)->decltype(auto)
    {
        return f(static_cast<Ts const&>(ts)...);
    };
}

auto pack = [](auto&&... ts)
{
    return pack_impl<std::decay_t<decltype(ts)>...>(static_cast<decltype(ts)>(ts)...);
};
```

It utilizes `mover` as a proxy, which allows lambda to capture it by move (it's a bit hacky). And `wrap_t` decides when is needed or beneficial to apply `mover`.

Now we can test it:

```
struct A
{
    A() = default;

    A(A&&)
    {
        std::cout << "move\n";
    }

    A(A const&)
    {
        std::cout << "copy\n";
    }
};

A a;
std::cout <<"p1------------\n";
auto p1 = pack(std::move(a));
std::cout <<"p2------------\n";
auto p2 = std::move(p1);
std::cout <<"p3------------\n";
auto p3 = p2;
```

Will print:

```
p1------------
move
move
p2------------
move
p3------------
copy
```