# Variadic templates - how can I create type, that stores passed arguments

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

So suppose, that I have got a class, that contains functional object and in the constructor call I pass arguments, that are to be passed to the functional object some time later. Something like:

```
class Binder{
public:
    Binder(functional_object, listOfParameters);
    callFunctionalObject(); // calls functional object with given list of parameters
};
```

Before C++11 I could not use Variadic templates, so one would do:

```
struct none{};

template <typename T1, typename T2=none, typename T3=none>
class Binder{
public:
    Binder(T1 functionalObject, T2 arg1=none(), T3arg3=none());
    void callFunctionalObject();
private:
    T1 m_functionalObject;
    T2 m_arg1;
    T3 m_arg2;
};
```

Where `callFunctionalobject` could be implemented as follows:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
void Binder<T1,T2,T3>::callFunctionalObject(){
    callImpl(m_functionalObject, m_arg1, m_arg2);
}
```

and `callImpl` would be overloaded to recognize objects of type `none` to pass proper amount of arguments to the functional object.

Now switching to C++11 I do not know how to implement the fact, that in private section I have got members, to which I have an direct access.

Could anyone explain me the way I can do the same using C++11 or C++14?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should store a `std::function` and a `std::tuple` and then call the function on the tuple.

Here a working C++14 solution

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template<typename T1, typename ...T>
class Binder
{
public:
    Binder(std::function<T1(T...)> f, std::tuple<T...> t) : m_functional_obj(f), m_parameters(t) {}

    template<std::size_t ...I>
    T1 callImpl(std::index_sequence<I...>) 
    {
        return m_functional_obj(std::get<I>(m_parameters)...);
    }

    T1 callFunctionalObject()
    { 
        return callImpl(std::index_sequence_for<T...>{}); 
    }
private:
    std::function<T1(T...)> m_functional_obj;
    std::tuple<T...>        m_parameters;
};

int test(int i) 
{
    std::cout << "test(" << i << ")" << std::endl;    
    return i + 1;
}

int main()
{
    Binder<int,int> bibi(test, std::make_tuple<int>(2));
    auto res = bibi.callFunctionalObject();
    std::cout << "res is " << res << std::endl;
}
```

**[Live code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7038169d1fff20c7)**

Comment: I thought of something like this, but wouldn't functionalObject then get one touple in the parameters instead of normal list of parameters?

Comment: Unpacking tuple parameters needs a little bit of work trying to get a live code solution for you :)

Comment: @DawidPi Updated a C++14 solution using `std::index_sequence`

Answer (score 4):

My example:

```
// Indices
template <std::size_t... Is>
struct Indices {};

template <std::size_t N, std::size_t... Is>
struct BuildIndices : BuildIndices <N - 1, N - 1, Is...> {};

template <std::size_t... Is>
struct BuildIndices<0, Is...> : Indices < Is... > {};

template<class FuncObject, class ... T>
class Binder
{
public:
    Binder(FuncObject funcObject, T... args)
      : m_funcObject(funcObject), m_arguments(std::make_tuple(args...))
    {
    }

    void Call()
    {
      DoCall(BuildIndices<sizeof ... (T)> {});
    }

private:
    template<size_t... Ind>
    void DoCall(Indices<Ind...>)
    {
        return m_funcObject(std::get<Ind>(m_arguments)...);
    }

    FuncObject m_funcObject;
    std::tuple<T...> m_arguments;
};

void Foo(int, char)
{
}

int main()
{
    Binder<void(*)(int, char), int, char> f(Foo, 1, 'd');
    f.Call();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is good, plus in C++14 you don't need your own `Indices` and `BuildIndices` classes any more.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to store an `std::function` object with already-set arguments using `std::bind`:

```
class Binder{
public:
    template <typename T1, typename... T2>
    Binder(T1 functionalObject, T2... args) : f(std::bind(functionalObject, args...)) {}
    void callFunctionalObject() { f(); }
private:
    std::function<void()> f;
};

void foo(int n, std::string s) {
    std::cout << n << " " << s << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    Binder b(foo, 42, "test");
    b.callFunctionalObject();
}
```

If you need something more advanced, then you might want to store the function arguments in and `std::tuple` and then use some template magic to unwrap it, but please specify what exactly do you need in the question.

P.S. See also ["unpacking" a tuple to call a matching function pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7858817/unpacking-a-tuple-to-call-a-matching-function-pointer)

Comment: Ok std::bind seems ok and easy way, but still I do not know what kind of mechanism is laying behind this. I should try to look for std::bind implementation then. What I am looking for is the same functionality as code give n in question but more flexible (maximum number of parameters is not set up from the start) using Variadic Templates.

Comment: I don't think you need the template parameters at the class level, you could just make the constructor a template and people could just use `Binder b(foo, 32, "test");`.

Comment: This then becomes an advantage of using `std::bind` over storing the parameters manually in a `std::tuple`.  Whether that advantage is meaningful to the OP or not is another matter though.