# how to capture a parameter pack by forward or move?

Tags: c++, c++17

Say I have this function:

```
template <typename ...A>
void test(A&& ...a)
{
  [=]()
  {
  };
}
```

is the parameter pack going to be forwarded into the lambda or just copied by value? I'm concerned, since I'd have to make an explicit `move()` or `forward()` usually, as `a...` are lvalues. Is a tuple intermediary necessary to forward/move them? If so, does there exist an easy way to unpack the tuple into a parameter pack, without using the indices trick?

Comment: How about capture it by reference and then use forward inside lambda body ? Capturing by value will not do that for you.

Comment: Also if you could write a pseudo code on what exactly you want to do, that would be helpful.

Comment: How do you plan to use your lambda? Also, too bad `[a = (std::forward<A>(a)...)](){};` doesn't compile. The compiler may optimize the capture if you do not use the arguments anywhere else.

Comment: It's about running some code in a thread. If I capture by reference, the references may be dangling by the time the thread starts running. So the idea is to copy everything by forwarding it, then use the copies inside the thread.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One of the few remaining useful things that can be done with [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind). The capturing is performed by `bind` and the captured values are passed as arguments to a capture-less generic lambda:

```
template <typename... A>
auto test(A&&... a)
{
    auto f = [](auto&&... a)
    {
        // use a...
    };
    return std::bind(f, std::forward<A>(a)...);
}
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/18225ea0d45db8cb)

The above works with Clang, but this GCC seems to have an issue with a spurious `volatile` qualifier.

We can do it without `bind` by capturing a `tuple` in a second lambda that calls [`std::apply`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply) (C++17) to unpack the tuple into the first lambda's parameter list:

```
template <typename... A>
auto test(A&&... a)
{
    auto f = [](auto&&... a)
    {
        // use a...
    };
    return [f, tup = std::make_tuple(std::forward<A>(a)...)]() mutable { std::apply(f, tup); };
}
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/002bb9b6c4a4f57c)

Works with Clang and GCC; `apply` is implemented with the indices trick that you wanted to avoid, but you are not exposed to it. The `mutable` means the second lambda's call operator is non-const, so the tuple elements don't end up gaining a `const` qualification.

---

## C++20

C++20 has proper support for capturing by perfect forwarding:

```
template <typename... A>
auto test(A&&... a)
{
    return [...a = std::forward<A>(a)]()
    {
        // use a...
    };
}
```

Comment: What if the lambda has a parameter?

Answer (score 8):

One way would be to write a functor in the Haskell sense.  Well a variardic one, which isn't very Haskell.

Write a function of signature `(Ts...)->( ((Ts...)->X) -> X )`.  Ie a function that takes a pack, and returns a function.  The returned function can take a function taking that pack and evaluate it.

```
template<class...Ts>
auto make_functor(Ts&&...ts); // TODO
```

Once we have that we can solve your problem easily.

```
template<class ...A>
auto test(A&& ...a) {
  return [unpack_a=make_functor(std::forward<A>(a)...)]() mutable
  {
    return unpack_a([&](auto&&...a){
      // here you have access to a...
      return sizeof...(a);
    });
  };
}
```

`test` takes a pack, and returns a function that returns the size of that pack (well, does anything with the pack).

`make_functor` is not easy: basically, we write a manual lambda, storing the args in a tuple, and unpacking the musing the indexes trick in an operator ().

In effect, we do the pack storing and unpacking *once* in a manual pseudo-lambda class, then get to reuse it later.

On second thought, it may be better to write a delayed apply that takes a tuple, stores it, then uses `std::apply` later.

```
template<class...Ts>
auto delayed_apply(std::tuple<Ts...> tup){
  return [tup=std::move(tup)](auto&&f)->decltype(auto) mutable{
    return std::experimental::apply(decltype(f)(f), std::move(tup));
  };
}
```

which lets the value/refness of parameters be not lost!

```
template<class ...A>
auto test(A&& ...a) {
  return [unpack_a=delayed_apply(std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<A>(a)...))]() mutable
  {
    return unpack_a([&](auto&&...a){
      // here you have access to a...
      return sizeof...(a);
    });
  };
}
```

this does require `std::experimental::apply`.

If you want to *store* rvalues and leave lvalues as references:

```
unpack_a=delayed_apply(std::tuple<A...>(std::forward<A>(a)...))
```

If you want to store both l and r values:

```
unpack_a=delayed_apply(std::make_tuple(std::forward<A>(a)...))
```

as you can see, this approach gives lots of control.

If you need a `std::experimental::apply`, there are reference implementations: better those than anything I write on a smartphone.

Note that `make_functor` can be written in terms of `delayed_apply`, but the opposite is ... not as true.

In case you are confused, `unpack_a` takes a lambda and unpacks the tuple used to create `unpack_a` into it.  Basically we store one object that is the entire pack, then unpack it when we need it inside the body of the lambda.

A longer `delayed_apply` that handles both const and non-const and maybe even rvalue overloads may be required if you want the unpacking to work "more than once" sometimss and "only once" other times.  It will have to return a class, not a lambda.  Annoying.  Made the example code work, I think, still not compiling.

Fortunetally this kind of thing is write once, use many.

Comment: Is this forward inside necessary? `std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<A>(a)...)`

Comment: @coy depends on use case.  Sometimes yes sometimes no.

Answer (score 3):

First capture the arguments in a tuple with perfect forwarding:

```
template <typename ...A>
void test(A&& ...a)
{
  [tup= std::tuple<A...>(std::forward<A>(a)...)]()
  {
       //tup should contain the forwarded elements
  };
}
```

Then use this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7858971/835629 to unpack the tuple in your later function calls.

```
//utils
template<int ...>
struct seq { };

template<int N, int ...S>
struct gens : gens<N-1, N-1, S...> { };

template<int ...S>
struct gens<0, S...> {
  typedef seq<S...> type;
};


template<typename F, typename T, int ...S>
void unpackTupleToFunction_utils(F func, const T &tup, seq<S...>) {
 func(std::get<S>(tup) ...);
}

template<typename F, typename ...Args, int ...S>
void unpackTupleToFunction(F func, const std::tuple<Args...> &tup) {
 unpackTupleToFunction_utils(func, tup, typename gens<sizeof...(Args)>::type());
}
```

And finally to unpack the tuple inside the lambda in order to call a function with it:

```
template <typename ...Args>
void test(Args&& ...a) {
  auto lambda = [tup= std::tuple<Args...>(std::forward<Args>(a)...)]()
  {
    unpackTupleToFunction(f, tup);
  };

  lambda();
  lambda();
  lambda();
}
```

---

PS: It's a pity that something like `[a = (std::forward<Args>(a)...)](){};` doesn't compile.

Comment: Yes, yes, but the indices trick is something I'm trying to avoid, you are completely correct though.

Answer (score 2):

why wouldn't it passed by value? the forwarding is to the top function only.

let's say you pass a `int` , `std::string&` and `float&&` for example, so your function will look like

```
void test(int,string&,float&&)
{
  [=]()
  {
  };
}
```

from there, the anonymous lambda will **copy** the `int`,`string&` and `float&&` by value. a copy of a reference is still a copy.
you can use a `tuple` to pack the arguments again and unpack them inside the lambda.

how to use a tuple inside the lamda?

1. use a recursion like we usually do with variadic template
2. find some non standard implementation of `std::apply` and use the tuple as arguments for anotehr function

Comment: Yes, but how to unpack without the indices to `get<>()`

Comment: A copy of a reference is a value in this context, and no longer a reference.  And this copy is generated by copy, not move, even from rvalues.

Comment: @user1095108 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7858817/unpacking-a-tuple-to-call-a-matching-function-pointer