# CUDA Kernel Scheduler on GPU

Tags: c++, cuda

I'm writing a CUDA kernel scheduler. The scheduler gets a vector of `Task` pointers and brings them to execution. The pointers point to `KernelTask` objects of different type parameters to support kernels with arbitrary parameters.

There's a CPU version of the Scheduler and a GPU version. The CPU version works just fine. It calls the virtual function `Task::start` to execute a Kernel. The GPU version has three problems:

1. Virtual functions are not allowed in CUDA. How can I avoid them without down casting?
2. std::get is a host function. Is there a way to implement std::get myself for the GPU?
3. (Low priority) Because `KernelTask` objects are of diffrent size I copy all of them seperatly with `copyToGPU()`. Is there a way for batch copying?

Here is the code:

```
// see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7858817/unpacking-a-tuple-to-call-a-matching-function-pointer
template<int ...>
struct seq { };

template<int N, int ...S>
struct gens : gens<N-1, N-1, S...> { };

template<int ...S>
struct gens<0, S...> {
  typedef seq<S...> type;
};

class Task {
private:
    bool visited;
    bool reached;
protected:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Task>> dependsOn;
    Task();
public:
    Task **d_dependsOn = NULL;
    int d_dependsOnSize;
    Task *d_self = NULL;

    int streamId;
    int id;
    cudaStream_t stream;

    virtual void copyToGPU() = 0;
    virtual void start() = 0;
    virtual void d_start() = 0;
    virtual ~Task() {}
    void init();
    void addDependency(std::shared_ptr<Task> t);
    cudaStream_t dfs();
};

template<typename... Args>
class KernelTask : public Task {
private:
    std::tuple<Args...> params;
    dim3 threads;
    dim3 blocks;
    void (*kfp)(Args...);

    template<int ...S>
    void callFunc(seq<S...>) {
        // inserting task into stream
        this->kfp<<<this->blocks, this->threads, 0, this->stream>>>(std::get<S>(params) ...);
        checkCudaErrors(cudaGetLastError());

        if (DEBUG) printf("Task %d: Inserting Task in Stream.\n", this->id);
    }

    template<int ...S>
    __device__ void d_callFunc(seq<S...>) {
        // inserting task into stream
        this->kfp<<<this->blocks, this->threads, 0, this->stream>>>(std::get<S>(params) ...);

        if (DEBUG) printf("Task %d: Inserting Task in Stream.\n", this->id);
    }

    KernelTask(int id, void (*kfp)(Args...), std::tuple<Args...> params, dim3 threads, dim3 blocks);

public:
    ~KernelTask();
    void copyToGPU();

    void start() override {
        callFunc(typename gens<sizeof...(Args)>::type());
    }

    __device__ void d_start() override {
        d_callFunc(typename gens<sizeof...(Args)>::type());
    }

    static std::shared_ptr<KernelTask<Args...>> create(int id, void (*kfp)(Args...), std::tuple<Args...> params, dim3 threads, dim3 blocks);
};

class Scheduler {
private:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Task>> tasks;
public:
    Scheduler(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Task>> &tasks) {
        this->tasks = tasks;
    }

    void runCPUScheduler();
    void runGPUScheduler();
};
```

---

EDIT:

(1) Virtual Functions in CUDA: I get a `Warp Illegal Address` exception in `scheduler` in the following example:

```
struct Base {
    __host__ __device__ virtual void start() = 0;
    virtual ~Base() {}
};

struct Derived : Base {
    __host__ __device__ void start() override {
        printf("In start\n");
    }
};

__global__ void scheduler(Base *c) {
    c->start();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    Base *c = new Derived();
    Base *d_c;
    checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc(&d_c, sizeof(Derived)));
    checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy(d_c, c, sizeof(Derived), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    c->start();
    scheduler<<<1,1>>>(d_c);

    checkCudaErrors(cudaFree(d_c));

    return 0;
}
```

(2) `thrust::tuple` works fine.

(3) I'm open to suggestions.

(4) How do I pass a kernel function pointer to a kernel? I get a `Warp Misaligned Address` exception in the following example:

```
__global__ void baz(int a, int b) {
    printf("%d + %d = %d\n", a, b, a+b);
}

void schedulerHost(void (*kfp)(int, int)) {
    kfp<<<1,1>>>(1,2);
}

__global__ void schedulerDevice(void (*kfp)(int, int)) {
    kfp<<<1,1>>>(1,2);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    schedulerHost(&baz);
    schedulerDevice<<<1,1>>>(&baz);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `Virtual functions are not allowed in CUDA`. They are. `Is there a way to implement std::get myself`. Yes, even though strictly speaking this is not allowed by the standard.

Comment: When calling d_start() from a Task Object I get the following Signal: `CUDA_EXCEPTION_14:Warp Illegal Address`. Do you have an idea on how to implement std::get?

Comment: please post a [mcve]

Comment: See my edit regarding kernel arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**"Virtual functions are not allowed in CUDA. How can I avoid them without down casting?"**

You can have both virtual `__host__` and `__device__` functions:  http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/#virtual-functions

However:

> It is not allowed to pass as an argument to a `__global__` function an
>   object of a class with virtual functions.

---

**"std::get is a host function. Is there a way to implement std::get myself for the GPU?**"

I'd suggest using `thrust::tuple` instead which has both a `__host__` and a `__device__` implementation:
    http://thrust.github.io/doc/group__tuple.html

---

**Regarding function pointers:**

> The address of a `__global__` function taken in host code cannot be
>   used in device code (e.g. to launch the kernel).

http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#function-pointers

Comment: For virtual functions: How do I use them out of kernel, if I'm not allowed to pass an object to that kernel? Can I only use static virtual functions out of kernels?

Comment: @martin you need to allocate the object I device code, then you can call virtual functions on said object in a kernel

Comment: For function pointers: It's possible to do the following: `__constant__  void (*d_baz)(int,int) = &baz;`. Then `cudaMemcpyFromSymbol()` to a host variable which you can pass to a kernel where you can call `baz`. Works for my GPU Scheduler.