# Transform typelist with function at runtime

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

I have a typelist. I would like to create a tuple with the results of calling a function on each type in that list and then use that as arguments to another functor. So something like this:

```
template<typename F>
struct function_traits;

template<typename T, typename R, typename... Args>
struct function_traits<R(T::*)(Args...) const> {
    using return_type = R;
    using param_types = std::tuple<Args...>;
};

template<typename T> struct function_traits : public
function_traits<decltype(&T::operator())> {};

template <typename T>
T* get_arg(int id)
{
    // Actual implementation omitted. Uses the id parameter to 
    // do a lookup into a table and return an existing instance 
    // of type T.
    return new T();
}

template <typename Func>
void call_func(Func&& func, int id)
{
    using param_types = function_traits<Func>::param_types>;

    func(*get_arg<param_types>(id)...); // <--- Problem is this line
}

call_func([](int& a, char& b) { }, 3);
```

The problem is that `func(*get_arg<param_types>(id)...);` doesn't actually compile since param_types is a tuple and not a parameter pack. The compiler generates this error: "there are no parameter packs available to expand". What I would liked to have happened is for that line to expand to:

```
func(*get_arg<int>(id), *get_arg<char>(id));
```

And to have that work for any number of arguments. Is there any way to get that result?

This question seems similar but does not solve my problem by itself: ["unpacking" a tuple to call a matching function pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7858817/unpacking-a-tuple-to-call-a-matching-function-pointer). I have a type list and from that I want to generate a list of values to use as function arguments. If I had the list of values I could expand them and call the function as outlined in that question, but I do not.

Comment: What is the expected result of the call to `func` inside `call_func`? That all arguments should be equal to `id`? In your example `call_func([](int& a, char& b) { }, 3)` what will the argument o the lambda be?

Comment: The id parameter isn't really important. In my use-case I use it inside get_arg to figure out which instance of T to return. The arguments to the lambda would hopefully be the results of calling get_arg for each type in the typelist, similar to what I wrote above: `func(*get_arg<int>(id), *get_arg<char>(id));`

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["unpacking" a tuple to call a matching function pointer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7858817/unpacking-a-tuple-to-call-a-matching-function-pointer)

Comment: It's not. I have a list of types, not a list of values. I do not know how to create a list of values by calling the get_arg function on each type. If I could do that, then that question would be helpful.

Comment: "I have a type list and from that I want to generate a list of values to use as function arguments.".
Here's a typelist: `int`, `std::list<char>`, `double`. If *you* don't know what values you would like
to generate from it, nobody does. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: I do know the values? In your example they would be `get_arg<int>(id)`, `get_arg<std::list<char>>(id)`, `get_arg<double>(id)`. I've tried to explain this twice now and I'm not sure a better way to do so. If you have a suggestion or can point to exactly where anything I've said is potentially confusing then please let me know so I can ask better questions in the future.

Comment: Oh. I think I should have provided the implementation for get_args. I left it out for brevity but perhaps I've lead you to believe I'm asking how to implement that function? The problem I'm actually having is the line: `func(*get_arg<param_types>(id)...)`. That does not compile because param_types is a tuple instead of a parameter pack. My wish is that it would expand to this: `func(*get_arg<int>(id), *get_arg<char>(id));` I will update my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure that is what do you want.

I don't know how to expand, inside `call_func()`, the parameters pack of `params_type` but, if you afford the use of a helper struct and a compiler with C++14...

I've prepared the following example with support for return type.

```
#include <tuple>

template<typename F>
struct function_traits;

template<typename T, typename R, typename... Args>
struct function_traits<R(T::*)(Args...) const> {
    using return_type = R;
    using param_types = std::tuple<Args...>;
};

template<typename T> struct function_traits : public
function_traits<decltype(&T::operator())> {};

template <typename T, typename ... Args>
T get_arg (std::tuple<Args...> const & tpl)
 { return std::get<typename std::decay<T>::type>(tpl); } 

template <typename ...>
struct call_func_helper;

template <typename Func, typename Ret, typename ... Args>
struct call_func_helper<Func, Ret, std::tuple<Args...>>
 {
   template <typename T, typename R = Ret>
      static typename std::enable_if<false == std::is_same<void, R>::value, R>::type
                fn (Func const & func, T const & t)
       { return func(get_arg<Args>(t)...); }

   template <typename T, typename R = Ret>
      static typename std::enable_if<true == std::is_same<void, R>::value, R>::type
                fn (Func const & func, T const & t)
       { func(get_arg<Args>(t)...); }
 };

template <typename Func,
          typename T,
          typename R = typename function_traits<Func>::return_type>
R call_func (Func const & func, T const & id)
 {
    using param_types = typename function_traits<Func>::param_types;

    return call_func_helper<Func, R, param_types>::fn(func, id);
 }

int main()
 {
   call_func([](int const & a, char const & b) { }, std::make_tuple(3, '6'));

   return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nice! I have to wrap my head around this but I think this does everything I need. I'm (pleasantly) surprised you're able to use `<Func, Ret, std::tuple<Args...>>` as a specialization for the lambda? I would have thought it would need to look like the uglier `R(T::*)(Args...) const` specialization on`function_traits`.