# c++11 how to implement `std::string ToString(std::tuple<Args...> &t)`?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, stdtuple

I want a very friendly `ToString` function for many types, include the `std::tuple`. The function is like this:

```
template <typename T>
inline std::string ToString(const T &t) { 
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << t;
    return ss.str();
}

template <typename... Args>
inline std::string ToString(const std::tuple<Args...> &t) {
    std::stringstream ss;
    for (int i = 0; i < t.size(); i++) {
        ss << ToString(std::get<i>(t)) << " ";
    }
    return ss.str();
}
```

The second part is wrong on grammar, how to implement it with c++11 template ?

And, how to implement the `FromString` like this:

```
template <typename T>
inline T FromString(const std::string &s) {
    std::stringstream ss(s);
    T t;
    ss >> t;
    return t;
}

template <typname... Args>
inline std::tuple<Args...> FromString(const std::string &s) {
    std::tuple<Args...> ret;
    ret.resize(sizeof...Args);
    std::stringstream ss;
    size_t pos;
    for (int i = 0, prev_pos = 0; i < sizeof...Args and prev_pos < s.length(); i++) {
        pos = s.find(" ", prev_pos);
        T t = FromString(s.substr(prev_pos, pos));
        std::get<i>(ret) = t;
        prev_pos = pos
    }
    return ret;
}
```

The second part is also wrong on c++11 grammar, how to implement it ?

Comment: Templates are *compile time only*. You can not use run-time variables as template arguments. To solve this I recommend you have a helper-function which takes a parameter pack, and you [unpack the tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7858817/unpacking-a-tuple-to-call-a-matching-function-pointer) in a call to that helper function.

Comment: In template metaprogramming, iteration is usually done using recursion.

Comment: I'm not good at c++ template, so I'm not sure how to write the code exactly... would you show me the code ?

Comment: You might use `std::index_sequence`

Comment: This gets much easier in C++14 and even easier in C++17.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In C++17, you may do:

```
template <typename ... Ts>
std::string ToString(const Ts& ... ts) { 
    std::stringstream ss;
    const char* sep = "";
    ((static_cast<void>(ss << sep << ts), sep = " "), ...);
    return ss.str();
}

template <typename... Args>
std::string ToString(const std::tuple<Args...> &t) {
    return std::apply([](const auto&... ts) { return ToString(ts...); }, t);
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/380f1b2d8b964b47)

Comment: @Holt Trailing whitespace

Comment: @PasserBy Original version did not remove the trailing whitespace, updated one does though ;)

Comment: does `boost::apply_visitor` do the same thing? it doesn't require c++17

Comment: [en.cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply) provides possible implementation. `boost::apply_visitor` is to visit `variant`.

Comment: @zhaochenyou Even if it does, [fold expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) require C++17.

Comment: @Jarod42 Could you detail the behavior of this particular fold expression? I am very intrigued.

Comment: Because I'm a git, `struct evil { friend evil operator<<( std::ostream& os, evil ) { return {}; } template<class X> friend void operator,(evil, X&&){ exit(-1); } }` and `ToString( evil{} )`; always do a `void` cast before using `,` in generic code.

Comment: @Holt: Fold expression with operator comma: `ss << sep << ts;` followed by `sep = " "` for each `ts`.

Comment: Note that in compliant C++ compilers, you can replace `(static_cast<void>(ss << sep << ts), sep = " ")` with `[&]{ss << sep << ts); sep = " ";}()`, which I think is clearer; the downside is that many compilers will fail to work, as they erronously cannot work out that the pack expansion (of `ts...`) occurs outside of the lambda, and generate an error saying tha `ts` is not expanded.

Answer (score 4):

```
namespace notstd {
  template<std::size_t...Is>
  struct index_sequence {};
  template<std::size_t N, std::size_t...Is>
  struct make_index_sequence:make_index_sequence<N-1,N-1,Is...>{};
  template<std::size_t...Is>
  struct make_index_sequence<0,Is...>:index_sequence<Is...>{};

#define RETURNS(...) \
  noexcept(noexcept(__VA_ARGS__)) \
  -> decltype(__VA_ARGS__) \
  { return __VA_ARGS__; }

  namespace details {
    template<class F, class Tuple, std::size_t...Is>
    auto apply( F&& f, Tuple&& tuple, index_sequence<Is...> )
    RETURNS( std::forward<F>(f)( std::get<Is>(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple))... ) )
    template<class Tuple>
    using raw_tuple = typename std::remove_cv<typename std::remove_reference<Tuple>::type>::type;
    template<class Tuple>
    using tuple_count = std::tuple_size< raw_tuple<Tuple> >;
  }
  template<class F, class Tuple>
  auto apply( F&& f, Tuple&& tuple )
  RETURNS(
    ::notstd::details::apply(
      std::forward<F>(f),
      std::forward<Tuple>(tuple),
      ::notstd::make_index_sequence<
        ::notstd::details::tuple_count<Tuple>::value
      >{}
    )
  )
}
```

now this `::notstd::apply` behaves a lot like C++17's `std::apply`.

We then glue this to your `ToString` via `ToStream`:

```
struct to_stream_t;

template<class...Args>
void ToStream(std::ostream& os, const std::tuple<Args...>& t) {
  os << '{';
  ::notstd::apply( to_stream_t{os}, t );
  os << '}';
}
inline void ToStream(std::ostream&) {}
template<class T>
void ToStream(std::ostream& os, const T& t) { 
  os << t;
}
template<class T0, class... Ts>
void ToStream(std::ostream& os, const T0& t0, const Ts& ... ts) { 
  ToStream(os, t0);
  using discard=int[];
  (void)discard{0,((
    void(os << ' '), to_stream_t{os}(ts)
  ),0)...};
}
struct to_stream_t {
  std::ostream& os;
  template<class...Args>
  void operator()(Args const&...args) const {
    ToStream(os, args...);
  }
};
template<class...Ts>
std::string ToString( Ts const&... ts ) {
  std::stringstream ss;
  ToStream( ss, ts... );
  return ss.str();
}
```

this also flattens recursive tuples.

If you add more `std` or fundamental type manual `ToStream` implementations, put them *before* the body of `to_stream_t` or recursion won't work.  And recurse via `to_stream_t{os}(t)` instead of `ToStream(os, t)` generally so you find the right overloads.

Test code:

```
std::tuple<std::string, std::string, int> t("hello", "world", 42);
std::cout << ToString(t, "-", t);
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b3d7140ab8df4240).

We can augment with vector support:

```
template<class T, class A>
void ToStream(std::ostream& os, const std::vector<T, A>& v) {
  os << '[';
  for (auto const& x:v)
  {
    if (std::addressof(x) != v.data())
        os << ',';
    to_stream_t{os}(x);
  }
  os << ']';
}
```

then test with all of this:

```
std::tuple<std::string, std::string, int> t("hello", "world", 42);
std::cout << ToString(t, "-", t) << "\n";
std::vector< int > v {1,2,3};
std::cout << ToString(v) << "\n";
std::vector< std::tuple<int, int> > v2 {{1,2},{3,4}};
std::cout << ToString(v2) << "\n";
auto t2 = std::tie( v, v2 );
std::cout << ToString(t2) << "\n";
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/80e94d0d5c2d2d5b).

The end output is:

```
{hello world 42} - {hello world 42}
[1,2,3]
[{1 2},{3 4}]
{[1,2,3] [{1 2},{3 4}]}
```

as expected.

Comment: @holt typos fixed.  I transitions from `ToStream` to `ToStream` to remove temporary `std::string`s and missed some stuff.

Comment: @holt It was required for `ToStream` to support that if I wanted to support recursive tuples.  And not supporting that sucks!

Comment: @holt There might be a lookup problem; the `to_stream_t` moves the point where we do lookup on `ToStream` inside `to_stream_t` to *after* every `ToStream` is declared.  If I use a lambda, I'd need ADL to find `ToStream`s declared *after* the lambda.  I could use an ADL token, but that is annoying.  `to_stream_t` seems easier.

Comment: Did not realize you posted earlier :P BTW yours is about a billion times nicer

Comment: @holt And what do you do when you want vector and tuple to mutually recurse on their contents?  Yet more repeating oneself.  I'd rather repeat myself once.

Answer (score 1):

In C++11 you may <strike>want to give up</strike> do this

```
#include<iostream>
#include<tuple>
#include<utility>
#include<sstream>

template<size_t... I>
struct index_sequence {};

template<size_t N, size_t sz, size_t... I>
struct make_index_sequence_
{
    using type = typename make_index_sequence_<N, sz + 1, I..., sz>::type;
};

template<size_t N, size_t... I>
struct make_index_sequence_<N, N, I...>
{
    using type = index_sequence<I...>;  
};

template<size_t N>
using make_index_sequence = typename make_index_sequence_<N, 0>::type;

template<typename Fn, typename Tuple, size_t... I>
auto apply_(Fn&& fn, Tuple&& tup, index_sequence<I...>) -> decltype(fn(std::get<I>(tup)...))
{
    return fn(std::get<I>(tup)...);
}

template<typename Fn, typename Tuple>
auto apply(Fn&& fn, Tuple&& tup) -> decltype(apply_(std::forward<Fn>(fn), std::forward<Tuple>(tup), make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<typename std::remove_reference<Tuple>::type>::value>{}))
{
    return apply_(std::forward<Fn>(fn), std::forward<Tuple>(tup), make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<typename std::remove_reference<Tuple>::type>::value>{});
}
```

All those above is re-implementing the standard library in newer C++.

```
template<typename T>
std::string ToString(const T& t)
{ 
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << t;
    return ss.str();
}

template<typename T, typename... Ts>
std::string ToString(const T& t, const Ts&... ts)
{
    return ToString(t) + ToString(ts...);   
}

template<typename... Ts>
std::string ToString(const std::tuple<Ts...>& tup)
{
    return apply<std::string (*)(const Ts&...)>(ToString, tup);   
}
```

And these are the real logic.

[Live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/912335b6ee9a4391)

Gave me appreciation on a whole new level just how great syntax sugar is.