# Unpack tuple to member initialization or superclass constructor

Tags: c++, c++17, template-meta-programming, stdtuple, argument-unpacking

Is it possible to initialize a member of a class (or call superclass constructor) by using the arguments contained in a tuple?
Please note that I am aware of `std::make_from_tuple()` and `std::apply()` but they cannot be used in this scenario.

Consider `sometype` is **non** copyable, **non** default constructible, **non** movable, **non** assignable, non anything else. The only way to instantiate it is by using using the arguments that are provided as a `std::tuple`.
Can this be done?

My attempt fails as appereantly "expansion pattern contains no argument pack" though the index_sequence generate should be one.

```
class node {
    public:
    sometype value;
    template <typename... Args>
    explicit node(const std::tuple<Args...>& args_tuple) :
            value(
                std::get<
                    std::index_sequence_for<Args...>{}
                >(args_tuple)...
            ) {
    }
};
```

Comment: `std::make_from_tuple()` should work thanks to guaranteed copy elision. Did you try it?

Comment: Do you have to take a tuple?  If not you can use `explicit node(Args...&& args) : value(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}`

Comment: Also related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7858817/unpacking-a-tuple-to-call-a-matching-function-pointer

Comment: `But they cannot be used in this scenario` - why?

Comment: "but they cannot be used in this scenario." Why not?

Comment: Because the value that is being constructed is non copiable, non assignable

Comment: @Brian I tried now, std::make_from_tuple seems to be working, though this is counter intuitive. If the semantics of the language is appearenatly being broken by allowing you to "copy" withouth having access to a copy constructor, then what is the point of all emplace methods that containers have?

Comment: As a side note, I don't understand the reason for a -1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you insist on not using `std::make_from_tuple()`, you need another level of indirection:

```
public:
    explicit node(const std::tuple<Args...>& args_tuple) :
        node(args_tuple, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Args)>{})
    { }

private:
    template<class Tuple, std::size_t... is>
    node(const Tuple& args_tuple, std::index_sequence<is...>) :
        value(std::get<is>(args_tuple)...)
    { }
```