# Initialize std::tuple with variadic arguments in constructor

Tags: c++, templates, types, variadic-templates, sfinae

I have a class that creates an `std::function`. For simplicity, I'll say the `std::function` returns a boolean for this example. The `std::function` needs to take in a variadic tuple. Currently, I have

```cpp
template<class... FuncArgs>
class Function
{
public:
    // Type that std::function returns
    using func_ret_ty = bool;

private:
    std::function<func_ret_ty(std::tuple<FuncArgs...>)> m_Function;
    std::tuple<FuncArgs...> m_Args;  // Stores m_Function's arguments

public:
    Function(
        std::function<func_ret_ty(std::tuple<FuncArgs...>)> function,
        FuncArgs... args)
        : m_Function(function)
        , m_Args(std::make_tuple(std::forward<FuncArgs>(args)...))
    {}
};
```

My question is simple: will this work?

More specifically, I'm concerned because there seems to be a circular dependency in declaring the type for `function`. Another thought for implementation I had was:

```cpp
template<class FuncTy, class FuncArgs...>
class Function
{
public:
    using func_ret_ty = bool;

private:
    FuncTy m_Function;
    std::tuple<FuncArgs...> m_Args;

public:
    Function(
        FuncTy function,
        FuncArgs... args)
        : m_Args(std::make_tuple(std::forward<FuncArgs>(args)...))
    {
        static_assert(
            std::is_same_v<FuncTy, std::function<func_ret_ty(std::tuple<FuncArgs...>)>>,
            "FuncTy invalid type!"
        );

        m_Function = std::move(function);
    }
};
```

Is the second implementation better? Is there a better way to go about doing this?

Comment: Your `static_assert` is too restrictive, [`std::is_assignable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_assignable) seems more appropriate.

Comment: I don't see you *circular dependency*.

Comment: @Jarod42 The reason I believed there was a circular dependency is because I declare the types for `FuncArgs...` after using those types in the `std::function` parameter type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first implementation looks better to me, because you don't have to repeat yourself by providing the function arguments twice.
Because you set the return type to `bool`, I would recommend changing the name of the class to `Predicate`, which is a well known term to describe functions that return boolean values.

Note that `std::function` can take parameter packs as template parameters too, so you can also do this:

```cpp
std::function<func_ret_ty(FuncArgs...)> m_Function;
```

Comment: Thank you. The reason I didn't use the parameter pack directly is because I have a method in this class called `run()`, which passes `m_Args` into `m_Function`, meaning I need to store whatever the parameter pack's values. I don't know how to do that other than a tuple. Is there another way?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7858817/unpacking-a-tuple-to-call-a-matching-function-pointer does this answer your question?