# Is it possible to write a generic variadic zipWith in C++?

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

I want a generic zipWith function in C++ of variable arity. I have two problems. The first is that I cannot determine the type of the function pointer passed to zipWith. It must be of the same arity as the number of vectors passed to zipWith and it must accept references to the vectors' element types respectively. The second is that I have no idea how to walk these vectors in parallel to build an argument list, call func(), and bail once the shortest vector is exhausted.

```
template <typename R, typename T, typename... Vargs>
std::vector<R> zipWith (R func(???<what goes here>), std::vector<T> first, Vargs rest) {
   ???
}
```

Comment: Accept a functor and not a function pointer. Don't take a vector by value. Use iterators. Use outputiterators. This is really hard to get right.

Comment: Have you had a look at boost iterator library? It provides a zip iterator that actually passes a tipple of iterators to the function that is called

Comment: @mark: looks like you've enjoyed a "tipple" or two yourself, tonight ;P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had a long answer, then I changed my mind in a way that made the solution much shorter.  But I'm going to show my thought process and give you both answers!

My first step is to determine the proper signature.  I don't understand all of it, but you can treat a parameter pack as a comma-separated list of the actual items with the text-dump hidden.  You can extend the list on either side by more comma-separated items!  So directly applying that:

```
template <typename R, typename T, typename... Vargs>
std::vector<R> zipWith (R func(T,Vargs...), std::vector<T> first, Vargs rest) {
   ???
}
```

You have to put a "..." after a parameter pack for an expression section to see the expanded list.  You have to put one in the regular parameter portion, too:

```
template <typename R, typename T, typename... Vargs>
std::vector<R> zipWith (R func(T,Vargs...), std::vector<T> first, Vargs... rest) {
   ???
}
```

You said that your function parameters are a bunch of vectors.  Here, you're hoping that each of `Vargs` is really a `std::vector`.  Type transformations can be applied to a parameter pack, so why don't we ensure that you have vectors:

```
template <typename R, typename T, typename... Vargs>
std::vector<R> zipWith (R func(T,Vargs...), std::vector<T> first, std::vector<Vargs> ...rest) {
   ???
}
```

Vectors can be huge objects, so let's use `const` l-value references.  Also, we could use `std::function` so we can use lambda or `std::bind` expressions:

```
template <typename R, typename T, typename... Vargs>
std::vector<R> zipWith (std::function<R(T, Vargs...)> func, std::vector<T> const &first, std::vector<Vargs> const &...rest) {
   ???
}
```

(I ran into problems here from using `std::pow` for testing.  My compiler wouldn't accept a classic function pointer being converted into a `std::function` object.  So I had to wrap it in a lambda.  Maybe I should ask here about that....)

At this point, I reloaded the page and saw one [response (by pmr)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9729574/1010226).  I don't really understand this zipping, folding, exploding, whatever stuff, so I thought his/her solution was too complicated.  So I thought about a more direct solution:

```
template < typename R, typename T, typename ...MoreTs >
std::vector<R>
zip_with( std::function<R(T,MoreTs...)> func,
 const std::vector<T>& first, const std::vector<MoreTs>& ...rest )
{
    auto const      tuples = rearrange_vectors( first, rest... );
    std::vector<R>  result;

    result.reserve( tuples.size() );
    for ( auto const &x : tuples )
        result.push_back( evaluate(x, func) );
    return result;
}
```

I would create a vector of tuples, where each tuple was made from plucking corresponding elements from each vector.  Then I would create a vector of
evaluation results from passing a tuple and `func` each time.

The `rearrange_vectors` has to make table of values in advance (default-constructed) and fill out each entry a sub-object at a time:

```
template < typename T, typename ...MoreTs >
std::vector<std::tuple<T, MoreTs...>>
rearrange_vectors( const std::vector<T>& first,
 const std::vector<MoreTs>& ...rest )
{
    decltype(rearrange_vectors(first, rest...))
      result( first.size() );

    fill_vector_perpendicularly<0>( result, first, rest... );
    return result;
}
```

The first part of the first line lets the function access its own return type without copy-and-paste.  The only caveat is that r-value reference parameters must be surrounded by `std::forward` (or `move`) so a l-value overload of the recursive call doesn't get chosen by mistake.  The function that mutates part of each tuple element has to explicitly take the current index.  The index moves up by one during parameter pack peeling:

```
template < std::size_t, typename ...U >
void  fill_vector_perpendicularly( std::vector<std::tuple<U...>>& )
{ }

template < std::size_t I, class Seq, class ...MoreSeqs, typename ...U >
void  fill_vector_perpendicularly( std::vector<std::tuple<U...>>&
 table, const Seq& first, const MoreSeqs& ...rest )
{
    auto        t = table.begin();
    auto const  te = table.end();

    for ( auto  f = first.begin(), fe = first.end(); (te != t) && (fe
     != f) ; ++t, ++f )
        std::get<I>( *t ) = *f;
    table.erase( t, te );
    fill_vector_perpendicularly<I + 1u>( table, rest... );
}
```

The table is as long as the shortest input vector, so we have to trim the table whenever the current input vector ends first.  (I wish I could mark `fe` as `const` within the `for` block.)  I originally had `first` and `rest` as `std::vector`, but I realized I could abstract that out; all I need are types that match the standard (sequence) containers in iteration interface.  But now I'm stumped on `evaluate`:

```
template < typename R, typename T, typename ...MoreTs >
R  evaluate( const std::tuple<T, MoreTs...>& x,
 std::function<R(T,MoreTs...)> func )
{
     //???
}
```

I can do individual cases:

```
template < typename R >
R  evaluate( const std::tuple<>& x, std::function<R()> func )
{ return func(); }

template < typename R, typename T >
R  evaluate( const std::tuple<T>& x, std::function<R(T)> func )
{ return func( std::get<0>(x) ); }
```

but I can't generalize it for a recursive case.  IIUC, `std::tuple` doesn't support peeling off the tail (and/or head) as a sub-tuple.  Nor does `std::bind` support currying arguments into a function in piecemeal, and its placeholder system isn't compatible with arbitrary-length parameter packs.  I wish I could just list each parameter like I could if I had access to the original input vectors....

...Wait, why don't **I do just that**?!...

...Well, I never heard of it.  I've seen transferring a template parameter pack to the function parameters; I just showed it in `zipWith`.  Can I do it from the function parameter list to the function's internals?  (As I'm writing, I now remember seeing it in the member-initialization part of class constructors, for non-static members that are arrays or class types.)  Only one way to find out:

```
template < typename R, typename T, typename ...MoreTs >
std::vector<R>
zip_with( std::function<R(T,MoreTs...)> func, const std::vector<T>&
 first, const std::vector<MoreTs>& ...rest )
{
    auto const  s = minimum_common_size( first, rest... );
    decltype(zip_with(func,first,rest...))         result;

    result.reserve( s );
    for ( std::size_t  i = 0 ; i < s ; ++i )
        result.push_back( func(first[i], rest[i]...) );
    return result;
}
```

where I'm forced to compute the total number of calls beforehand:

```
inline  std::size_t minimum_common_size()  { return 0u; }

template < class SizedSequence >
std::size_t  minimum_common_size( const SizedSequence& first )
{ return first.size(); }

template < class Seq, class ...MoreSeqs >
std::size_t
minimum_common_size( const Seq& first, const MoreSeqs& ...rest )
{ return std::min( first.size(), minimum_common_size(rest...) ); }
```

and sure enough, it worked!  Of course, this meant that I over-thought the problem just as bad as the other respondent (in a different way).  It also means that I unnecessarily bored you with most of this post.  As I wrapped this up, I realized that the replacement of `std::vector` with generic sequence-container types can be applied in `zip_width`.  And I realized that I could reduce the mandatory one vector to no mandatory vectors:

```
template < typename R, typename ...T, class ...SizedSequences >
std::vector<R>
zip_with( R func(T...) /*std::function<R(T...)> func*/,
 SizedSequences const& ...containers )
{
    static_assert( sizeof...(T) == sizeof...(SizedSequences),
     "The input and processing lengths don't match." );

    auto const  s = minimum_common_size( containers... );
    decltype( zip_with(func, containers...) )     result;

    result.reserve( s );
    for ( std::size_t  i = 0 ; i < s ; ++i )
        result.push_back( func(containers[i]...) );
    return result;
}
```

I added the `static_assert` as I copied the code here, since I forgot to make sure that the `func`'s argument count and the number of input vectors agree.  Now I realize that I can fix the dueling function-pointer vs. `std::function` object by abstracting both away:

```
template < typename R, typename Func, class ...SizedSequences >
std::vector<R>
zip_with( Func&& func, SizedSequences&& ...containers )
{
    auto const     s = minimum_common_size( containers... );
    decltype( zip_with<R>(std::forward<Func>(func),
     std::forward<SizedSequences>(containers)...) )  result;

    result.reserve( s );
    for ( std::size_t  i = 0 ; i < s ; ++i )
        result.push_back( func(containers[i]...) );
    return result;
}
```

Marking a function parameter with an r-value reference is the universal passing method.  It handles all kinds of references and `const`/`volatile` (cv) qualifications.  That's why I switched `containers` to it.  The `func` could have any structure; it can even be a class object with multiple versions of `operator ()`.  Since I'm using r-values for the containers, they'll use the best cv-qualification for element dereferencing, and the function can use that for overload resolution.  The recursive "call" to internally determine the result type needs to use `std::forward` to prevent any "downgrades" to l-value references.  It also reveals a flaw in this iteration: I **must** provide the return type.

I'll fix that, but first I want to explain the STL way.  You do not pre-determine a specific container type and return that to the user.  You ask for a special object, an output-iterator, that you send the results to.  The iterator could be connected to a container, of which the standard provides several varieties.  It could be connected to an output stream instead, directly printing the results!  The iterator method also relieves me from directly worrying about memory concerns.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstddef>
#include <iterator>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

inline  std::size_t minimum_common_size()  { return 0u; }

template < class SizedSequence >
std::size_t  minimum_common_size( const SizedSequence& first )
{ return first.size(); }

template < class Seq, class ...MoreSeqs >
std::size_t  minimum_common_size( const Seq& first,
 const MoreSeqs& ...rest )
{
    return std::min<std::size_t>( first.size(),
     minimum_common_size(rest...) );
}

template < typename OutIter, typename Func, class ...SizedSequences >
OutIter
zip_with( OutIter o, Func&& func, SizedSequences&& ...containers )
{
    auto const  s = minimum_common_size( containers... );

    for ( std::size_t  i = 0 ; i < s ; ++i )
        *o++ = func( containers[i]... );
    return o;
}

template < typename Func, class ...SizedSequences >
auto  zipWith( Func&& func, SizedSequences&& ...containers )
 -> std::vector<decltype( func(containers.front()...) )>
{
    using std::forward;

    decltype( zipWith(forward<Func>( func ), forward<SizedSequences>(
     containers )...) )  result;
#if 1
    // `std::vector` is the only standard container with the `reserve`
    // member function.  Using it saves time when doing multiple small
    // inserts, since you'll do reallocation at most (hopefully) once.
    // The cost is that `s` is already computed within `zip_with`, but
    // we can't get at it.  (Remember that most container types
    // wouldn't need it.)  Change the preprocessor flag to change the
    // trade-off.
    result.reserve( minimum_common_size(containers...) );
#endif
    zip_with( std::back_inserter(result), forward<Func>(func),
     forward<SizedSequences>(containers)... );
    return result;
}
```

I copied `minimum_common_size` here, but explicitly mentioned the result type for the least-base case, proofing against different container types using different size types.

Functions taking an output-iterator usually return iterator after all the iterators are done.  This lets you start a new output run (even with a different output function) where you left off.  It's not critical for the standard output iterators, since they're all pseudo-iterators.  It is important when using a forward-iterator (or above) as an output iterator since they **do** track position.  (Using a forward iterator as an output one is safe as long as the maximum number of transfers doesn't exceed the remaining iteration space.)  Some functions put the output iterator at the end of the parameter list, others at the beginning; `zip_width` must use the latter since parameter packs have to go at the end.

Moving to a suffix return type in `zipWith` makes every part of the function's signature fair game when computing the return type expression.  It also lets me know right away if the computation can't be done due to incompatibilities at compile-time.  The `std::back_inserter` function returns a special output-iterator to the vector that adds elements via the `push_back` member function.

Comment: Very nice train of thought, +1. :) Though I thought the whole time "why doesn't he just template the function...", heh.

Comment: It's nice to see how the design decision of the stdlib make implementing something a lot easier. +1 for actually trying to implement OPs actual function signature.

Comment: Each sequence-container type has to support the `size`, `front`, and `operator []` non-static member functions, with their expected meaning.  That limits standard containers to `std::vector` and `std::deque`.  Maybe if each sequence was represented by an iterator begin/end pair, and traversal/dereferencing was done by messing with the first iterator of the pair, we could adapt the algorithm for any container that returns forward-iterators.  (Pre-compute the range sizes with `std::distance`.)

Comment: I forgot that `std::array` could also work.   On another note, STL stands for the Standard Template Library, where the template-based parts of the standard library (since C++98) came from.

Comment: I was going to post a query on writing `evaluate`, but I found relevant posts like "[How do I expand a tuple into variadic template function's arguments?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/687490/1010226)".  Good thing I didn't search right away, since my alternative saves space, time, and code.

Comment: I wanted to tinker some more, so I copied my code, plus some improvments, [within my area](https://gist.github.com/2081658) at GitHub/Gist.

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I cobbled together:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

template<typename F, typename T, typename Arg>
auto fold(F f, T&& t, Arg&& a) 
  -> decltype(f(std::forward<T>(t), std::forward<Arg>(a)))
{ return f(std::forward<T>(t), std::forward<Arg>(a)); }

template<typename F, typename T, typename Head, typename... Args>
auto fold(F f, T&& init, Head&& h, Args&&... args) 
  -> decltype(f(std::forward<T>(init), std::forward<Head>(h)))
{ 
  return fold(f, f(std::forward<T>(init), std::forward<Head>(h)), 
              std::forward<Args>(args)...); 
}

// hack in a fold for void functions
struct ignore {};

// cannot be a lambda, needs to be polymorphic on the iterator type
struct end_or {
  template<typename InputIterator>
  bool operator()(bool in, const std::pair<InputIterator, InputIterator>& p) 
    { return in || p.first == p.second; }
};

// same same but different
struct inc {
  template<typename InputIterator>
  ignore operator()(ignore, std::pair<InputIterator, InputIterator>& p) 
    { p.first++; return ignore(); }
};

template<typename Fun, typename OutputIterator, 
         typename... InputIterators>
void zipWith(Fun f, OutputIterator out, 
             std::pair<InputIterators, InputIterators>... inputs) {
  if(fold(end_or(), false, inputs...)) return;
  while(!fold(end_or(), false, inputs...)) {
    *out++ = f( *(inputs.first)... );
    fold(inc(), ignore(), inputs...);
  }
}

template<typename Fun, typename OutputIterator, 
         typename InputIterator, typename... Rest>
void transformV(Fun f, OutputIterator out, InputIterator begin, InputIterator end,
                Rest... rest) 
{
  if(begin == end) return ;
  while(begin != end) {
    *out++ = f(*begin, *(rest)... );
    fold(inc2(), ignore(), begin, rest...);
  }
}

struct ternary_plus {
  template<typename T, typename U, typename V>
  auto operator()(const T& t, const U& u, const V& v) 
    -> decltype( t + u + v) // common type? 
    { return t + u + v; }
};

int main()
{
  using namespace std;
  vector<int> a = {1, 2, 3}, b = {1, 2}, c = {1, 2, 3};
  vector<int> out;

  zipWith(ternary_plus(), back_inserter(out)
          , make_pair(begin(a), end(a))
          , make_pair(begin(b), end(b))
          , make_pair(begin(c), end(c)));

  transformV(ternary_plus(), back_inserter(out),
             begin(a), end(a), begin(b), begin(c));

  for(auto x : out) { 
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

This is a slightly improved variant over previous versions. As every
good program should, it starts by defining a left-fold.

It still does not solve the problem of iterators packed in pairs.

In stdlib terms this function would be called `transform` and would
require that only the length of one sequence is specified and the
others be at least as long. I called it `transformV` here to avoid
name clashes.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Embarrassing.

Comment: I like the fold techique. Is all the code here? I cannot find transformV nor understand the purpose of end_or and inc.

Comment: Never mind. My phone's browser was truncating your code. Clicking "edit revealed" it.

Comment: @SamuelDanielson Going forward from `foldl` and `foldr` on argument lists you probably want to implement some of the most needed list functions like `map` and `zip`. It would be nice to have this as a small library.