# Name of a transversal reduction operation?

Tags: c++, function, naming

I am currently writing a highly templated C++ helper class for vectorized operations and I need a name for a specific operation.

I have already 2 functions with very common names taken from vectorial languages :

- `apply()` which apply a function to each element of a vector
- `reduce()` which apply a reduction operation over the vector and returns a scalar

Now I would like to implement another function, which is a mix between these two : it takes several vectors as an input, and apply a reduction operation over each line, and returns a vector.

To illustrate that, we have :

- `apply(func, vec)` -> returns `{func(vec[0]), func(vec[1]), ..., func(vec[n])}`
- `reduce(func, vec)` -> returns `func(vec[0], vec[1], ..., vec[n])`

and :

- `something(func, vec1, vec2, ..., vecn)` -> 
  returns `{func(vec0[0], vec1[0], ..., vecn[0]), func(vec0[1], vec1[1], ..., vecn[1]), ..., func(vec0[n], vec1[n], ..., vecn[n])}`

What would be a common name for this function (a simple verb like apply or reduce) (compatible with other vectorial languages if such a function exists) ?

Comment: Isn't the standard name for this MapReduce? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce

Comment: it's just combining a zip and a map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe zip_with which I've seen used from Haskell?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9729127/is-it-possible-to-write-a-generic-variadic-zipwith-in-c