# Why gcc can't inline function pointers that can be determined?

Tags: c++, gcc

The following program compiled under gcc 4.6.2 on centos with -O3:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class F {
public:
     typedef void (T::*Func)();

     F(Func f) : f_(f) {}

     void operator()(T& t) {
         (t.*f_)();
     }
private:
     Func f_;
};

struct X {
    X() : x_(0) {}

    void f(){
        ++x_;
    }

    int x_;
};

int main()
{
     const int N = 100000000;
     vector<X> xv(N);
     auto begin = clock();
     for_each (xv.begin(), xv.end(), F<X>(&X::f));
     auto end = clock();
     cout << end - begin << endl;
}
```

`objdump -D` shows that the generated code for the loop is:

```
  40097c:       e8 57 fe ff ff          callq  4007d8 <clock@plt>
  400981:       49 89 c5                mov    %rax,%r13
  400984:       0f 1f 40 00             nopl   0x0(%rax)
  400988:       48 89 ef                mov    %rbp,%rdi
  40098b:       48 83 c5 04             add    $0x4,%rbp
  40098f:       e8 8c ff ff ff          callq  400920 <_ZN1X1fEv>
  400994:       4c 39 e5                cmp    %r12,%rbp
  400997:       75 ef                   jne    400988 <main+0x48>
  400999:       e8 3a fe ff ff          callq  4007d8 <clock@plt>
```

Obviously gcc doesn't inline the function.  Why isn't gcc capable of this optimization?  Is there any compiler flag that can make gcc do the desired optimization?

Answer (score 8):

I think, GCC tries to optimize whole `main` function, but fails (lots of indirect calls of global functions to allocate/free memory for `xv`, get timer value, input/output, etc). So, you can try to split your code into two (or more) independent parts, like this:

```
inline
void foobar(vector<X>& xv)
{
  for_each (xv.begin(), xv.end(), F<X>(&X::f));
}

int main()
{
  const int N = 100000000;
  vector<X> xv(N);
  auto begin = clock();
  foobar(xv);
  auto end = clock();
  cout << end - begin << endl;
}
```

So, now we have "equivalent" code as before, but GCC's optimizer has easier task to do now. I don't see any calls of `ZN1X1fEv` in assembler listing now.

Comment: your answer can't be generalized to more complicated cases.  I'll edit the question.

Comment: @icando general rule to help a compiler with optimization is "do not try to optimize complicated functions".

Answer (score 7):

Some good reading material on this is Scott <s>Adams</s> Meyers' Effective C++ (Third Edition) Item 30: Understand the ins and outs of inlining, where he claims that a call to function pointer is never inlined. The third edition was published in 2008, and I have indeed been able to get gcc to inline function call by compile-time-constant-pointer starting in gcc 4.6, which came out in 2011 (maybe 2010?).  However, this was in C and is tricky.  In one scenario, I had to declare the calling function `__attribute__((flatten))` before it would inline the call (in this situation, I passed the function pointer as the member of a struct, who's pointer I then passed to an inline function that would make the function call by pointer that got inlined).

So in short, no, this isn't a bug gcc, but that doesn't mean that gcc (and/or other compilers) might not be able to inline this some day.  But the real issue, I think, is that you don't understand what's really happening here.  To get that understanding, you have to think more like an assembly programmer, or a compiler programmer.

You're passing an object of type `F<X>` and initializing it with a pointer to a member function of another class.  You have not declared your instance `F<X>` object constant, it's `Func f_` member as constant, nor your `void F::operator()(T& t)` member as constant.  At the C++ language level, the compiler has to treat it as non-constant.  That still doesn't mean that it can't later, at the optimization stage, determine that your function pointer doesn't change, but you're making it incredibly hard at this point.  But at least it's a local.  If your `F<X>` object had been global and not declared `static`, it would forbid it entirely from being considered constant.

Hopefully, you're doing this on an exercise in inlining by function pointer and not as a real solution for indirection.  When you want C++ to make real performance stuff, you use the power of types.  Specifically, when I declare a template parameter as a member function pointer, it isn't just a constant, it's part of the type.  I've never seen a case where this technique generates a function call.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

template <typename T, void (T::*f_)()>
class F {
public:
     void operator()(T& t) {
         (t.*f_)();
     }
};

struct X {
    X() : x_(0) {}

    void f(){
        ++x_;
    }

    int x_;
};

int __attribute__((flatten)) main()
{
     const int N = 100000000;
     vector<X> xv(N);

     auto begin = clock();
     for_each (xv.begin(), xv.end(), F<X, &X::f>());
     auto end = clock();
     cout << end - begin << endl;

}
```

Comment: In my example, compiler already knows that it should call _ZN1X1fEv (X::f) so that it generates the assembly `callq ZN1X1fEv` directly instead of calling through a pointer. Obviously you only remembers some rule (function pointer can't be inlined), but don't understand why. If compiler can determine its value at compile time, there is no reason it can't be inline. Also your example is totally irrelevant, logically, it shows a situation where gcc works, but I am asking why it doesn't work on my case.

Comment: @icando Basically, it doesn't work because it doesn't have to. I have given you a reference (the Scott Myers) and you can also read the [spec](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3690.pdf). The C++ compiler does not have to inline functions you call via pointer, and gcc only *ever* does that because they added an optimization for it (`-findirect-inline` introduced in 4.6.0), which is *not* perfect. See also [always_inline function attribute](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html).

Comment: @DanielSantos, well as I said tons of times I know C++ compiler can ignore the `inline` keyword.  My original question is why the optimizer fails to inline it, even though it can tell the exactly value of the function pointer by static analysis (because it generates the correct function call directly instead of indirectly).

Comment: @DanielSantos while you answer is interesting, it isn't the answer to Kan Li's question.

Comment: "Inlining" means not replacing something to a direct call, but to move the contents of some function to the place you call it, so you won't need a stack frame and a function call at all (passing arguments, and so on). So, I don't understand how replacing a some argument call to a direct function call means "inlining". @KanLi Do you think I am wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

You could add `inline __attribute__((__always_inline__))` to your function, and `-Winline` flag to compiler, so you'll be noticed when compiler fail to inline function.

Unfortunately, attribute will not make your function inlined, and `Winline` not sound alarm. Untill 4.8. BUT!!! From 4.9 this issue seems to be fixed!

So, grab your gcc 4.9, add always_inline flag, set optimizer to -O3 level. And be happy!

Proof:
http://goo.gl/kkuXzb

Comment: Actually, that isn't fixed yet, even in 4.10. [I was just discussing this a few days ago](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2014-07/msg00240.html). It may work in *your* case, but it wont always work (currently). Also, as I was mentioning with `always_inline`, it won't produce an error when indirection is used and it fails to inline either. :( I recently got [the docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) updated to reflect this. BTW, that's a really cool web site!