# Function pointer indirection not optimized by gcc or clang - bug or intended?

Tags: c++, optimization, function-pointers, compiler-optimization, conditional-operator

Given the following two functions:

```
int f() { return 0; }
int g() { return 1; }
```

And the following code to invoke one of them depending on a boolean `b`:

```
int t0(bool b) { return (b ? &f : &g)(); }
int t1(bool b) { return b ? f() : g(); }
int t2(bool b) { return b ? t0(true) : t0(false); }
```

Both `g++ (trunk)` and `clang++ (trunk)` with `-std=c++2a -Ofast -march=native` fail to optimize the following code:

```
int main(int ac, char**) { return t0(ac & 1); }
```

Producing the following assembly:

> ```
> main:
>   and edi, 1
>   mov eax, OFFSET FLAT:f()
>   mov edx, OFFSET FLAT:g()
>   cmove rax, rdx
>   jmp rax
> ```

Invoking `t1` or `t2` (instead of `t0`) produces the following optimized assembly:

> ```
> main:
>         mov     eax, edi
>         not     eax
>         and     eax, 1
>         ret
> ```

Everything can be reproduced [live on **gcc.godbolt.org**](https://godbolt.org/z/gh7270).

---

I find it puzzling that invoking `t0` directly in `main` doesn't get optimized, while invoking it in `t2` is OK.

**Is there a reason why invoking `t0` does not produce the same assembly as `t1` or `t2`?** Or is this a missed optimization opportunity by both `g++ (trunk)` and `clang++ (trunk)`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10047448/why-gcc-cant-inline-function-pointers-that-can-be-determined

Comment: "is this a missed optimization opportunity?": Yes. All `t*` functions works the same, they can be optimized to the same code.