# C++11: I can go from multiple args to tuple, but can I go from tuple to multiple args?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I expand a tuple into variadic template function's arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687490/how-do-i-expand-a-tuple-into-variadic-template-functions-arguments)
>   [“unpacking” a tuple to call a matching function pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7858817/unpacking-a-tuple-to-call-a-matching-function-pointer)

In C++11 templates, is there a way to use a tuple as the individual args of a (possibly template) function?

Example:
Let's say I have this function:

```
void foo(int a, int b)  
{  
}
```

And I have the tuple `auto bar = std::make_tuple(1, 2)`.

Can I use that to call `foo(1, 2)` in a templaty way?

I don't mean simply `foo(std::get<0>(bar), std::get<1>(bar))` since I want to do this in a template that doesn't know the number of args.

**More complete example:**

```
template<typename Func, typename... Args>  
void caller(Func func, Args... args)  
{  
    auto argtuple = std::make_tuple(args...);  
    do_stuff_with_tuple(argtuple);  
    func(insert_magic_here(argtuple));  // <-- this is the hard part  
}
```

I should note that I'd prefer to not create one template that works for one arg, another that works for two, etc…

Comment: Sure. You want something like `template <typename F, typename Tuple, int N...> call(F f, Tuple const & t) { f(std::get<N>(t)...); }`. Now just fill in the blanks :-)

Comment: Do you mean skipping variadic templates and creating multiple `caller()` templates instead?

Comment: @Thomas: You'll have to make a little dispatching harness that builds up the integer pack `N...`, and partially specializing when `N == std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value`, you want to call the original function in the way I suggested.

Comment: (It should have been `int ...N`, of course.)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
// implementation details, users never invoke these directly
namespace detail
{
    template <typename F, typename Tuple, bool Done, int Total, int... N>
    struct call_impl
    {
        static void call(F f, Tuple && t)
        {
            call_impl<F, Tuple, Total == 1 + sizeof...(N), Total, N..., sizeof...(N)>::call(f, std::forward<Tuple>(t));
        }
    };

    template <typename F, typename Tuple, int Total, int... N>
    struct call_impl<F, Tuple, true, Total, N...>
    {
        static void call(F f, Tuple && t)
        {
            f(std::get<N>(std::forward<Tuple>(t))...);
        }
    };
}

// user invokes this
template <typename F, typename Tuple>
void call(F f, Tuple && t)
{
    typedef typename std::decay<Tuple>::type ttype;
    detail::call_impl<F, Tuple, 0 == std::tuple_size<ttype>::value, std::tuple_size<ttype>::value>::call(f, std::forward<Tuple>(t));
}
```

Example:

```
#include <cstdio>
int main()
{
    auto t = std::make_tuple("%d, %d, %d\n", 1,2,3);
    call(std::printf, t);
}
```

With some extra magic and using `std::result_of`, you can probably also make the entire thing return the correct return value.

Comment: @JonathanWakely : `call_impl` is an implementation detail -- users never call it directly, global `call` is all that users interface with. Is the example that unclear?

Comment: Ah no, I just hadn't looked properly, I thought `call` was a replacement for the OP's `caller` and so the unwieldy use of `call_impl` happened in the user's code.

Comment: This, my good sir, is confounding, and deserves an up vote.

Comment: That's the best way of unpacking std::tuple I've found on stackoverflow yet and it has half of the upvotes of much worse solutions...

Comment: Just a suggestion, you might wanna throw an `auto` in there for call so you can use the return value of a function as well, BTW other than that really like the solution

Answer (score 4):

Create an "index tuple" (a tuple of compile-time integers) then forward to another function that deduces the indices as a parameter pack and uses them in a pack expansion to call `std::get` on the tuple:

```
#include <redi/index_tuple.h>

template<typename Func, typename Tuple, unsigned... I>  
  void caller_impl(Func func, Tuple&& t, redi::index_tuple<I...>)  
  {  
    func(std::get<I>(t)...);
  }

template<typename Func, typename... Args>  
  void caller(Func func, Args... args)  
  {  
    auto argtuple = std::make_tuple(args...);  
    do_stuff_with_tuple(argtuple);
    typedef redi::to_index_tuple<Args...> indices;
    caller_impl(func, argtuple, indices());
  }
```

My implementation of `index_tuple` is at https://gitlab.com/redistd/redistd/blob/master/include/redi/index_tuple.h
but it relies on template aliases so if your compiler doesn't support that you'd need to modify it to use C++03-style "template typedefs" and  replace the last two lines of `caller` with

```
    typedef typename redi::make_index_tuple<sizeof...(Args)>::type indices;
    caller_impl(func, argtuple, indices());
```

A similar utility was standardised as `std::index_sequence` in C++14 (see [index_seq.h](https://gitlab.com/redistd/redistd/blob/master/include/redi/index_seq.h) for a standalone C++11 implementation).

Comment: can you please explain the `type::template` syntax ?

Comment: @ubik https://womble.decadent.org.uk/c++/template-faq.html#disambiguation

Comment: @JonathanWakely Very nice. Maybe I'm missing an obvious trick, but is there any way to apply a `tuple` like this when the function in question is a constructor... or is that asking for a little bit too much magic? :D

Comment: Hmm, think I've gotten it working by having the `_impl` function equivalent templated on `T_ReturnedObject` and getting it to call that object's ctor with all the stuff unpacked. I guess that was the "obvious trick" I mentioned!

Comment: @underscore_d, yes, that's the obvious way to do it.