# Get the variadic arguments from template argument

Tags: c++, templates, variadic

I have two templates, one is passed to the other as an argument. I would like to be able to use the Args from the argument in the main template. Or if I have:

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
class Foo
{
    typedef T Type;
    static void foo(Args... args)
    {
    }
};

template <typename C>
class Bar
{
    void bar(Args... args)
    {
        // do something
        C::foo(args...);
    }
};
```

How I can make `Args` visible in the template `Bar`. Note that with `typedef T Type`, I can use `C::Type` in `Bar`. What is the syntax if possible for the variadic argument?

Comment: I've seen this. The answer has something to do with the indecies trick. http://stackoverflow.com/a/18993297/845092

Comment: because I want it to be

Comment: [one option](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/974cb2d15ff09079)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here a possible solution based on template template parameter:

```
template<typename T>
class Bar;

template <template<typename...> class C, typename... Args>
class Bar<C<Args...>> {
    void bar(Args... args) {
        // do something
        C<Args...>::foo(args...);
    }
};
```

You can use it as it follows:

```
Bar<Foo<int, double>> v;
```

You don't get the arguments `Args` directly from the `C` class. Instead, the idea is to exploit the fact that the `C` class is a variadic templated one for itself, thus getting `Args` from the parameter list of a template specialization of `Bar`.

Comment: this does not answer the question, but it is better option from what I was trying to do - I will mark it as solution

Comment: @gsf Well, actually this way you are *able to use the Args from the argument in the main template*. So, it also answers the question indeed. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You could have a typedef for a 'type list' that wraps `Args...`. Here's an example using `tuple` to perform the role of the type list:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <experimental/tuple>

template <typename T, typename... Args>
class Foo
{
public:
    using Type = T;

    using Arguments = std::tuple<Args...>;

    static void foo(Args... args)
    {
    }
};

template <typename C>
class Bar
{
public:
    void bar(typename C::Arguments &&args)
    {
        // do something
        std::experimental::apply(C::foo, args);
    }
};

int main() {
    Bar<Foo<int, double, float>> b;
    b.bar(std::make_tuple(2.0, 1.0f));
}
```

With a bit more meta-programming it should be possible to produce a `Bar::bar` function that takes arguments directly based on `C::Arguments`.