# How to declare "basic" type for argument of generic std::function

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to write a generic wrapper (for some script interpreter) for function/class method that would convert all call parameters from string to some arbitrary type T.
I'll try to cover topic in points:

- Script allows to map user function
- When interpreter tries to process user function - a callback routine is made
- Callback is intended to take array of objects that describe (one-by-one) arguments' values
- I already got (template) routines that converts string to arbitrary (basic) type T
- I would like to wrap user routine (provided externally as variadic std::function<> type) so that conversion from subsequent strings from callback's array to appropriate argument is done automatically

Example:

Prototype for callback routine is as follows:

```
int CallbackFn(Interp *interp, int argc, const char **argv)
```

I got (sample) user function:

```
int UserRoutine(const std::string &in_str, int x);
```

so std::function would look like:

```
std::function<int(const std::string&, int)>
```

Generic conversion routine has syntax:

```
template <typename T>
T conv(const char *str);
```

I have specializations that convert:

1. "const char*" to "std::string"
2. "const char*" to "int"

so that ideally conversion would look like:

```
std::string p0 = conv<std::string>(argv[0]);
int p1 = conv<int>(argv[1]);
```

It could be wrapped all into variadic templates, but std::function<...> arguments do not exactly match the types i'm preparing - e.g. it is very common to pass objects as const T&, while i need to create "pure" type of T.

Any ideas how to handle different means of passing arguments?

Answer (score 4):

The first problem is that you are reinventing the wheel, to be honest. The default conversion function is `operator>> (istream&, T&)`. Stuff each argument in a `std::stringstream`. And obviously, `operator<<` for the return type.

As you correctly note, you use variadic templates. But I wouldn't bother with generating `std::function<int(const std::string&, int)>` here. Instead, you always generate the common type `std::function<std::string(std::string)>`. Each packaged function contains the right argument conversion.

This gives us the declaration

```
template<typename RET, typename Args...>
std::function<std::string(std::string) (RET (*fptr)(Args...));
```

The body roughly has to look roughly like

```
std::tuple<Args...> args;
std::istringstream iss(fromScript);
iss>>args;
std::ostringstream oss;
oss << *fptr(args.get<0>, args.get<1>(), ...);
return oss.str();
```

For that tricky call to `*fptr`, see [C++11: I can go from multiple args to tuple, but can I go from tuple to multiple args?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10766112/c11-i-can-go-from-multiple-args-to-tuple-but-can-i-go-from-tuple-to-multiple?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

[edit]
I just noted one bit I missed: " arguments do not exactly match the types i'm preparing - e.g. it is very common to pass objects as `const T&`, while i need to create "pure" type of `T`.". I suspect you're looking for [`std::decay<Arg>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer :) !! Seems i need to get more familiar with C++11... and focus on class <-> string conversion.

Comment: Thanks :) That's another thing i wasn't aware of:)
Now i'm trying to wrap all the stuff into a class - i'd like to have "mapped function descriptors" that would hold std::function + name + pointer to interpreter etc.
I got it templated for <typename RET, typename ...ARGS> and have std::function with same RET/ARGS... what about pointer to member?
I know there is std::bind that can wrap std::function together with object, but can i somehow declare result of std::bind?
Or should i just declare another template with additional "typename OBJ" parameter that holds also pointer to the object?

Comment: @raku99: A pointer to member is a function with N+1 arguments, the +1 being a hidden `this` parameter. You can indeed use `std::bind` to reduce the arity of a function. The return type is unspecified, since it should not matter. You seem to have the `std::function` and the `std::bind` reversed. The object returned from `std::bind` usually goes into a `std::function`. But your talk about "std::function with the same RET/ARGS" makes me suspect that we are not talking about the same approach anyway. The whole point of `std::function` is type erasure, and you are not doing that.

Comment: Sorry for confusion - seems i need to learn a bit before attempting to use std::function and std::bind. Thanks for pointing it out :) !!