# Call a variadic template function with a tuple?

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I expand a tuple into variadic template function's arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687490/how-do-i-expand-a-tuple-into-variadic-template-functions-arguments)

Currently, I have function of the form :

```
template<typename Type, typename... List> 
void myFunction(Type& x, List&... list);
```

I also have a tuple :

```
std::tuple<int, unsigned int, unsigned long long int, int> myTuple;
```

Is it possible (and if yes, how ?) to pass `myTuple` to `myFunction` ?

Comment: The preferred technique is to use [a pack of indices](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7858971/726300).

Comment: You want specific answer for this very tuple: `std::tuple<int, unsigned int, unsigned long long int, int>` or general answer for any tuple. The general one is pointed by nosid.

Comment: Are you trying to pass the *contents* of the tuple to the function, or just the tuple itself?

Comment: @PiotrNycz : I want a general aswer for any tuple with arithmetic types. `myTuple` is just an example.
@Nicol Bolas : I want to pass the contents of the tuple (I would like to unpack the tuple)