# Constructor arguments from tuple

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, constructor, stdtuple

Suppose I have a template which is parametrized by a class type and a number of argument types. a set of arguments matching these types are stored in a tuple. How can one pass these to a constructor of the class type?

In almost C++11 code:

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
struct foo {
  tuple<Args...> args;
  T gen() { return T(get<0>(args), get<1>(args), ...); }
};
```

How can the `...` in the constructor call be filled without fixing the length?

I guess I could come up with some complicated mechanism of recursive template calls which does this, but I can't believe that I'm the first to want this, so I guess there will be ready-to-use solutions to this out there, perhaps even in the standard libraries.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7858817/unpacking-a-tuple-to-call-a-matching-function-pointer or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/687490/how-do-i-expand-a-tuple-into-variadic-template-functions-arguments

Answer (score 15, accepted):

C++17 has [`std::make_from_tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/make_from_tuple) for this:

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
struct foo
{
  std::tuple<Args...> args;
  T gen() { return std::make_from_tuple<T>(args); }
};
```

Answer (score 5):

You need some template meta-programming machinery to achieve that.

The easiest way to realize the argument dispatch is to exploit pack expansion on expressions which contain a packed **compile-time sequence of integers**. The template machinery is needed to build such a sequence (also see the remark at the end of this answer for more information on a proposal to standardize such a sequence).

Supposing to have a class (template) `index_range` that encapsulates a compile-time range of integers [M, N) and a class (template) `index_list` that encapsulates a compile-time list of integers, this is how you would use them:

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
struct foo
{
    tuple<Args...> args;

    // Allows deducing an index list argument pack
    template<size_t... Is>
    T gen(index_list<Is...> const&)
    {
        return T(get<Is>(args)...); // This is the core of the mechanism
    }

    T gen()
    {
        return gen(
            index_range<0, sizeof...(Args)>() // Builds an index list
            );
    }
};
```

And here is a possible implementation of `index_range` and `index_list`:

```
//===============================================================================
// META-FUNCTIONS FOR CREATING INDEX LISTS

// The structure that encapsulates index lists
template <size_t... Is>
struct index_list
{
};

// Collects internal details for generating index ranges [MIN, MAX)
namespace detail
{
    // Declare primary template for index range builder
    template <size_t MIN, size_t N, size_t... Is>
    struct range_builder;

    // Base step
    template <size_t MIN, size_t... Is>
    struct range_builder<MIN, MIN, Is...>
    {
        typedef index_list<Is...> type;
    };

    // Induction step
    template <size_t MIN, size_t N, size_t... Is>
    struct range_builder : public range_builder<MIN, N - 1, N - 1, Is...>
    {
    };
}

// Meta-function that returns a [MIN, MAX) index range
template<unsigned MIN, unsigned MAX>
using index_range = typename detail::range_builder<MIN, MAX>::type;
```

Also notice, that an [interesting proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3493.html) by [Jonathan Wakely](https://stackoverflow.com/users/981959/jonathan-wakely) exists to **standardize** an `int_seq` class template, which is something very similar to what I called `index_list` here.

Comment: I haven't tried this yet, but it looks to me like you have an off-by-one error there: you set `MAX` to `sizeof...(Args) - 1` even though that maximum is excluded from the list. Otherwise thanks for the great answer, since it very clearly explains the individual steps.

Comment: The forward declaration of the primary template is pointless and confusing. Just define the "Induction step" one first.

Answer (score 5):

Use `index_sequence` to unpack a `std::tuple` (or `std::pair`, `std::array`, or anything else supporting the tuple interface):

```
#include <utility>
#include <tuple>

template <typename Tuple, std::size_t... Inds>
SomeClass help_make_SomeClass(Tuple&& tuple, std::index_sequence<Inds...>)
{
    return SomeClass(std::get<Inds>(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple))...);
}

template <typename Tuple>
SomeClass make_SomeClass(Tuple&& tuple)
{
    return help_make_SomeClass(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple),
        std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value>());
}
```

`std::index_sequence` and `std::make_index_sequence` will be in C++1y.  If you can't find a header that defines them, you could use these:

```
template <std::size_t... Inds>
struct index_sequence {
    static constexpr std::size_t size()
    { return sizeof...(Inds); }
};

template <std::size_t N, std::size_t... Inds>
struct help_index_seq {
    typedef typename help_index_seq<N-1, N-1, Inds...>::type type;
};

template <std::size_t... Inds>
struct help_index_seq<0, Inds...> {
    typedef index_sequence<Inds...> type;
};

template <std::size_t N>
using make_index_sequence = typename help_index_seq<N>::type;
```

Live example, in C++11 mode: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ed91a67c8363061b

Answer (score 3):

C++14 will add standard support for `index_sequence`:

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
struct foo {
  tuple<Args...> args;
  T gen() { return gen_impl(std::index_sequence_for<Args...>()); }
private:
  template <size_t... Indices>
  T gen_impl(std::index_sequence<Indices...>) { return T(std::get<Indices>(args)...); }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a sequence of indexes from 0 through n-1:

```
template<size_t... indexes>
struct seq {};

template<size_t n, size_t... indexes>
struct make_seq: make_seq<n-1, n-1, indexes...> {};

template<size_t... indexes>
struct make_seq: make_seq<0, indexes...> {
  typedef seq<indexes...> type;
};
```

unpack them in parallel with your args, or as the index to `get<>` in your case.

The goal is something like:

```
template< typename T, typename Tuple, typename Indexes >
struct repack;

template< typename... Ts, size_t... indexes >
struct repack< tuple<Ts...>, seq<indexes...> > {
  T operator()( tuple<Ts...> const& args ) const {
    return T( get<indexes>(args)... );
  }
};
```

use `repack` in your `gen` like this:

```
T gen() {
  repack<T, tuple<Args...>, typename make_seq<sizeof...(Args)>::type> repacker;
  return repacker( args );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use the [indices trick](http://loungecpp.wikidot.com/tips-and-tricks%3aindices), which means a layer of indirection:

```
template <std::size_t... Is>
struct indices {};
template <std::size_t N, std::size_t... Is>
struct build_indices
  : build_indices<N-1, N-1, Is...> {};
template <std::size_t... Is>
struct build_indices<0, Is...> : indices<Is...> {};

template<typename T, typename... Args>
struct foo {
  tuple<Args...> args;
  T gen() { return gen(build_indices<sizeof...(Args)>{}); }
private:
  template<std::size_t... Is>
  T gen(indices<Is...>) { return T(get<Is>(args)...); }
};
```

Comment: Took me some time to figure out that the second version of `build_indices` is a specialization of the first, and not the other way round. Reading the more verbose answer by Andy Prowl first certainly did help.