# std::apply to constructor in a templated function

Tags: c++, templates, tuples

I am writing generic code, and I need to call the constructor of a generic template parameter `T` with a generic variadic tuple of arguments:

```
T& init_and_return(ArgsTuple& args)
{
    m_data = std::apply(&T::T, args); // here compiler complains
    return m_data;
}
```

In my main, `T` will be a type called `A`.
Compiler is saying "no member named `T` in `A`".

How can I refer to the constructor of `T` in a generic way?

Comment: You can't get a pointer to a constructor, whether the type is a template parameter or not.

Comment: @interjay any workaround to use std::apply with constructor?

Comment: Here is how to construct an object from args tuple https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14897527/constructor-arguments-from-tuple

Comment: @Renat no more readable way to achieve the same in C++17?

Comment: `std::apply([](auto&&... args2) { return T{std::forward<decltype(args2)>(args2)...}; }, args);` would be sufficient, but Yakk´s answer is even better.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The constructor is not a function or a method like other methods are -- it is special, and you cannot take its address.  Personally I think it should be possible, but it isn't.

The C++ standard has [make from tuple](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/make_from_tuple), which does what you want.

```
m_data = std::make_from_tuple<T>(args);
```

Comment: Could you please explain how constructor is not a function or method?

Comment: `[class.mem.special]` states that "*The default constructor, copy constructor, move constructor, copy assignment operator, move assignment operator, and destructor are **special member functions**."*. That kinda contradicts with what you said, doesn't it?

Comment: @Fureeish Sure, that is technically correct, which is the best kind of correct.