# argument packing in std::tuple<> and then applying

Tags: c++, c++11, lua, tuples, variadic-templates

I'm writing a binding engine for `lua`. It works by instantiating function tamplates, that gather arguments provided by `lua` into a `std::tuple` and then apply the `std::tuple` on a pointer to member function. Here's an example:

```
template <member_meta_info const* mmi, class C, class R, class ...A>
inline typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<void, R>::value, int>::type
member_stub(lua_State* L)
{
  assert(sizeof...(A) + 1 == lua_gettop(L));

  static std::tuple<A...> args;

  set_args<0, 2>(args, L);

  lua_getfield(L, -1, "__instance");
  assert(lua_islightuserdata(L, -1));

  typedef R (C::*ptr_to_member_type)(A...);

  apply_tuple(static_cast<C*>(lua_touserdata(L, -1)),
    *static_cast<ptr_to_member_type*>(mmi->ptr_to_member), args);

  lua_pushnil(L);

  return 1;
}
```

`mmi->ptr_to_member` is simply a `void*` pointer. The `set_args` trick was stolen from:
[iterate over tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198260/iterate-over-tuple):

```
template<std::size_t I = 0, std::size_t O = 1, typename... Tp>
inline typename std::enable_if<I == sizeof...(Tp)>::type
set_args(std::tuple<Tp...>&, lua_State*)
{
}

template<std::size_t I = 0, std::size_t O = 1, typename... Tp>
inline typename std::enable_if<I != sizeof...(Tp)>::type
set_args(std::tuple<Tp...>& t, lua_State* L)
{
  set_arg(L, I + O, std::get<I>(t));

  set_args<I + 1, O, Tp...>(t, I);
}
```

`set_arg()` are a set of overloaded functions for various primitive types (such as `int`, `double`, ...) that set the reference, returned from `std::get<>`, for example:

```
inline void set_arg(lua_State* L, std::size_t i, double& value)
{
  assert(lua_isnumber(L, i));
  value = lua_tonumber(L, i);
}
```

The `apply` trick was adapted from:
[How do I expand a tuple into variadic template function's arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687490/how-do-i-expand-a-tuple-into-variadic-template-functions-arguments)

```
#ifndef APPLYTUPLE_HPP
# define APPLYTUPLE_HPP

template<size_t N>
struct Apply {
template<typename F, typename T, typename... A>
    static inline auto apply(F&& f, T && t, A &&... a)
      -> decltype(Apply<N-1>::apply(::std::forward<F>(f), ::std::forward<T>(t),
        ::std::get<N-1>(::std::forward<T>(t)), ::std::forward<A>(a)...
      ))
    {
      return Apply<N-1>::apply(::std::forward<F>(f), ::std::forward<T>(t),
        ::std::get<N-1>(::std::forward<T>(t)), ::std::forward<A>(a)...
      );
    }

    template<typename C, typename F, typename T, typename... A>
    static inline auto apply(C && c, F && f, T && t, A &&... a)
      -> decltype(Apply<N-1>::apply(::std::forward<C>(c),
        ::std::forward<F>(f), ::std::forward<T>(t),
        ::std::get<N-1>(::std::forward<T>(t)), ::std::forward<A>(a)...
      ))
    {
      return Apply<N-1>::apply(::std::forward<C>(c), ::std::forward<F>(f),
        ::std::forward<T>(t), ::std::get<N-1>(::std::forward<T>(t)),
        ::std::forward<A>(a)...
      );
    }

    template<typename C, typename T, typename... A>
    static inline C* apply(T && t, A &&... a)
    {
      return Apply<N-1>::template apply<C>(::std::forward<T>(t),
        ::std::get<N-1>(::std::forward<T>(t)), ::std::forward<A>(a)...
      );
    }
};

template<>
struct Apply<0> {
  template<typename F, typename T, typename... A>
  static inline auto apply(F && f, T &&, A &&... a)
    ->decltype((*::std::forward<F>(f))(::std::forward<A>(a)...))
  {
    return (*::std::forward<F>(f))(::std::forward<A>(a)...);
  }

  template<typename C, typename F, typename T, typename... A>
  static inline auto apply(C && c, F && f, T &&, A &&... a)
    ->decltype((::std::forward<C>(c)->*::std::forward<F>(f))(::std::forward<A>(a)...))
  {
    return (::std::forward<C>(c)->*::std::forward<F>(f))(::std::forward<A>(a)...);
  }

  template<typename C, typename T, typename... A>
  static inline C* apply(T &&, A &&... a)
  {
    return new C(::std::forward<A>(a)...);
  }
};

template<typename F, typename T>
inline auto apply_tuple(F && f, T && t)
  ->decltype(Apply< ::std::tuple_size<
    typename ::std::decay<T>::type
  >::value>::apply(::std::forward<F>(f), ::std::forward<T>(t)))
{
  return Apply< ::std::tuple_size<
    typename ::std::decay<T>::type
  >::value>::apply(::std::forward<F>(f), ::std::forward<T>(t));
}

template<typename C, typename F, typename T>
inline auto apply_tuple(C && c, F && f, T && t)
  ->decltype(Apply< ::std::tuple_size<
    typename ::std::decay<T>::type
  >::value>::apply(::std::forward<C>(c), ::std::forward<F>(f), ::std::forward<T>(t)))
{
  return Apply< ::std::tuple_size<
    typename ::std::decay<T>::type
  >::value>::apply(::std::forward<C>(c), ::std::forward<F>(f), ::std::forward<T>(t));
}

template<typename C, typename T>
inline C* apply_tuple(T && t)
{
  return Apply< ::std::tuple_size<
    typename ::std::decay<T>::type
  >::value>::template apply<C>(::std::forward<T>(t));
}

#endif // APPLYTUPLE_HPP
```

it applies the tuple `args` on the pointed to member function. Now for my question. I'm disturbed that for each function call I copy all the arguments `lua` provides into a `std::tuple` and then apply it the on the pointer to member. Certainly the copying entails some overhead. Is it possible to omit the copying somehow? Does there exist a container (standard or otherwise) that is more suitable for the copying of arguments than `std::tuple` is (i.e. is less fat, more trimmed).

Comment: "Certainly the copying entails some overhead." -- Did you profile this? Is it actually a problem? Also, "`mmi->ptr_to_member` is simply a `void*` pointer" -- you're entering undefined behaviour land, a member function pointer can not necessarily be represented by a normal data pointer. Same goes for a normal function pointer. What you need is a dummy class and `reinterpret_cast` the member functions like `reinterpret_cast<void (Dummy::*)()>(&SomeClass::some_member)` -- this is guaranteed to round-trip if you cast it back to the correct type.

Comment: I cast it to a pointer to member pointer and dereference *static_cast<ptr_to_member_type*>(mmi->ptr_to_member). Is that undefined? There's double indirection. Otherwise I viewed the code under a debugger and don't like it too much.

Comment: What is undefined behaviour is casting a member pointer to `void*` in the first place.

Comment: But I don't, I do this: `*static_cast<decltype(ptr_to_member)*>(mmi.ptr_to_member) = ptr_to_member;`. The `void*` pointer points to:`new char[sizeof(ptr_to_member)];`

Comment: I see, nevermind then. :) What still stands is - did you profile that this is actually a problem? Also, I'd hazard the guess that you can't do much against the copying, unless you get references back from the `lua_toXXX` functions.

Comment: @Xeo The problem is, that despite `-O3 -finline-functions`, I see a lot of functions that are not inlined. I also see the copying taking place. This is not a problem, since I am writing this as an exercise and scripting languages are slow as it is. I'm trying to learn something new.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think using a `std::tuple` should be fine, but you might want to try to drop the `static` and construct it in *one step* only (no recursion). It could improve the generated code, but I'll leave it for you to measure and/or analyze it.

```
#include <cstddef>

// we need a compile-time helper to generate indices
template< std::size_t... Ns >
struct indices
{
  typedef indices< Ns..., sizeof...( Ns ) > next;
};

template< std::size_t N >
struct make_indices
{
  typedef typename make_indices< N - 1 >::type::next type;
};

template<>
struct make_indices< 0 >
{
  typedef indices<> type;
};

// instead of set_arg, provide get_arg:
template< typename T >
T get_arg( lua_State* L, std::size_t N )
{
  static_assert( sizeof( T ) == 0, "T not specialized" );
}

// one specialization per type
template<>
inline double get_arg< double >( lua_State* L, std::size_t i )
{
  assert(lua_isnumber(L, i));
  return lua_tonumber(L, i);
}

// etc.

// now that we have the helpers, we use it to create an impl
// and forward the original call to it.
template< typename... Args, std::size_t... Ns >
void member_stub_impl( lua_State* L, const indices< Ns... >& )
{
  // and here's the non-recursive direct initialization
  // version of a std::tuple< Args... >, adjust the offset (1) as needed
  const std::tuple< Args... > args( get_arg< Args >( L, Ns + 1 )... );

  // now use it...

}

// the forwarder providing the indices to the impl
template< typename... Args >
void member_stub( lua_State* L )
{
  typedef typename make_indices< sizeof...( Args ) >::type Indices;
  return member_stub_impl< Args... >( L, Indices() );
}
```

**EDIT:** Now that we've seen `apply_tuple`, I think you can actually get rid of both `apply_tuple` and the `std::tuple` itself. My above helpers in place, it boils down to:

```
template <member_meta_info const* mmi, class C, class R, class ...A, std::size_t ...Ns>
inline typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<void, R>::value, int>::type
member_stub_impl(lua_State* L, const indices<Ns...>& )
{
  assert(sizeof...(A) + 1 == lua_gettop(L));

  lua_getfield(L, -1, "__instance");
  assert(lua_islightuserdata(L, -1));

  typedef R (C::*ptr_to_member_type)(A...);
  C* obj = static_cast<C*>(lua_touserdata(L, -1));
  auto func = *static_cast<ptr_to_member_type*>(mmi->ptr_to_member);

  // look ma, no std::tuple! ;)
  obj->*func( get_arg< A >( L, Ns + 1 )... );

  lua_pushnil(L);

  return 1;
}
```

I couldn't test it so there might be some typo's in there, but I hope they are easy to fix. In case you need help, let me know.

Comment: This really helped quite a bit. The recursion trick is badly optimized apparently.

Comment: I was just thinking about it again and I have a feeling: I think `apply_tuple` could probably be integrated into `member_stub_impl`. Could you edit your question and add the implementation of `apply_tuple`, please?

Comment: Some nice metal gymnastics going on in there. Works better now and executable is smaller.

Comment: Good to see it works for you. In general, I have the impression that too many people still think that, when working with variadic templates, recursion is a natural choice and they don't look for alternatives. From my experience, however, you can often avoid it which leads to much better code that is shorter (both source- and binary-wise), more efficient, readable and thus more maintainable.