# C++ unit testing framework with type and value parametrisation

Tags: c++, unit-testing

I am looking for a unit testing framework that allows passing type and value parameters to test function at the same time.

Example: let's say I have a few template sorting functions:

```
template<class ITERATOR, class COMPARATOR = std::less<typename std::iterator_traits<ITERATOR>::value_type>>
void selectionSort(const ITERATOR first,const ITERATOR last, const COMPARATOR comparator = COMPARATOR ()){ ... };

template<class ITERATOR, class COMPARATOR = std::less<typename std::iterator_traits<ITERATOR>::value_type>>
void insertionSort(const ITERATOR first,const ITERATOR last, const COMPARATOR comparator = COMPARATOR ()) { ... }
```

and I want to test these functions with different input types as:

```
template<class T>
vector<T> makeRandomVector(int size){ ... }

vector<int> intVec = makeRandomVector<int>(10);  //10 is vector size
someSort(intVec.begin(),intVec.end())
vector<MyCustomStruct> structVec = makeRandomVector<MyCustomStruct>(10);  
someSort(structVec.begin(),structVec.end())
```

and with different size arguments for `makeRandomVector` to test these function if vector size is 0,1,10 etc.

So I am looking for C++ unit testing framework that allows creating test that would accept type (int,MyCustomStruct) and value parameters (0,1,10) at the same time and perform the test for each element of the cartesian product of Types x Values.

Comment: Here's a starting place. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unit_testing_frameworks and it would be great if you would provide more details about your development environment.

Comment: I think Catch2 is what you're looking for : https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/master/docs/test-cases-and-sections.md#type-parametrised-test-cases

Comment: It took me a lot of time to understand that Google test can't do what I need. One needs a good knowledge of a particular testing framework to answer my question and it is reason I ask it here

Comment: From what I read Catch2 allows just type not type and value parametrization. Tough I can be wrong

Comment: About development environment: I am willing to setup anything that is available for free for Linux and Windows. Currently I am using Qt creator on Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible way is the typed test of GoogleTest as follows.
Please note that this is the solution for C++14 and over, and integer parameters just like your example `{0, 1, 10}`.

---

**Approach**

Let us define the following struct `Case`:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t I>
struct Case
{
    using type = T;
    static constexpr std::size_t size = I;
};
```

The basic idea of testing all combinations of types and sizes are using this struct to specify test types like this:

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

template <typename T>
class TypedTest : public ::testing::Test {};

using TestTypes = ::testing::Types<Case<int, 0>, Case<int, 1>, Case<int, 10>, Case<MyCustomStruct, 0>, ...>;

TYPED_TEST_CASE(TypedTest, TestTypes);

TYPED_TEST(TypedTest, sort) 
{
    auto vec = makeRandomVector<TypeParam::type>(TypeParam::size);
    ...
}
```

---

**Combinatorics**

Now our problem is how can we simply construct the all combinations of types and sizes.
I just answered the [**almost same question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55005063/create-a-type-list-combination-of-types-in-c/55008771#55008771) with this problem yesterday.
In the current case, all possible pairs of `{int, MyCustomStruct}` and `{0, 1, 10}` are labeled by one dimensional integers 0,1,...,5 like this (and max66's approach would be also possible):

```
0 -> (0/3, 0%3) = (0,0) -> std::tuple<int,  0>
1 -> (1/3, 1%3) = (0,1) -> std::tuple<int,  1>
2 -> (2/3, 2%3) = (0,2) -> std::tuple<int, 10>
3 -> (3/3, 3%3) = (1,0) -> std::tuple<MyCustomStruct,  0>
4 -> (4/3, 4%3) = (1,1) -> std::tuple<MyCustomStruct,  1>
5 -> (5/3, 5%3) = (1,2) -> std::tuple<MyCustomStruct, 10>
```

where `3` is the size of `{0, 1, 10}`.
It is simple and straightforward to write the function which makes all possible combinations with this algorithm as follows.
For instance, `Combinations<std::tuple<int, MyCustomStruct>, 0, 1, 10>` is equal to the type of `std::tuple<Case<int,0>, Case<int,1>, Case<int,10>, Case<MyCustomStruct,0>, ...>`:

```
template<typename TupleType, typename TupleIdx, std::size_t I>
struct make_case
{
    static constexpr std::size_t N = std::tuple_size<TupleIdx>::value;

    using type = Case<typename std::tuple_element<I/N, TupleType>::type,
                               std::tuple_element<I%N, TupleIdx >::type::value>;
};

template <typename T1, typename T2, typename Is>
struct make_combinations;

template <typename TupleType, typename TupleIdx, std::size_t... Is>
struct make_combinations<TupleType, TupleIdx, std::index_sequence<Is...>>
{
    using tuples = std::tuple<typename make_case<TupleType, TupleIdx, Is>::type...>;
};

template<typename TupleTypes, std::size_t ...Is>
using Combinations = typename make_combinations
                       <TupleTypes,
                        std::tuple<std::integral_constant<std::size_t, Is>...>,
                        std::make_index_sequence<(std::tuple_size<TupleTypes>::value)*(sizeof...(Is))>>
                     ::tuples;
```

---

**Testing**

Applying answers of this [**post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15418841/how-do-i-strip-a-tuple-back-into-a-variadic-template-list-of-types), we can stripe this tuple `Combinations<...>` into a list of types and here I apply Nawaz's simple one.
Then all tests can be done as follows:

```
template<typename T>
struct Test;

template<typename ...T>
struct Test<std::tuple<T...>>
{
    using Types = ::testing::Types<T...>;
};

template <typename T>
class TypedTest : public ::testing::Test {};

using TestTypes = Test<Combinations<std::tuple<int, MyCustomStruct>, 0, 1, 10>>::Types;

TYPED_TEST_CASE(TypedTest, TestTypes);

TYPED_TEST(TypedTest, sort) 
{
    auto vec = makeRandomVector<TypeParam::type>(TypeParam::size);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Wow! It is amazing how you managed to generate all type/value combinations using templates. I am learning template programming and your code looks very educative. Thanks a lot for showing this cool approach.

Comment: @xevepisis many thx :). And I have checked that this approach well works in my Windows environment.