# GTest - parametrized tests for different types

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

I would like to mix parametrized test with typed test. Here is my attempt:

```
struct X {};

struct Y {};

template <typename T>
struct MyTestFixture: public ::testing::Test
{
    T t;
};

template <typename T, typename Param>
struct MyTestFixtureWithParam : public MyTestFixture<T>, 
                                public ::testing::WithParamInterface<Param>
{
};

using MyTestFixtureWithXandString = MyTestFixtureWithParam<X, std::string>;

TEST_P(MyTestFixtureWithXandString, Test1)
{
}

INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P(Name, MyTestFixtureWithXandString, 
                        ::testing::Values("a", "b"));

using MyTestFixtureWithYandString = MyTestFixtureWithParam<Y, std::string>;

TEST_P(MyTestFixtureWithYandString, Test1)
{

}

INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P(Name, MyTestFixtureWithYandString, 
                        ::testing::Values("a", "b"));
```

Does Gtest contain some macro which mixes TYPED_TEST and TEST_P or the above code is the only way to achieve my goal ?

Comment: GoogleTest offers that functionality, but I've never used it, so I can't provide a proper answer. [See the docs](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/advanced.md#type-parameterized-tests) (under "Type-Parameterized Tests" in case the link doesn't scroll down)

Comment: Why don’t you just inherit from `WithParamInterface<std::string>` here?

Answer (score 2):

There might be no such a macro as far as I know but there is a possible way to do it as follows.

---

**Basic Idea**

Let us define the following structs `a`, `b` and `Case`.
Here `a::str` and `b::str` are the parameters which we want to test:

```
// types
struct X {};
struct Y {};

// "parameters"
struct a { static constexpr char str[] = "a"; };
struct b { static constexpr char str[] = "b"; };

template<class T, class P>
struct Case
{
    using type = T;

    static std::string GetParam()
    {
        return P::str;
    }
};
```

The basic idea of testing all combinations of your types `X` and `Y` and string parameters within a single test logic is using this struct `Case` to specify the test type and parameter as follows:

```
using TestTypes = ::testing::Types<Case<X, a>, Case<X, b>, Case<Y, a>, Case<Y, b>>;

template <class T>
class MyTestFixture: public ::testing::Test {};

TYPED_TEST_CASE(MyTestFixture, TestTypes);

TYPED_TEST(MyTestFixture, Test12) 
{
    // X or Y
    TypeParam::type t;

    // "a" or "b"
    const std::string str = TypeParam::GetParam();
}
```

---

**Improvement**

Now our problem is how we can improve the construction of the all combinations of types and string parameters.
I have answered to the [**almost same problem**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55005063/create-a-type-list-combination-of-types-in-c/55008771#55008771).
In the current case, all possible pairs of `{X, Y}` and `{a, b}` are labeled by one dimensional integers `0,1,2,3` like this:

```
0 -> (0/2, 0%2) = (0,0) -> Case<X, a>
1 -> (1/2, 1%2) = (0,1) -> Case<X, b>
2 -> (2/2, 2%2) = (1,0) -> Case<Y, a>
3 -> (3/2, 3%2) = (1,1) -> Case<Y, b>
```

where `2` is the size of `{a, b}`.
It is straightforward to write the function which makes all possible combinations with this algorithm as follows.
For instance, `Combinations_t<std::tuple<X, Y>, a, b>` is equal to the type of `std::tuple<Case<X,a>, Case<X,b>, Case<Y,a>, Case<Y,b>>`:

[**Live DEMO**](https://godbolt.org/z/JcL0y2)

```
template<class TupleType, class TupleParam, std::size_t I>
struct make_case
{
    static constexpr std::size_t N = std::tuple_size<TupleParam>::value;

    using type = Case<typename std::tuple_element<I / N, TupleType >::type,
                      typename std::tuple_element<I % N, TupleParam>::type>;
};

template <class T1, class T2, class Is>
struct make_combinations;

template <class TupleType, class TupleParam, std::size_t... Is>
struct make_combinations<TupleType, TupleParam, std::index_sequence<Is...>>
{
    using tuples = std::tuple<typename make_case<TupleType, TupleParam, Is>::type...>;
};

template<class TupleTypes, class... Params>
using Combinations_t = typename make_combinations
                       <TupleTypes,
                        std::tuple<Params...>,
                        std::make_index_sequence<(std::tuple_size<TupleTypes>::value)*(sizeof...(Params))>>
                     ::tuples;
```

Applying answers of this [**post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15418841/how-do-i-strip-a-tuple-back-into-a-variadic-template-list-of-types), we can stripe this tuple `Combinations_t<...>` into a list of types and here I apply Nawaz's simple one.
Then, finally, all tests can be done as follows:

```
template <class T>
class MyTestFixture : public ::testing::Test {};

template<class T>
struct Test;

template<class ...T>
struct Test<std::tuple<T...>>
{
    using Types = ::testing::Types<T...>;
};

using TestTypes = Test<Combinations_t<std::tuple<X, Y>, a, b>>::Types;

TYPED_TEST_CASE(MyTestFixture, TestTypes);

TYPED_TEST(MyTestFixture, Test12)
{
    // X or Y
    TypeParam::type t;

    // "a" or "b"
    const std::string str = TypeParam::GetParam();
}
```