# Is there any way to strip a tuple of pairs to variadic template types or instantiat something with variadic types?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a `tuple` of `pair`s in which each pair has a fixed type and a variant type. What I want is a list of the variant types or defining an object (which definitely constructs with a variadic template pack) with these types.

According to [How do I strip a `tuple<>` back into a variadic template list of types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15418841/how-do-i-strip-a-tuple-back-into-a-variadic-template-list-of-types), it is possible to instantiate something with constituent types of the `tuple`. But in this case, I don't know whether it is even possible and if possible, how to do it.

Imagine I have something like this:

```
struct MyFixedType
{ /* ... */ };


using Tuple = std::tuple<
    std::pair<MyFixedType, int>,
    std::pair<MyFixedType, double>,
    std::pair<MyFixedType, std::string>
>;
```

And I have this class:

```
template <typename... Ts>
class MyClass
{
};
```

What I want is to declare an object of `MyClass` with `<int, double, std::string>`

Note: Although this case can be handled using a pre-processor or some macros, I'm not allowed to use macros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using function template argument deduction for brevity:

```
template <class Fixed, class... Variant>
MyClass<Variant...> MyClassFromPairTuple_impl(std::tuple<std::pair<Fixed, Variant>...> &&);

template <class Tuple>
using MyClassFromPairTuple = decltype(MyClassFromPairTuple_impl(std::declval<Tuple>()));
```

Usage:

```
using Tuple = std::tuple<std::pair<MyFixedType, int>, std::pair<MyFixedType, double>, std::pair<MyFixedType, std::string>>;

MyClassFromPairTuple<Tuple> instance; // MyClass<int, double, std::string>
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/efDEYhPJ7lQBFlFa)