# c++11: Calling a variadic function with the elements of a vector

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

There are plenty of questions about how to call a variadic function with the elements of a  tuple.
e.g:
[How do I expand a tuple into variadic template function's arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687490/how-do-i-expand-a-tuple-into-variadic-template-functions-arguments)
My problem is a bit different:

I have a family of functions:

```
void f(int arg1);
void f(int arg1, int arg2);
...
```

I'd like a template:

```
template<size_t Arity>
void call(std::vector<int> args) {
   ???
}
```

That calls the appropriate `f` with `args[0], args[1]...`

Comment: Is there an upper limit for the number of args?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley that'd be `Arity`, I suppose.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: The same trick that solves this for a tuple, also solves it for vector (just replace `std::get<I>(t)...` with `v[I]...`)

Comment: @jrok: that can easily be tested. What I do know it the arity of the function I wish to call.
@Captaion Obvlious: I have db bindings which give me a family of `bind` calls. I know (statically) which one I wish to call and have all the arguments in a `vector`.

Comment: @R. Martinho Fernandes: do you have a working example? I tried to adapt the tuple examples but failed.

Comment: @TillVaroquaux Including your failed attempts is often a good idea.  Odds are you just made a trivial mistake: it is nearly identical to the `tuple` case.  Maybe replace a `sizeof...(Ts)` with a `Arity`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a working example:

```
#include <vector>

// indices machinery

template< std::size_t... Ns >
struct indices {
    typedef indices< Ns..., sizeof...( Ns ) > next;
};

template< std::size_t N >
struct make_indices {
    typedef typename make_indices< N - 1 >::type::next type;
};

template<>
struct make_indices< 0 > {
    typedef indices<> type;
};

void f(int) {}
void f(int, int) {}

// helper function because we need a way
// to deduce indices pack

template<size_t... Is>
void call_helper(const std::vector<int>& args, indices<Is...>)
{
    f( args[Is]... ); // expand the indices pack
}

template<std::size_t Arity>
void call(const std::vector<int>& args)
{
    if (args.size() < Arity) throw 42;
    call_helper(args, typename make_indices<Arity>::type());
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v(2);
    call<2>(v);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

[Working example:](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=0b27340a16e6e881fd6c75aefeb7a3db-c3b76f6a9fe4d2157fe78258faf829d5)

```
#include <cassert>
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template <size_t... I>
struct index_sequence {};

template <size_t N, size_t... I>
struct make_index_sequence : public make_index_sequence<N - 1, N - 1, I...> {};

template <size_t... I>
struct make_index_sequence<0, I...> : public index_sequence<I...> {};

int f(int a, int b) {
  return a + b;
}
void f(int a, int b, int c) {
  cout << "args = (" << a << ", " << b << ", " << c << ")\n";
}

template <typename T, size_t... I>
auto call_(const vector<T>& vec, index_sequence<I...>)
  -> decltype(f(vec[I]...)) {
  return f(vec[I]...);
}

template <size_t Arity, typename T>
auto call(const vector<T>& vec)
  -> decltype(call_(vec, make_index_sequence<Arity>())) {
  assert(vec.size() >= Arity);
  return call_(vec, make_index_sequence<Arity>());
}

int main() {
  vector<int> values = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
  call<3>(values);
  cout << "call<2>(values) = " << call<2>(values) << endl;
}
```