# Call variadic function in C++ with a vector of arguments

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-functions

Suppose I have a variadic function like this:

```
template <typename... A>
void func(A... args)
{
    //Do stuff
}
```

And I have also a vector like this:

```
enum Type{
    DOUBLE,
    STRING
};
std::vector<std::pair<std::string, Type>> varg;
```

So I want to iterate over the elements of the map and call the templated function with the specified types, like: `varg = {{"a", Type::STRING}, {"1.2", Type::DOUBLE}};`
should call `func("a", 1.2)`

Any hints on how to do that?

Comment: `std::map` seems like the wrong data structure to use for this. Seems like you would be better using `std::vector<std::pair<std::string, Type>>` or `std::vector<TaggedString>` where you write `TaggedString`.

Comment: That will work as well, I'll modify the question

Comment: Are you getting these strings from user input or is this a poor-man's `boost::variant`?

Comment: I'm getting them from user input.

Comment: You need more than just a variadic template for this as you don't know the types until runtime. Something version of the visitor pattern might work for you, but it really depends on what `func` is doing.

Comment: `func` is just adding its arguments to other structure.

Comment: May be it's solution [c++11: Calling a variadic function with the elements of a vector](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17974752/1823963)

Comment: @malchemist That won't work because the types need to be known at compile-time.

Comment: Use `std::tuple` for that kind of thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the lowest level (C-like), the [application binary interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) follows some  [calling conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention), notably how arguments are transmitted to a function, and it usually depends on the type of the argument (often, pointers go in some processor registers and floating point numbers go in some other kind of registers).

If you want to call a function of unknown signature (i.e. you know its signature and the actual arguments and their number only at *runtime*, not at compile time) you need some ABI specific tricks, and probably some machine specific code. You might consider using the [libffi](https://sourceware.org/libffi/) which provides

> a portable, high level programming interface to various calling conventions

BTW, you could consider packing or boxing your values in some "universal" container à la [boost::any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/any.html) or [QVariant](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html) or your own [tagged unions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union), or perhaps [boost::variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/variant.html)

Perhaps you might want to embed some interpreter in your application, e.g. [GNU guile](http://www.gnu.org/software/guile/) or [Lua](http://lua.org).

Noticve that for C or C++, *functions and function pointers have some **compile-time** known signature* which matters a lot. Calling something with the wrong signature (that is a function whose signature is not the one the compiler expects) is [**undefined behavior**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: I feel like there's a better solution to the problem then ABI hacks, OP is just asking the wrong question.

Comment: I can know in runtime, how the function is gonna be called (and the signature doesn't change from now and on), I don't know if that helps as well

Comment: @Fynn The thing is, if you want to use templates, every single template parameter has to be known at compile-time.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up compile-time and runtime features here. (Hint: It won't work)
As a thought-experiment:

Suppose you have a `std::vector<>` of some kind, that is filled with some data, say with `N` entries. Note that this `N` is a priori **only** known at runtime! 
Now you want to unpack these `N` data segments into a variadic template, something that **has to** be done compile-time! Templates are compile-time features!

This cannot work. You can in principle do something similar if you use compile-time containers (see `boost::mpl`). But these require, that you know (or can calculate) everything at compile-time.
Also you may want to look at `boost::fusion` which sort of tries to bridge this gap. Though you should always note that it cannot! Templates are still compile-time only.