# Threaded Building Blocks (TBB) enqueue task with lambda

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, lambda, tbb

The TBB documentation gives [this example](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/tbb_sa/help/tbb_userguide/Lambda_Expressions.htm#tutorial_Lambda_Expressions) of using lambda expressions with parallel_for, but doesn't provide an example of using lambda expressions with `tbb::task::enqueue`.

I am looking for a simple example of `tbb::task::enqueue` with a lambda expression.

Comment: Did you try to adapt it to `task::enqueue`? What did go wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure how to inherit from ```tbb::task``` inside the lambda expression.

Comment: Note that I have never used lambdas. I commented that because the more info you provide, the higher the chances are for someone to answer your question ASAP.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Low-level tasks in TBB do not directly support lambda expressions. But with some extra coding you might create syntax-sugar helpers to do what you want.

You'd need to create a task class that calls a given functor:

```
template<typename F>
class lambda_task : public tbb::task {
    F my_func;
    /*override*/ tbb::task* execute() {
        my_func();
        return NULL;
    }
public:
    lambda_task( const F& f ) : my_func(f) {}
};
```

And then, you'd need to create a function template that takes a functor/lambda, wraps it into `lambda_task`, and enqueues:

```
template<typename F>
void tbb_enqueue_lambda( const F& f ) {
    tbb::task::enqueue( *new( tbb::task::allocate_root() ) lambda_task<F>(f) );
}
```

And then you might use this function with lambda expressions:

```
tbb_enqueue_lambda( []{ /* code here */ } );
```

The official TBB API classes that support lambda expressions, such as `task_group` and `task_arena`, use very similar code internally.

---

Update: to pass a function pointer and arguments to call it with, the above approach can be extended in some ways:

- In C++03, you'd need to add separate class templates for a task with one argument, two arguments, etc., and corresponding overloads of `tbb_enqueue_lambda` function
- In C++11, you could use variadic templates, storing the actual arguments in an `std::tuple` inside `lambda_task`, and 'unpacking' those for the function call. Unpacking is not trivial, but there are a few SO topics covering that already: ["unpacking" a tuple to call a matching function pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7858817/unpacking-a-tuple-to-call-a-matching-function-pointer), [How do I expand a tuple into variadic template function's arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687490/how-do-i-expand-a-tuple-into-variadic-template-functions-arguments), and other.

Comment: Improvement suggestions: if lambda returns non-void, use its return value to produce the `tbb::task*` to allow chaining.  Maybe split the creation of the `lambda_task` from the `enqueue`?  Maybe not.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful answer! How could you modify this to enqueue a pointer to a function that has arguments directly? This works: ```tbb_enqueue_lambda([=]{doTask(arg);});```, as well as ```tbb_enqueue_lambda(&doTask);```, but how could you pass the arguments without the lambda expression?

Comment: I have update the answer to cover passing arguments.

Comment: Why not to add this to TBB? `task::enqueue()` misses any high-level API