# Generically call member function on each element of a tuple

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-meta-programming, stdtuple

#### Step one: expand a tuple and pass elements to a function:

I have a function which takes N parameters

```
void func(int, double, char);
```

and a tuple with the matching types

```
std::tuple<int, double, char> tuple;
```

[As per this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687490/how-do-i-expand-a-tuple-into-variadic-template-functions-arguments), I am able to expand the tuple and call the function.

#### Step two: expand a tuple and pass result of calling a member function on each of the elements to a function:

Taking it a step further, my tuple contains multiple instances of a class template:

```
template<typename T>
struct Foo;

std::tuple<Foo<int>, Foo<double>, Foo<char>>
```

`Foo` has a member function, `Foo<T>::get()` which returns a value of type `T`.

[As per this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7858971/955273), 
I have below working code which expands the tuple and calls `element.get()` on each element, ultimately passing the result to `func`.

The unfortunate thing is that I've **hard-coded** the call to `element.get()`.

#### Step three: make the specification of which member function to call on each of the tuple elements generic:

***(This is what I'm looking for help to do)***

Is it possible to make this generic? That is, to pass *which* member function to call to `apply`, and therefore have it as a generic utility?

I thought perhaps I could use [`std::mem_fn`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn) to wrap a function (`std::mem_fn(&Foo::get)`) and pass the resulting object to `apply`, but that don't work because `Foo` is a class template:

> `error: ‘template<class T> struct Foo’ used without template parameters`

Is there any way to make this generic?

### Working example below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

template<size_t...>
struct Seq
{ };

template<size_t N, size_t... Sq>
struct GenSeq : GenSeq<N - 1, N - 1, Sq...>
{ };

template<size_t... Sq>
struct GenSeq<0, Sq...>
{
    using type = Seq<Sq...>;
};

/////////////////////////////////////

struct Invoker
{
    template<typename Func, typename Tuple, size_t... Sq>
    static auto invoke(Func func, const Tuple& tuple, Seq<Sq...>)
        -> decltype(func(std::get<Sq>(tuple).get()...))
    {
        // calls the .get() member on each object in the tuple
        // I would like to make this generic
        return func(std::get<Sq>(tuple).get()...);
    }

    template<typename Func, typename... Args>
    static auto apply(Func func, const std::tuple<Args...>& args)
        -> decltype(invoke(func, args, typename GenSeq<sizeof...(Args)>::type()))
    {
        return invoke(func, args, typename GenSeq<sizeof...(Args)>::type());
    }
};

template<typename Func, typename Tuple>
inline auto apply(Func func, const Tuple& tuple)
    -> decltype(Invoker::apply(func, tuple))
{
    return Invoker::apply(func, tuple);
}

///////////////////////////////////////

template<typename T>
struct Foo
{
    T i;
    auto get() const -> decltype(i) { return i; }
};

template<typename... Ts>
struct Bar
{
    Bar(Ts... ts) : tuple(std::make_tuple(Foo<Ts> { ts }...)) {}
    std::tuple<Foo<Ts>...> tuple;
};

void func(int i, double d, char c)
{
    std::cout << i << ", " << d << ", " << c << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    Bar<int, double, char> bar { 4, 1.23, 'a' };
    apply(func, bar.tuple);
}
```

Comment: I think `apply` is a red herring. What you really want to do is more like a functional map across the tuple or a for each. This implementation of [`tuple_for_each`](https://github.com/jaredhoberock/tuple_utility/blob/master/tuple_utility.hpp#L629) might help.

Comment: Instead of `mem_fn`, `[](auto&& obj) -> decltype(auto) { return std::forward<decltype(obj)>(obj).get(); }`, or an equivalent C++11 functor.

Comment: `struct call_get { template<class T> auto operator()(T&& obj) const -> decltype(std::forward<T>(obj).get()) { return std::forward<T>(obj).get(); } };`

Comment: Thanks - this is exactly what I needed - if you want to create an answer I'll gladly accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `mem_fn` to create a wrapper that calls a member function on objects of heterogeneous type, as the wrapper created by `mem_fn` wraps a pointer to a particular member of a particular type.

The trick is to pass something with a templated function call operator that can accept any appropriate type and call the member function.

In C++14, pass a polymorphic lambda:

```
[](auto&& obj) -> decltype(auto) { return std::forward<decltype(obj)>(obj).get(); }
```

For C++11, you'd need to write the equivalent functor by hand:

```
struct call_get {
    template<class T>    
    auto operator()(T&& obj) const -> decltype(std::forward<T>(obj).get()) {
         return std::forward<T>(obj).get(); 
    } 
};
```